# Tips for golfing in PHP

Tags: code-golf, tips, php

What general tips do you have for golfing in PHP? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to PHP (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: Wait, am I doing it right?... Anyway, I'm really curious about this one. PHP is used by many people and golfers, but I almost have no idea how to golf a PHP code.

Comment: Use short tags <??> It can save a few bytes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Understand how variables and whitespace interact with PHP's language constructs.**

In my (admittedly short) time golfing, I have found that PHP's language constructs (e.g. echo, return, for, while, etc) behave in a less-than-intuitive way when interacting with variables and whitespace.

`echo$v;`, for example, is perfectly valid, as are `return$v;` and other similar constructs. These small reductions in whitespace can lead to a significant cumulative decrease in length.

Keep in mind, though, that variables **before** language constructs require a space after, as in the following example:

```
foreach($a AS$b){}
```

Because `AS` is a language construct, a space is not required before the variable `$b`, but if one were to omit the space *before it*, resulting in `$aAS`, this would be parsed as a variable name and lead to a syntax error.

Comment: `foreach($a[1]as$b)` needs no white space. This is not about language constructs and variables, but about spaces between word-characters of different words.

Comment: Another instance where you need whitespace is in string concatenation. For instance, `echo $a+5." text"` will not work because PHP thinks the `.` is a decimal point for the `5`. To make it work, you would need to add a space like this: `echo $a+5 ." text"`

Comment: @BasicSunset That statement can be written as `echo$a+5," text";`. The `echo` construct allows you to pass multiple parameters. where one would have to write `echo"result: ".($a+5)."!";`, you can write `echo"result: ",$a+5,"!";`. In fact, passing multiple parameters to an `echo` is a micro-optimization, since the code will run a tiny bit faster (since you don't concatenate the output, but send it separately). For challenges about writting the fastest code, this may help a tiny tiny tiny bit.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It works with `echo`, but not with `print` (which you need if you put it inside an expression: `echo` is a pure construct with no return value while `print` _can_ act as a function: it requires no parentheses, but it always returns `int(1)`.

Comment: @Titus I didn't said anything about `print`.

Answer (score 23):

**Use strings wisely.**

This answer is two-fold. The first part is that when declaring strings, you can utilize PHP's implicit conversion of unknown constants to strings to save space, e.g:

```
@$s=string;
```

The `@` is necessary to override the warnings this will produce. Overall, you end up with a one-character reduction.

is that sometimes, it may be space effective to set a variable to the name of an often used function. Normally, you might have:

```
preg_match(..);preg_match(..);
```

But when golfing, this can be shortened easily to:

```
@$p=preg_match;$p(..);$p(..);
```

With only two instances of "preg_match", you're only saving a single character, but the more you use a function, the more space you will save.

Comment: @ is not needed in codegolf; notices and warnings (including `E_DEPRECATED`) are acceptable

Comment: @Titus But in PHP, the warnings would output to the standard file output, so they are needed.

Comment: @Titus I believe you can suppress them in the `php.ini` file

Comment: Does the string tip work for empty strings? e.g. `@$k=;`

Comment: Starting from PHP 8, [an undefined constant causes Error to be thrown](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php).

Answer (score 13):

You don't always need to write out conditional checks. For example, some frameworks use this at the top of their files to block access:

```
<?php defined('BASE_PATH')||die('not allowed');
```

Or in normal functions

```
$value && run_this();
```

instead of

```
if($value) { run_this(); }
```

Comment: It works also in JS

Answer (score 10):

### Use short array syntax

Since PHP 5.4, arrays can be declared using square brackets (just like JavaScript) instead of the `array()` function:

```php
$arr=['foo','bar','baz'];
// instead of
$arr=array('foo','bar','baz');
```

It will save five bytes.

---

But It may cost bytes if you have "holes" in an associative array:

```php
$arr=array(,1,,3,,5);
// is one byte shorter than
$arr=[1=>1,3=>3,5=>5];
```

the disadvantage hits a little later if you can fill the holes with "empty" values:

```php
// saves two bytes over array()
$arr=[0,1,0,3,0,5];
// but for a larger array
$arr=[0,1,0,3,0,5,0,7,0,9,0,11];
// costs two byte more than
$arr=array(,1,,3,,5,,7,,9,,11);
```

Comment: PHP 7.1 also introduced short list assignment: `[,$a,$b,$c]=$argv;`.

Answer (score 9):

### Use ${0}, ${1}, ${2}, ... instead of $a[0], $a[1], $a[2], ...

Unless you're performing an array manipulation, most references to an array index `$a[$i]` can be replaced with simply `$$i`. This is even true if the index is an integer, as integers are valid variable names in PHP (although literals will require brackets, e.g. `${0}`).

Consider the following implementation of the Rabonowitz Wagon spigot:

```php
3.<?for(;$g?$d=0|($a[$g]=$d*$g--/2+($a[$g]?:2)%$g*1e4)/$g--:238<<printf($e?'%04d':'',$e+$d/$g=1e4)^$e=$d%$g;);
```

This can be improved by 6 bytes, simply by replacing both array references `$a[$g]` with `$$g` instead:

```php
3.<?for(;$g?$d=0|($$g=$d*$g--/2+($$g?:2)%$g*1e4)/$g--:238<<printf($e?'%04d':'',$e+$d/$g=1e4)^$e=$d%$g;);
```

Comment: I just saved 3 bytes with that: [showcase](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105710#105710).

Answer (score 6):

**Learn a large subset of the library functions**.

PHP's library is pretty huge and provides a ton of convenient functions that can greatly shorten various tasks.  You could just search every time you try to do something, but beyond wasting time you might not find anything that matches your particular search.  The best way is just to get familiar with the library and memorize function names and what they do.

Comment: That's a lot of memorization, especially given the rather inconsistent naming of a whole lot of functions ;-)

Comment: @Joey Agreed. Akin to memorizing the Java library, except that would be arguably less useful since it's more verbose.

Comment: I find that the most important functions for the challenges I've come across so far here are the string manipulation and array manipulation functions. Creative use of those can really cut down the code.

Comment: Creativity required - there's a bunch of stuff that is very niche, and some stuff that would be useful + should exist but doesn't. Like getting an individual char of a string.

Answer (score 6):

Running functions inside strings.

Try this:

```
$a='strlen';
echo "This text has {$a('15')} chars";
```

Or try this:

```
//only php>=5.3
$if=function($c,$t,$f){return$c?$t:$f;};
echo <<<HEREDOCS
    Heredocs can{$if(true,' be','not be')} used too and can{$if(<<<BE
{$if(true,1,0)}
BE
,'','not')} be nested
HEREDOCS;
//Expected output: Heredocs can be used too and can be nested
```

This only works with strings using `""` and heredocs (DON'T make confusion with nowdocs).

Using nested functions is only possible inside nested heredocs (or you will run into parse errors)!

Comment: `you will run into parse errors` I cant read it myself? How does the pesky Zend engine put this together

Comment: The next time I'm in a _"PHP is a good programming language"_ argument, I'm going to use this as a counter-point. Wow.

Comment: @primo Is it that bad? :O

Answer (score 5):

## fun with typecasts

- `!!$foo` will turn any truthy value to `true` (or `1` in output), falsy values (0, empty string, empty array) to `false` (or empty output)
  This will rarely be needed in code golf, for in most cases where you need a boolean, there is an implicit cast anyway.
- `(int)$foo` can be written as `$foo|0` or `foo^0`, but may need parentheses.
  For booleans and strings, `$foo*1` or `+$foo` can be used to cast to int.
- Unlike most other languages, PHP handles strings with numeric values as numbers. So if you have any string that contains a number you have to calculate with, just calculate.
- The other way does *not* work: To multiply any number in a variable with `10`, you could append a zero: `*10` -> `.0`. But in this case, PHP will take the dot as decimal point and complain. (It´s different though if you have a variable amount of zeroes in a string.)
- To turn an array into a string, use `join` instead of `implode`.
  If you don´t need a delimiter, don´t use it: `join($a)` does the same as `join('',$a)`
- Incrementing strings: The most amazing feature imo is that `$s=a;$s++;` produces `$s=b;`. This works with uppercase and lowercase characters. `$s=Z;$s++;` results in `$s=AA;`.
  This also works with mixed case: `aZ` to `bA`, `A1` to `A2`, `A9` to `B0` and `z99Z` to `aa00A`.
  Decrement does *not* work on strings. (And it does not on `NULL`).
  Back in PHP 3, `$n="001";$n++;` produced `$n="002";`. I am a little sad they removed that.

Whatever you golf: **always have the [operator precedence table](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.precedence.php) at hand.**

Answer (score 5):

### by any other name ... function aliases

use ...

- `join` instead of `implode`
- `chop` instead of `rtrim` (`chop` in PERL is different!)
- `die` instead of `exit`
- `fputs` instead of `fwrite`
- `is_int` instead of `is_integer` or `is_long`
- `is_real` instead of `is_float` or `is_double`
- `key_exists` instead of `array_key_exists`
- `mysql` instead of `mysql_db_query`

... to name the most important aliases.
Take a look at http://php.net/aliases for more.

Comment: Oh ... and did You know that `die` works with and without parameters? `die(1)` will exit the program with error code `1` (not completely sure on this; needs testing); `die` will exit with code `0`, and `die("Hello")` will exit with code `0` after printing `Hello`.

Answer (score 5):

**looping through strings**

can be done with 26 bytes or with 24 down to 18:

```php
foreach(str_split($s)as$c)  # A) 26 - general
for($p=0;a&$c=$s[$p++];)    # B) 24 - general
for($p=0;$c=$s[$p++];)      # C) 22 - if $s has no `0` character
for(;a&$c=$s[$p++];)        # D) 20 - if $p is already NULL or 0 (does NOT work for false)
for(;$c=$s[$p++];)          # E) 18 - both C and D

for(;$o=ord($s[$p++]);)     # F) 23 - work on ASCII codes, if $s has no NULL byte and D
for(;~$c=$s[$p++];)         # G) 19 - if $s has no chr(207) and D
```

---

`$a&$b` does a bitwise AND on the (ascii codes of) the characters in `$a` and `$b`
and results in a string that has the same length as the shorter of `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: can you please add `ord($s[$p++])` as alternative `for(;$s+=ord($argv[++$i])%32?:die($s==100););` against `for(;$c=$argv[++$i];)$s+=ord($c)%32;echo$s==100;` in this question https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116933/bernardino-identifies-unaltered-dollar-words

Comment: Please add `~` for cases you are working only with digits

Comment: Note that PHP 7.2 yields warnings for the `~$c` approach.

Answer (score 4):

## Use shorttags

In normal code, it's good practice to use `<?php` and `?>`. However, this is *not* normal code - you are writing a code golf code. Instead of `<?php`, write `<?`. Instead of `<?php echo`, write `<?=`. Don't type `?>` at end - it's completely optional. If you need `?>` for some reason (for example to output text, and it's shorter somehow, or something, don't put a semicolon before it - it's not needed, as `?>` implies semicolon.

Wrong (definitely too long):

```
<?php echo ucfirst(trim(fgets(STDIN)));?>s!
```

Correct:

```
<?=ucfirst(trim(fgets(STDIN)))?>s!
```

Comment: With the `-r` flag ([which comes free](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2428/55735)), you don´t even any tags at all (and you´re not allowed to use any).

Answer (score 4):

## Use ternary operators

```
if(a==2){some code;}else{some other code;}
```

can be abbreviated to this:

```
(a==2?some code:some other code);
```

Shorter, huh?

Comment: “Conditional shorthands”? Better tell its real name, so those interested in more details can find it in the documentation: [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Thanks, corrected. In informal use, I have heard it referred to mainly as 'conditional shorthands' or 'shorthand conditionals'.

Comment: The question asks for tips which are somewhat specific to PHP. This is one included in the [tips for all languages](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5315/194).

Comment: The ternary operator has a weird behaviour in PHP, if you nest it. `a?aa:ab?aba:abb:b` evaluates to `(a?aa:ab)?(aba):(abb)` or something like that.

Comment: And starting with PHP 5.3, you can omit the second operator: `$a?:$b` is the same as `$a?$a:$b`.

Comment: @Titus isn't that just `||`?

Comment: @Cyoce `||` casts to boolean in PHP.

Comment: a-2?some other code:some code. also for all languages.

Comment: And with php 7+ you have access to `??` to check if isset. Example `$a??$a:$b` will evaluate to `isset($a)?$a:$b`. It's called the [Null Coalescing Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

Answer (score 4):

## array_flip vs array_search

use

```
array_flip($array)[$value]
```

instead of

```
array_search($value,$array)
```

to save 1 Byte in arrays where the occurence of each value is unique

Answer (score 4):

## Combining `for` loops

Suppose you have code of the following form:

```php
for($pre1; $cond1; $post1) for($pre2; $cond2; $post2) $code;
```

this can generally be re-rolled in the following form:

```php
for($pre1; $cond2 • $post2 || $cond1 • $pre2 • $post1; ) $code;
```

where `•` represents a generic combining operator. This usually results in an byte count reduction, but will likely require some creativity. `$cond2` will need to be written so that it fails the first time through. `$post1` should also fail to execute the first time, although it may be easier to refactor beforehand so that `$post1` is not present.

If you're working with three or more nested loops, you can also combine two first, and then combine that to another, and so on. I find that it has generally been easier to combine from the inside outwards.

---

As an example, consider the following solution to the [H-carpet fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/157664/4098) (*97 bytes*):

```php
for(;$i<$n=3**$argn;$i+=print"$s\n")for($s=H,$e=1;$e<$n;$e*=3)$s.=str_pad($i/$e%3&1?$s:'',$e).$s;
```

This can be reformulated in the following way:

```php
for(;($i+=$e&&print"$s\n")<$n=3**$argn;)for($s=H,$e=1;$e<$n;$e*=3)$s.=str_pad($i/$e%3&1?$s:'',$e).$s;
```

*`$e&&print` prevents `print` on first iteration, and also does not increment `$i`.*

and finally (*93 bytes*):

```php
for(;$H>$e*=3or$e=($i+=$e&&print"$s\n")<${$s=H}=3**$argn;)$s.=str_pad($i/$e%3&1?$s:'',$e).$s;
```

*`$H>$e*=3` will fail the first time as both variables are undefined.*

Answer (score 3):

**line breaks**
if the output requires line breaks, use a physical line break (1 byte) instead of `"\n"`
This also gives you a possible benefit to chose between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

#### Associative arrays can be merged with the `+` operator.

Instead of:

```
$merged = array_merge($a, $b);
```

Use:

```
$merged = $a + $b;
```

Note the `+` operator works with indexed arrays as well, but probably doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Indeed, frequently a good replacement, though not exactly the same: http://pastebin.com/seYeaP38

Comment: Ah yeah, dang it, I originally had the title "associative arrays ... " and then removed it. I'll clarify, thanks.

Comment: numeric arrays can also merged using `+`, as long as the indexes are distinct. If they are not, the values from the first array will be overwritten with those from the second one (just like array_merge). The difference: `+` does not reorder indexes.

Answer (score 3):

**some interesting facts on [variable variables](http://php.net/variables.variable)**

I just had to share them (even before I [verified](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105831#105831) that at least one of them helps golfing):

- Use letters: `$x=a;$$x=1;$x++;$$x=2;echo"$a,$b";` prints `1,2`
  but other arithmetic operations do not work with letters.
- As [primo mentioned earlier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86394#86394), you can use pure numbers as variable names:
  `$a=1;$$a=5;$a++;$$a=4;${++$a}=3;echo${1},${2},${3};` prints `543`.
- You can not only use `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` for variable names, but EVERY string:
  `$x="Hello!";$$x="Goodbye.";echo${"Hello!"};` prints `Goodbye.`.
- But: Everything but `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*` as variable names requires braces for literal use.
- With no variables defined, `$$x=1` sets `${NULL}`, which is the same as `${false}` and `${""}`.
- `$a=1;$$a=5;` does not only set `${1}`, but also `${true}`.
- one more, the weirdest one I´ve found so far: Try `$a=[];$$a=3;echo${[]};`. Yes, it prints `3`!

The reason for most of this: variable names are always evaluated to strings.
<sup>(Thanks @Christoph for pointing out.)</sup>
So, whatever you get when you `print` or `echo` the expression, that´s what you get as variable name.

Comment: Variable names are converted to strings that explains the last three points on your list. `[]` converts to `Array`: `${[]} = 5;echo $Array;` prints `5`. I'm pretty sure you know that but it might not be obvious to everyone :)

Comment: @Jeff I fixed the typo. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

### PCRE-Related (Regex)

#### Functions

If the pattern always matches the subject string (thanks to the comment by @Deadcode), instead of `preg_replace`, you can use `preg_filter` (1 byte shorter).

#### Patterns

Sometimes [espace sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) are useful, like `\d`, `\w`, `\W`, `\s` or `\S`.

#### Examples

Filter non-alphabet characters:

```php
preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i", "", $s);
preg_filter("/\W|\d/", "", $s); // 3 bytes shorter
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice tip!

Comment: @taRadvylfsriksushilani, thanks you very much! :)

Comment: Note that this only works if the regex always matches. If it doesn't, it may still be made to work by adding a `|` at the end of the regex to make it match even when it doesn't match, but then there's no byte savings anymore. Also I'm not sure why you're showing `/[^a-z]/i` for `preg_replace` but `/\W|\d/` for `preg_filter` – they both use PCRE and anything that works in the latter should work in the former.

Comment: @Deadcode, thanks for the note, added in the answer. And about your last note: I know, but I just wanted to show these two tricks *together* can shorten the code by 3 characters.

Answer (score 2):

**avoid quotes where possible**

PHP implicitly casts unknown words to literal strings.

`$foo=foo;` is the same as `$foo='foo';` (assuming that `foo` is neither a key word or a defined constant): `$foo=echo;` does not work.

BUT: `$p=str_pad;` does; and `$p(ab,3,c)` evaluates to `abc`.

Using string literals without quotes will yield a Notice for `Use of undefined constant`; but that won´t show if you use the default value for `error_reporting` (CLI parameter `-n`).

Comment: I just noticed: This answer is a somewhat extended/updated duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2916/55735.

Comment: Note: PHP before 7.2 yielded Notices (which you can opress with the `-n` flag); 7.2 yields Warnings; later versions will throw Errors!

Answer (score 2):

## array_merge vs array_push

```
array_push($a,...$b);
```

is one byte shorter than

```
$a=array_merge($a,$b);
```

Does not work the same with Associative arrays

[variable-arg-list PHP >5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: This is an older tip now, but don't miss out on `$a=[...$a,...$b]` too!

Answer (score 2):

## Use boolean operators instead of `strtoupper()` and `strtolower()`

If you're working exclusively with strings consisting of alphabet characters, you can use boolean operators to change them to uppercase or lowercase with fewer keystrokes than PHP's built-in functions.

#### Example:

```php
// Convert lowercase to uppercase
$s = "g";
echo strtoupper($s);  // Outputs 'G', uses 20 characters
echo~" "&$s;          // Outputs 'G', uses 12 characters

// Convert uppercase to lowercase
$s = "G";
echo strtolower($s);  // Outputs 'g', uses 20 characters
echo$s^" ";           // Outputs 'g', uses 11 characters

// Switch case of each character
$s = "Gg";
echo$s^"  ";          // Outputs 'gG', uses 12 characters
```

Things are a little trickier for strings of arbitrary length, but the `&` and `^` operators will truncate the result to the length of the shorter input string. So for example, if `$W` is a string of spaces at least as long as any input `$s`, then `~$W&$s` is equivalent to `strtoupper($s)`, and `$s|$W^$s` is equivalent to `strtolower($s)` (whereas `$s|$W` by itself will produce a string with additional spaces unless `$s` and `$W` are of equal length).

Answer (score 2):

## Arrow functions in PHP 7.4

PHP 7.4 is on RC2 version now and hopefully will be released in about 2 months. List of new features are [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php) (this page can actually be updated when 7.4 is released). In 7.4, finally PHP has got the arrow functions, so not only function answers can be shorter now, but also passing closures to other functions can be a lot shorter too. Here are a few examples:

**Return input + 1:**

Anonymous function (closure) - 25 bytes - 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7P600L7kkMz9PQyVPs7ootaS0KE8lT9vQuva/NRdXanJGvoJKmoaRpvV/AA)

```php
function($n){return$n+1;}
```

Arrow function - 12 bytes - 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7Py1PQyVP09ZOJU/b8L81F1dqcka@gkqahpGm9X8A)

```php
fn($n)=>$n+1
```

**Multiply items of first input (array of ints) by second input (int):**

Anonymous function (closure) - 72 bytes - 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxDoJADADQ/b6CoUNruojAcho/xBhSCBcYrE29G4zh28@RNz9brV7vtloIkG41FZ3z9lYEYVD6@ZKLayPu8h1fYniEicpnwSPBdAKNO4NQ3GsMwXzTPDpCwseZW75wxz0PT25aolj/)

```php
function($a,$n){return array_map(function($b)use($n){return$b*$n;},$a);}
```

Arrow function - 38 bytes - 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg7DoAgDADQnVM4dADTRfwsih7EGFIGgoNNQ1w8fdU3PimiyyZFjIEcNLMFQmAXVqqVnniR2D/TN5BaYARyOhsj9eQ7VgvZ7h167HHAEacDG@/crC8)

```php
fn($a,$n)=>array_map(fn($b)=>$b*$n,$a)
```

Did you notice that `$n` is accessible in the inner function without a `use $n` statement? Yeah that is one of the arrow function features.

---

As a side note, I could not get arrow functions to work recursively (call the same arrow function inside itself), because we cannot give them a name and storing them as a closure in a variable like `$f` doesn't make `$f` accessible withing itself (sad). So this example **doesn't work** and using `$f` in first line causes a fatal error:

```php
$f=fn($n)=>$n?$f($n-1):0;
$f(5); // Causes error: "PHP Notice: Undefined variable: f" + "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string"
```

But calling an arrow function withing a different arrow function works:

```php
$f1=fn($n)=>$n+1;
$f2=fn($n)=>$f1($n-1);
$f1(2) // Returns 3
$f2(2) // Returns 2
```

Comment: What if instead of `$f=fn($n)=>$n?$f($n-1):0;` you do `$f=$F=fn($n)=>$n?$F($n-1):0;`? Would that work? And then you call `$(5)` as usual.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it still seems to throw same error. You can actually try on http://tio.run#php yourself as Dennis has updated its PHP to 7.4 RC2 a while back.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Seems that only variables defined *before* are available.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding file I/O:

Linking to another [related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5713/3862), the answers to which fit here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Directly dereference arrays returned from functions.

E.g., instead of this:

```
$a = foo();
echo $a[$n];
```

You can do:

```
echo foo()[$n];
```

This works with methods too:

```
echo $obj->foo()[$n];
```

You can also directly dereference array declarations:

```
echo [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][$n];
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use negative indexes to reference the end of a string

If you need the last character in a string, you can use the array reference method, and provide a negative index:

```
$lastChar = $string[-1];
```

This also works for functions like `substr()`:

```
$lastFour = substr($string, -4);
```

Comment: [Added as of PHP 7.1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/negative-string-offsets).

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `end()` instead of `array_pop()`

The `end()` function doesn't just move the internal pointer to the end of the array, it also returns the last value. Note of course that it doesn't *remove* that value, so if you don't care what the array contains afterwards, you can use it instead of `array_pop()`.

Answer (score 1):

## double array_flip vs in_array vs array_unique

in this [special case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116786/find-the-translation-table) a double array_flip saves 10 Bytes

`($f=array_flip)($k=$f($c)))` remove all double values in the array
and I have dropped this `$c=[],` , `|in_array($o,$c)` and replace `array_keys($c)` with `$k`

```
for([,$x,$y]=$argv;a&$o=$y[$i];$i++)
$x[$i]==$o?:$c[$x[$i]]=$o; # if char string 1 not equal char string 2 set key=char1 value=char2
echo strtr($x,($f=array_flip)($k=$f($c)))==$y # boolean replacement string 1 equal to string 2
    ?join($k)." ".join($c) # output for true cases
:0; #Output false cases
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15c1d9bddf3b7132a6998e6563b08e728dff0343)

against

```
for($c=[],[,$x,$y]=$argv;a&$o=$y[$i];$i++)
  $x[$i]==$o|in_array($o,$c)?:$c[$x[$i]]=$o; # if char string 1 not equal char string 2 set key=char1 value=char2
echo strtr($x,$c)==$y # boolean replacement string 1 equal to string 2
  ?join(array_keys($c))." ".join($c) # output for true cases
  :0; #Output false cases
```

[Online version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/806278a6c8ec65d86984b234f7d3f0bec8017477)

against array_unique it saves 2 Bytes

```
for([,$x,$y]=$argv;a&$o=$y[$i];$i++)
  $x[$i]==$o?:$c[$x[$i]]=$o; # if char string 1 not equal char string 2 set key=char1 value=char2
echo strtr($x,array_unique($c))==$y # boolean replacement string 1 equal to string 2
  ?join(array_keys($c))." ".join($c) # output for true cases
  :0; #Output false cases
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bcf8625977f94b64cdea19bf39fd2c3cabd866a)

After finding a bug in this program and replacement `$x[$i]==$o?:$c[$x[$i]]=$o` to `($p=$x[$i])==$o?:$k[$c[$p]=$o]=$p` the double array_flip was not necessary longer

Comment: associative safe `array_unique`. Yay!

Comment: @Titus I have add your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

### Return two copies of an expression

If you want to get two copies of the result of an expression, you can use this:

```
$v.$v=expr
```

But it won't be shorter than the more straightforward `($v=expr).$v` if you need to append more things to the result.

For 4 copies:

```
$v.$v.=$v=expr
```

You cannot use it to get 3 copies.

Answer (score 1):

**intersecting strings**

Have you ever used
`join("DELIMITER",str_split($s))` (31 bytes) or even
`preg_replace(".","DELIMITER",$s)` (32 bytes)
?

There´s a builtin for that:

Try `chunk_split($s,1,"DELIMITER")` (29 bytes).

---

If you omit the third parameter, [`chunk_split`](http://php.net/chunk-split) will use `\r\n`;  that can save you 7 or 8 bytes.

But beware: `chunk_split` also appends the delimiter to the string,
so you may not get exactly what you want.

(If you don´t provide the chunk length, it will use 76. Rather unusual for code golf, but who knows.)

Comment: Maybe you should add an example in combination with `strtr` I love this idea.

Answer (score 1):

## Removing characters in a string

```
join(explode(" ",$string));
```

saves 1 character compared to

```
str_replace(" ","",$string);
```

Comment: Note that this works for all (nonempty) strings, not just characters.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Why should it not work for empty strings? It make no sense or this case.

Comment: Well, the first version doesn't work with `""` and it's not very useful anyway.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Could you explain why it should not work? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVYpLijLz0m2VlKy5CoCskvgiDZVU29SKgpz8lFQNJQUlHagSTU1rrtTkjHyFrPzMPKAaTev//wE "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: I meant `" "`=`""`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVYpLijLz0m2VlKy5CoCskvgiDZVU29SKgpz8lFQNJSUdqApNTWuu1OSMfIWs/Mw8oBJN6///AQ "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @CalculatorFeline And for this case a zero byte solution is much better. It make no sense to do this in that way.

Comment: Your join example is missing a `)`. And `strtr($string,[" "=>""])` is even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## str_repeat

In some cases you have a input of characters and you should output them repeated with an input greater zero for each characters.

```php
for(;--$z?:($c=$argn[$i++]).$z=$argn[$i++];)echo$c;
```

(52 bytes) is shorter than

```php
for(;~$c=$argn[$i++];)echo str_repeat($c,$argn[$i++]);
```

or

```php
for(;~$c=$argn[$i++];)echo str_pad($c,$argn[$i++],$c);
```

(54 bytes each)

### How it works for example input `a1b2c1`

`$z` is not set (implicit `NULL`), so `--$z` does nothing and is falsy;

`$c="a"`, `$z="1"` and `$i=2` -> `$c.$z="a1"` is truthy -> output `"a"`

`--$z=0`; so we set `$c="b"`, `$z="2"` (and `$i=4`) -> `$c.$z="b2"` is truthy -> output `"ab"`

`--$z=1` -> output `"abb"`

`--$z=0`; so we set `$c="c"` and `$z=1`  `$c.$z="c1"` is true output `"abbc"`

`--$z=0` so `$c=""` and `$z=""` -> `$c.$z=""` is falsy -> loop breaks

Answer (score 1):

## unset() vs INF

In a case search for a minimum in an array you can use instead of

```
unset($var[$k]);

$var[$k]=INF;
```

to save 3 Bytes

Answer (score 0):

**use deprecated functions**
If you can use POSIX instead of PERL regex without wasting more than 5 bytes on the expression, use `ereg` or `eregi` instead of `preg_match`, `split` or `spliti` instead of preg_split.
`split` Can also be used as a synonym for `explode` for most delimiters.

These functions are marked deprecated and will throw `E_DEPRECATED` notices, but (cannot find the source now) I think I have read that warnings and notices are ok.

Comment: Watch out! These were removed in PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use short append syntax to add elements to the end of an array.

Instead of keeping track of the number of elements:

```
$array[++$i] = $value;
```

Or using the explicit push function:

```
array_push($array, $value);
```

You can use the implicit push feature:

```
$array[] = $value;
```

Comment: With a rare exception: when you need to append more than 3 elements, `array_push($array, $value, $value, $value, $value);` may be shorter;

Comment: Heh yeah, also note, if `$value` is itself an array, it's probably not going to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

#### JSON encode static array definitions

JSON encoding is one byte shorter per element than native PHP encoding for associative arrays. Of course, then you have to quote the resulting string (an additional two chars) and call `json_decode()` on that string (an additional 13 chars.) So, if you have a static associative array with more than 15 elements, try JSON encoding it. Note this probably won't work if you can use the "unquoted string literals" trick in your PHP array definition.

Instead of:

```
$array = [...];
```

Use:

```
$array = json_decode('...');
```

Comment: I think `explode` is also worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

## Switches base on arrays or strings

A little collection which can save Bytes for different conditions

Switch a function through an array

```
<?=(bc.[sub,add,mul,pow][($x=$argn)&3])($x,$x);
```

Make different Math operations

```
<?=[0,($x=$argn)+$x,$x*$x,$x**$x][$x&3];
```

Ternary Operator to switch a function

```
echo(strto.(rand()&1?low:upp).er)($c);
```

Using the Keys in an array as conditions

```
echo[ctype_alpha($s=dechex($argn))=>"Only letters",ctype_digit($s)=>"Only numbers",Mix][1];
```

special on strings but only not in all cases you must use a function and `trim` will do nothing

```php
($bool?trim:strtolower)($string)
```

character switch

```
"char"[$x%4]
```

character only in zero cases

```
"c"[$x%2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it listed so when using a list and explode you can use a number as the delimiter ( assuming its not in the string of course ). This lets you get rid of the quotes.

If there is backslash before the delimiter then it has to be `8` or `9` so it doesn't get confused with octal ( such as `\0` )

So instead of:

```
explode(",", "one,two,buckle,my,shoe")
```

You can do this

```
explode(1, "one1two1buckle1my1shoe")
```

Saving 2 bytes for the quotes.

As I mentioned for backslashes

```
explode(",", "/ \,| .. |,\ /");
```

Use `8` or `9`

```
explode(8, "/ \8| .. |8\ /");  // so you get \8 instead of \0 etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

## seek potential in combining several expressions to one

It´s easy to see that `A?B:C;` is shorter than `if(A)B;else C;`
`A&&B` is shorter than `if(A)B;` and `A||B;` is shorter than `if(!A)B;`

But how can `if(A){B;C;}else{D;E;}` be golfed?

Assume that `B` returns something truthy and `D` something falsy:

```php
if(A){B; C;}else{B; C;}  # 21 bytes
A?    B&&C  :    B||C;   # 12 bytes
```

another one:

```php
if(A){$b=123;$c="hello";} # 25 bytes
A&&$b=123+!$c="hello":    # 22 bytes
A&&$c="hello".!$b=123;    # also 22 bytes
```

`$c="hello` is truthy, so `!$c` is `false`. `+` casts to int; so we add `0` to `123`.
`$b=123` is truthy, so `!$b` is `false`. `.` casts to string, and that´s empty for `false`.

I even had [a case today](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174236/55735) where appending digits to the string didn´t make a difference.
(See line 5 of the breakdown.)

more examples:

```php
for(;;$a++,print$x);
for(;;$a+=print$x);
```

`print` always returns true, so its return value can be added to `$a` instead of incrementing `$a` separately.

```php
$a=1,$b=0
$a=!$b=0

if(X){$a=123;$b=0;}
X&&$a=123+$b=0;     # useful if you need $b to be and int (for printing)
X&&$b=!$a=123;

if(X){$a=123;$b=1;}
X&&$b=!!$a=123;
X&&$a=123*$b=1;
```

### advanced: combining nested loops

takes a new level to combining expressions. There is no general solution or approach; and it doesn´t always make the code shorter. Good chances are when the outer loop has no body except the inner loop; imagine shifting through a 2D array or sorting one.

Try

```php
for($a=1;$a<20;$a+=print"\n")for($b=$a;$b++<20;)echo$a*$b,"\t";
```

61 bytes (counting the control characters as one each)
that loop `$a` from `1` to `19`, `$b` from `$a+1` to `20`
and print the products, breaking the line when `$a` increments.

Ok, one simple two-byte saving is

```php
for($a=1;20>$b=$a;$a+=print"\n")for(;$b++<20;)echo$a*$b,"\t";
```

Combining the two loops to one saves another two bytes:

```php
for($a=$b=1;$b++<20||21>$b=1+$a+=print"\n";)echo$a*$b,"\t";
```

And you can save two more bytes with a leading linebreak instead of a trailing one (this often saves a byte or two):

```php
for($b=20;$b++<20||21>$b=1+$a+=print"\n";)echo$a*$b,"\t";
```

This is a pretty easy and rewarding example; so don´t be upset if your first attempts fail on saving bytes. It may take a while until you get an eye for it.

Ok, `for(;20>$b=++$a;print"\n")for(;$b++<20;)echo$a*$b,"\t";` is golfier; and in PHP 7, you can even avoid trailing tabs without any costs: `for(;20>$b=++$a;)for(;$b++<20;)echo$a*$b,"\n\t"[$b<20];`

But imagine you have to loop `$a` from somewhere else but `1`, like through ascii codes.

I may one day come up with an example that makes more sense. No promises on these premises though.

Comment: primo also posted on [combining loops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158096/55735) in March 2014. Don´t miss out on that one!

Answer (score 0):

When using `array_values()` to re-index an array with numeric keys, from PHP7.4 you can use a technique that I call [splatpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57725811/2943403) (**see link for further details and a demonstration**).

You use the "splat/spread" operator to "unpack" the array, then immediately "repack" the elements into an empty array.  Though not designed for this purpose, the result is the same -- in that limited scenario.

Technique using `$a` representing an array:

```
array_values($a)  // 14 characters (not counting $a)
```

becomes

```
[...$a]  // 5 characters (not counting $a)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Little-known tricks with increment/decrement

```php
$x = 'a';
echo ++$x; // Outputs "b"

$x = 'z';
echo ++$x; // Outputs "aa"
```

And many more at the following RFC, showing they will be removed/normalized in PHP 8.3

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/saner-inc-dec-operators