# The world ends in ed

Tags: code-golf, string

Taken straight from the ACM Winter Programming Contest 2013. You are a person who likes to take things literally. Therefore, for you, the end of The World is ed; the last letters of "The" and "World" concatenated.

Make a program which takes a sentence, and output the last letter of each word in that sentence in as little space as possible (fewest bytes). Words are separated with anything but letters from the alphabet (65 - 90, 97 - 122 on the ASCII table.) That means underscores, tildes, graves, curly braces, etc. are separators. There can be more than one seperator between each word.

`asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop` -> `flvmrp`
`pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs` -> `ststbts`
`looc si siht ,gnitirw esreveR` -> `citwR`
`99_bottles_of_beer_on_the_wall` -> `sfrnel`

Comment: Could you add a test case including digits and underscores?

Comment: The world ends in ed? I *knew* vim and Emacs couldn't measure up!

Comment: Well, the “real men use ed” essay has been part of the Emacs distribution for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Will the inputs be ASCII only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Perl 5, 18 bytes

```perl
s/\pL*(\pL)|./$1/g
```

Requires a `-p` command line switch. The named property `L` matches only letter characters `A-Za-z`. There are [several hundred](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) such named properties, but when dealing with ASCII text, very few of them are interesting. Besides `\pL`, the only other one of any real note is `\pP`, which matches punctuation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYmxDoIwFAB3vqKDgxqEODggTs5OziYvFB6lWvtqXwVjiJ9uRZLL5ZJz6M0uRs4v7rReTlqNWb7Y5irGiptWXG@mBHi/6v5zEL209zR7DOhHMT41ucRpxanAKoiGFJdzHUnu5/jPxBDVgvVEF0SqrA7aDwLZY4/npChAUggGGagFieiBLIQOYaiM@ZILmizHjfsB)

---

**Perl 5, 17 bytes**

*A one byte improvement by [Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/385684?noredirect=1)*

```perl
print/\pL*(\pL)/g
```

Requires `-n` (and `-l` to support multiple inputs).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYmxDoIwEEB3vuJGNSiTA@rk7ORscqFwlGrt1fYEY4ifbkWSl5eXPE/BblPywTgpLv60WkxaFjqlKjYtXG92j/h@1f3nAL1y93zzGCiMMD4N@8wbHXOgSqBhHfdzHVnt5vjPzDLXEM1EJ5BrZ8SEASgG6umclSUqFrEUkVtURAHZoXSEQ2Xtl70YdjGtnf0B)

---

**Sample usage**

```perl
$ more in.dat
asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop
pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs
looc si siht ,gnitirw esreveR
99_bottles_of_beer_on_the_wall

$ perl -p ends-in-ed.pl < in.dat
flvmrp
ststbts
citwR
sfrnel
```

Comment: I think `\w` also matches digits and underscores.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. That will need to be updated.

Comment: Brilliant. Regex was an obvious solution, but `|.` was not obvious (to me, at least).

Comment: Just noticed a `-1` in `print/\pL*(\pL)/g`, seems to output the same for your test cases!

Comment: `s/(\pL)*|./$1/g` and `print/(\pL)*/g` for 15 and 14 bytes since the capturing group captures here one char at a time so it store the last char of the word

Answer (score 23):

## ed, 35 characters

```
s/[a-zA-Z]*\([a-zA-Z]\)\|./\1/g
p
Q
```

So, the world ends in ed. As I like to be too literal, I decided to write to write the solution with ed - [and apparently it is actually a programming language](https://nixwindows.wordpress.com/2018/03/13/ed1-is-turing-complete/). It's surprisingly short, even considering many shorter solutions already exist in this thread. It would be nicer if I could use something other than `[a-zA-Z]`, but considering ed isn't a programming language, it's actually good enough.

First, I would like to say this only parses the last line in file. It would be possible to parse more, just type `,` at beginning of two first lines (this specified "everything" range, as opposed to standard last line range), but that would increase code size to 37 characters.

Now for explanations. The first line does exactly what Perl solution does (except without support for Unicode characters). I haven't copied the Perl solution, I just invented something similar by coincidence.

The second line prints last line, so you could see the output. The third line forces quit - I have to do it, otherwise `ed` would print `?` to remind you that you haven't saved the file.

Now for how to execute it. Well, it's very simple. Just run `ed` with the file containing test case, while piping my program, like that.

```
ed -s testcase < program
```

`-s` is silent. This prevents `ed` from outputing ugly file size at beginning. After all, I use it as a script, not editor, so I don't need metadata. If I wouldn't do that, ed would show file size that I couldn't prevent otherwise.

Comment: I installed ed just to try this.

Comment: 32 bytes... [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S035/79YPzpRt8pRNypWK0YDxozRjKnR048x1E8v@F/Opfc/sTglTSErO8c6Pr6qIrmszkahLCkvV0evsDy1qEahpjQzPwAA)

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript, 49

```
alert(prompt().replace(/.(?=[a-z])|[^a-z]/gi,''))
```

It uses a regular expression to remove all characters that come before a letter, as well as all non-letter characters. Then we're left with the last letter of each word.

Thanks to [tomsmeding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6689/tomsmeding) for a nice improvement.

Comment: You can probably improve this by making the regex case-insensitive, like in: `alert(prompt().replace(/.(?=[a-z])|[^a-z]/gi,''))`

Answer (score 6):

## C, 78

Golfed:

```
main(int c,char**s){for(;c=*s[1]++;)isalpha(c)&&!isalpha(*s[1])?putchar(c):0;}
```

With whitespace:

```
main(int c,char**s)
{
  for(;c=*s[1]++;)
    isalpha(c)&&!isalpha(*s[1])?putchar(c):0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using K&R declaration and defaulting `c`: `main(c,s)char**s;{for`

Answer (score 5):

### GNU Sed, <strike>40</strike> <strike>38</strike> 37

```
s/[a-z]\b/&\n/g; s/[^\n]*\(.\)\n/\1/g
```

#### Testing

```
cat << EOF > data.txt
asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop
pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs
looc si siht ,gnitirw esreveR
EOF
```

Run sed:

```
sed 's/[A-Za-z]\b/&\n/gi; s/[^\n]*\(.\)\n/\1/g' data.txt
```

Output:

```
flvmrp
ststbts
citwR
```

#### Explanation

The first substitution replaces all word boundaries, that are preceded by the desired match group, with a new-line. This makes it easy to remove all extraneous characters in the second substitution.

#### Edit

- Use case-insensitive flag (-2), thanks **manatwork**.
- Don't count whitespace (-1).

Comment: `sed`'s `s` command has `i` flag for cases insensitive matching: `s/[a-z]\b/&\n/gi`.

Comment: @manatwork: good point, this would make it GNU sed only, but it seems it already is, thanks.

Comment: `\b` considers `_`s to be letters, so if any words in the test *END* with `_`, that word's last letter is not included in the output

Answer (score 3):

### Grep and Paste, <strike>36</strike> <strike>34</strike> 28

```
> echo 'asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop' | grep -io '[a-z]\b' | tr -d \\n
flvmrp

> echo 'pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs'   | grep -io '[a-z]\b' | tr -d \\n
ststbts

echo 'looc si siht ,gnitirw esreveR'         | grep -io '[a-z]\b' | tr -d \\n
citwR
```

If a final new-line is needed, replace `tr -d \\n` with `paste -sd ''`.

#### Edit

- Use case-insensitive grep (-2), thanks **manatwork**.
- Use `tr` instead of `paste` (-4), thanks **manatwork**.
- Don't count whitespace around pipe (-2).

Comment: Quite creative with that `paste -sd ''`, but `tr -d \\n` is shorter. Regarding `grep`, it has `-i` switch meaning “ignore case”, which can make it shorter: `grep -io '[a-z]\b'`.

Comment: @manatwork, `tr` also delete the final newline. Case insensitive mode is of course shorter, thanks.

Comment: there is no rule requiring final newline.

Comment: @manatwork: I can agree with that, updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

### sed, 37 chars

Equal length to [Thor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10882/3544), but, I think, simpler.

```
s/[a-z]*\([a-z]\)/\1/ig;s/[^a-z]*//ig
```

The logic is quite trivial - replace letter sequences with their last letter, then delete all non-letters.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 39

```
""<>StringCases[#,(__~~x_)?LetterQ:>x]&
```

Test:

```
""<>StringCases[#,(__~~x_)?LetterQ:>x]& /@
 {"asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop",
  "pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs",
  "looc si siht ,gnitirw esreveR",
  "99_bottles_of_beer_on_the_wall"}
```

> ```
> {"flvmrp", "ststbts", "citwR", "sfrnel"}
> ```

Comment: Good one. `LetterQ` should be called `LettersQ` :) I haven't thought of it for testing whole strings.

Comment: @belisarius Actually, with this construct it is applied character-wise, so it could be a literal "LetterQ" and still work.

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/) (builtins only), 40

```zsh
for j (${=@//[^a-zA-Z]/ });printf $j[-1]
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##NcvdToNAEAXg@z7FBKuBBCTV9KKiifQRvDDapp3wM8Ai7tDdlVX68@poG0nOxUnOd3pdDSRz7Xr7oWAFNbjT/dNzGK63SdDHwWoTwtGLWiWkKWBar4PZZqCs4slxcv6Bs7P3wexOmR9L8/nV9fYG8e195XpaxzG8Lp1/lui8gPqjiRD776w7PUKXyk//dmdJHeDwJbgdaStK7QMlBnIudXRpS04fLuU8jrBhzkCLv1QG/FIKI5QF0oo6ehnRYoEpG9OQRi4wJVLIEk1FaJOmcYZf)...

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4.5 bytes (9 nibbles)

```
.%~$\$a/\
```

```
.%~$\$a/\       # 9 nibble program
.%~$\$a/\$$     # with implicit variables added:
 $~             # split
   $            # the input
    \           # by whether the character class
     $          # of each element
      a         # is alphabetic;
.               # now, map over this
        \       # reversing
         $      # each group
       /        # and folding across these
          $     # returning the first (left-hand) argument
                # (in other words, return the first character of each group)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica <s>62</s> <s>57</s> 52

```
Row@StringTake[StringCases[#,LetterCharacter..],-1]&
```

Testing

```
l = {"asdf jkl;__zxcv~<vbnm,.qwer| |uiop", 
     "pigs,eat dogs;eat Bob:eat pigs", 
     "looc si siht,gnitirw esreveR"}

Row@StringTake[StringCases[#,LetterCharacter..],-1]&/@ l
(*{flvmrp,ststbts,citwR}*)
```

Comment: I mistakenly edited yours, but then rolled it back. Ooops.

Answer (score 2):

## K, 49

```
{last'f@&"b"$#:'f:"|"\:@[x;&~x in,/.Q`a`A;:;"|"]}
```

.

```
k){last'f@&"b"$#:'f:"|"\:@[x;&~x in,/.Q`a`A;:;"|"]}"asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop"
"flvmrp"
k){last'f@&"b"$#:'f:"|"\:@[x;&~x in,/.Q`a`A;:;"|"]}"pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs"
"ststbts"
k){last'f@&"b"$#:'f:"|"\:@[x;&~x in,/.Q`a`A;:;"|"]}"looc si siht ,gnitirw esreveR"
"citwR"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Scala, 59 (or 43)

Assuming the string in already in `s`:

```
s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+").map(_.last).mkString
```

If you need to read from a prompt and print rather than using the REPL output, convert `s` to `readLine` and wrap in `println()` for 59.

Answer (score 2):

### x86: 54 bytes

Assume a [cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) routine with the signature `void world_end(char *input, char *output)`:

```
60 8b 74 24 24 8b 7c 24 28 33 d2 8a 0e 8a c1 24
df 3c 41 72 08 3c 5a 77 04 8a d1 eb 09 84 d2 74
05 88 17 47 33 d2 46 84 c9 75 e0 84 d2 74 03 88
17 47 88 0f 61 c3
```

Comment: By the way, I realize the question asks for a program and not a _routine_, but I wanted to do something different.  Contrary to the problem statement, I guess I'm not a "person who likes to take things literally" after all. :P

Answer (score 2):

### Xi, 32

```
println$ @{=>.-1}<>input re"\W+"
```

[Xi](https://github.com/arshajii/xi) is a language still in its beta phase, but it seems to work well with code golf so I figured I might as well show yet another short and functional solution (and advertise the language a little :-)).

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 76 chars

`import re;print "".join(re.findall("([a-zA-Z])(?=$|[^a-zA-Z])",raw_input()))`

Comment: You can remove the space after `print`.

Comment: Shorten by porting to Python 3: `import re;print(*re.findall("([a-zA-Z])(?=$|[^a-zA-Z])",input()),sep='')`

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 59 chars

```
import re;print(re.sub('.(?=[a-z])|[^a-z]','',input(),0,2))
```

Correctly deals with capital letters and underscores.  The 2 is to pass `re.sub` the `re.IGNORECASE` flag without having to use `re.I`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>16</s> <s>9</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
q\L mÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVA&code=cVxMIG3M&input=IlRoZSBXb3JsZCI) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=cVxMIG3M&footer=cQ&input=WwoiYXNkZiBqa2w7X196eGN2fjwgdmJubSwucXdlcnwgfHVpb3AiIC0%2bIGZsdm1ycAoicGlncywgZWF0IGRvZ3M7IGVhdCBCb2I6IGVhdCBwaWdzIiAgIC0%2bIHN0c3RidHMKImxvb2Mgc2kgc2lodCAsZ25pdGlydyBlc3JldmVSIiAgICAgICAtPiBjaXR3UgoiOTlfYm90dGxlc19vZl9iZWVyX29uX3RoZV93YWxsIiAgICAgIC0%2bIHNmcm5lbApdLW1S)

```
q\L mÌ     :Implicit input of string U
q          :Split on
 \L        :  Regex /[^a-z]/gi
    m      :Map
     Ì     :  Last character
           :Implicitly join & output
```

Comment: I think you can just do `f"%l(?!%l)" q` (doesn't work in v2 because the parser doesn't like the `(?`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```hs
f s=last<$>words[last$' ':[c|'@'<c,c<'{','`'<c||c<'[']|c<-s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdNDsIgEEDhq0waktmgB1BqvINL0lSkJdbSHxnaGp14dcTVe9/dUN96n5IDKr2hqMRpm0JD@g@BgAdtGc@orLQKPyjxmp85Q2OVs6MqDaYboYR5iZcYQICDwlDj4NH7Y12/X3b9Klhv4yD3z60NDLx001ykHw) Thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard) for a version without the import, saving two bytes!

---

#### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 62 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
f s=last<$>words[last$' ':[c|isAlpha c]|c<-s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcfRCoIwFAbg@57iRwRvygeoGUS9QZcicpoOl5uunakRo1df9N19A/HYG5OStm72ATcKVF4H8jsFrgxxEPl5m33H9T95geJYy6j5YtxAkE2U4sBNsqQnVHBLuAePHAoZcafwHM2pbT9vuX4F1sdk9@Vr631EXPTssvQD)

Given an input string `s`, `[last$' ':[c|isAlpha c]|c<-s]` converts all non-alphabetic characters to spaces. `words` splits the resulting string on white space and `last<$>` takes the last character of each of the resulting strings.

Comment: [60 bytes.](https://tio.run/##FcdNDsIgEEDhq0waktmgB1BqvINL0lSkJdbSHxnaGp14dcTVe9/dUN96n5IDKr2hqMRpm0JD@g@BgAdtGc@orLQKPyjxmp85Q2OVs6MqDaYboYR5iZcYQICDwlDj4NH7Y12/X3b9Klhv4yD3z60NDLx001ykHw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>27</s> 19 bytes

```
seMc:z"[^A-Za-z]+"d
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=seMc%3Az%22%5B%5EA-Za-z%5D%2B%22d&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=asdf+jkl%3B__zxcv%7E%3C+vbnm%2C.qwer%7C+%7Cuiop%0Apigs%2C+eat+dogs%3B+eat+Bob%3A+eat+pigs%0Alooc+si+siht+%2Cgnitirw+esreveR%0A99_bottles_of_beer_on_the_wall&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
seMc:z"[^A-Za-z]+"d | Full code
--------------------+---------------------------------------------
    :z"[^A-Za-z]+"d | In the input, replace non-letters with space
   c                | Split on spaces
 eM                 | Replace each word with its last letter
s                   | Concatenate each letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 126

My R solution

```
function(x){cat(paste(unlist(sapply(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(gsub("
[^[:alpha:]]"," ",x)," ")),""),tail,1)),collapse=""),"\n")}
```

Comment: Nice approach, golfed down a bit to [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYhBCsMgEEX3PYXMaoTZdBvwJGkKNtFGEBVnpAmlZ7dx8/77r3Zvum9plZATHtRMSzGwEBuWyiUG0d/VCjZkW0o8kYfim9sL4TY/58nGsttpWYBAAR16jL4ImsSGSPdxHgmIXTFX/XWPILtTLm0qezX0k2vcQPc/)...

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
DQ*a@+XA
```

Verify all test cases: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxDoIwEIDhnae4WRt3wEGND6Auul1aOKBauNJWagzx1auS/MOX/FbbdAVZjHBKx/NK7ta3fUrS1w3cH6ZEfL@q6bOFSQ292IyR3AzzU7PNrG69AJIBam59uejAqljwn5lhrsDrX10A0Q46aBeBvKOJLlmeo@IQDHnkBhWRQx4wdIRRGvMF)

#### Explanation

```
      XA  Built-in regex variable: `[A-Za-z]`
     +    Apply regex + quantifier: `[A-Za-z]+`
   a@     Find all matches in the input
DQ*       Dequeue the last character from each match
          Concatenate together and autoprint (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica <s>71</s> <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 61

Back to the drawing board, after @belisarius found an error in the code.

```
StringCases[#, RegularExpression["[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z])"]] <> "" &
```

Testing

```
l = {"asdf jkl;__zxcv~<vbnm,.qwer| |uiop", "asdf jkl__zxcv~<vbnm,.qwer| |uiop", 
"pigs,eat dogs;eat Bob:eat pigs", "looc si siht,gnitirw esreveR"};

StringCases[#, RegularExpression["[A-Za-z](?![A-Za-z])"]] <> "" & /@ l
```

> {"flvmrp", "flvmrp", "ststbts", "citwR"}

Comment: `\\w` matches `_`, so it doesn't work for (for example) `"asdf jkl__zxcv~<vbnm,.qwer| |uiop"`

Comment: Wait `Row@StringTake[
    StringCases[#, 
     LetterCharacter ..], -1] &@"asdf jkl__zxcv~<vbnm,.qwer| |uiop"` gives me `flvmrp`, but `#~StringCases~RegularExpression@"\\w\\b" <> 
   "" &@"asdf jkl__zxcv~<vbnm,.qwer| |uiop"` returns `fvmrp` here. Are we getting the same results??

Comment: @belisarius You were right about the error in my earlier version.  I was testing it with the wrong string!

Comment: Hehe , +1 again

Comment: @belisarius guys, please see the answer I posted.  If it is correct it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>88 80 75 69</strike> 68

```
s=p=''
for c in raw_input()+' ':a=c.isalpha();s+=p[a:];p=c*a
print s
```

Input: `435_ASDC__uio;|d re;fG o55677jkl..f`

Output: `CodeGolf`

---

This solution can be shortened to **67** characters if you allow the output to include backspace characters (ASCII code 8) at the beginning. The output will be visually identical.

```
s=p='<BS>'
for c in raw_input()+p:a=c.isalpha();s+=p[a:];p=c*a
print s
```

Same input, (visually) same output. `<BS>` is meant to be the backspace character.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.x, 64 bytes

```
import re;print(''.join(a[-1] for a in re.split('\W+',input())))
```

Comment: The last example is not working. Also, an error occurs if the line begins or ends with a separator

Comment: You can remove the space before `for`.

Answer (score 1):

## **Lua, 42**

```
print(((...):gsub('.-(.)%f[%A]%A*','%1')))
```

Usage example: `lua script.lua "asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop"`

Answer (score 1):

### VBA, 147 <strike>161</strike>

```
Sub a(s)
For n=0 To 255:m=Chr(n):s=Replace(s,IIf(m Like"[A-Za-z]","",m)," "):Next
For Each r In Split(s," "):t=t & Right(r,1):Next
MsgBox t
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Smalltalk**, Squeak/Pharo flavour
**122** char with traditional formatting for this method added to String:

```
endOfWords
    ^(self subStrings: (CharacterSet allCharacters select: #isLetter) complement) collect: #last as: String
```

**62** chars in Pharo 1.4, with regex and weird formatting

```
endOfWords^''join:(self regex:'[a-zA-Z]+'matchesCollect:#last)
```

Answer (score 1):

## J: 60 characters (or 38 characters for a less correct version)

```
(#~e.&(,26&{.&(}.&a.)"0(97 65))){:&>;:]`(' '"_)@.(e.&'_:')"0
```

If we're willing let the program break whenever there are words ending in a colon or an underscore, then we can simplify this to 38 characters.

```
(#~e.&(,26&{.&(}.&a.)"0(97 65))){:&>;:
```

Sample run:

```
    (#~e.&(,26&{.&(}.&a.)"0(97 65))){:&>;:]`(' '"_)@.(e.&'_:')"0'asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop'
flvmrp
    (#~e.&(,26&{.&(}.&a.)"0(97 65))){:&>;:]`(' '"_)@.(e.&'_:')"0'pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs'
ststbts
    (#~e.&(,26&{.&(}.&a.)"0(97 65))){:&>;:]`(' '"_)@.(e.&'_:')"0'99_bottles_of_beer_on_the_wall'
sfrnel
```

Comment: 38 Bytes (for a correct version): `(#~[:2&|64 90 96 122&I.@(u:inv)){:&>;:`, or 43 bytes for a non-explicit version: `(#~[:2&|64 90 96 122&I.@(u:inv))@:({:@>)@;:`. This uses the interval index verb, `I.`, which interprets `64 90 96 122` as the set of intervals `(__, 64] (64, 90], (90, 96], (96, 122], (122, _)`, and returns the index of the iterval to which its argument, the ascii code of the char, belongs. If this index is odd, it's not alphabetical.

Comment: @BolceBussiere doesn’t work with underscores for some reason (last test case).

Comment: @FrownyFrog ah, I see why, `;:` interprets `abc_` as one word since variable names can contain underscores. +10 bytes to add `(#~~:&'_')`, probably an inefficient fix

Comment: @BolceBussiere that’s just `'_'-.~` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

## **C#**

Method, **105** bytes: (assumes usings for System, System.Text.RegularExpressions and System.Linq)

```
string R(string i){return string.Concat(Regex.Split(i,"[^a-zA-Z]").Where(x=>x!="").Select(n=>n.Last()));}
```

Program, **211** bytes:

```
using System;using System.Text.RegularExpressions;using System.Linq;class A{static void Main(){Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Regex.Split(Console.ReadLine(),"[^a-zA-Z]").Where(x=>x!="").Select(n=>n.Last())));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in **PHP**. **197** bytes :(
I'm beginner

```
$l=$_GET['line'];
$l=preg_replace('/(\W|_)+/',' ',$l);
$s=explode(' ',$l);
foreach($s as $d){
$a=substr($d,-1,1);
$o=ORD($a);
if(($o>=97 && $o<=122) || ($o>=65 && $o<=90)){
echo $a;
  }
}
```

**EDITED**
Now it's **171 bytes**

```
<?$l=$_GET['l'];$l=preg_replace('/(\W|_)+/',' ',$l);$s=explode(' ',$l);foreach($s as $d){$a=substr($d,-1,1);$o=ORD($a);if(($o>=97&&$o<=122)||($o>=65&&$o<=90)){echo$a;}}
```

Comment: For golf, you should as much as possible reduce your variable names to single characters at the very least.

Comment: edited it.Thanks for telling me.I'm new here.

Comment: Sure. You may also want to look [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2913/3862) for some additional PHP-specific help.

Comment: `foreach((' ',preg_replace('/(\W|_)+/',' ',$_GET['line'])) as $d){$a=substr($d,-1,1);$o=ORD();if(($o>=97 && $o<=122) || ($o>=65 && $o<=90)){echo $a;}}` is 149, if it works.

Comment: `\W|_` excludes digits; so you should add `\d` to your regex or use `/[^a-z]+/i`

Answer (score 1):

***K 30***

```
q)k)f:{x@&-1=-':(1_x," ")in,/.Q`a`A}
q)f "asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop"
"flvmrp"
q)f "pigs, eat dogs; eat Bob: eat pigs"
"ststbts"
q)f "looc si siht ,gnitirw esreveR"
"citwR"
q)f "99_bottles_of_beer_on_the_wall"
"sfrnel"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 2.0, 25 (+1) chars

```
gsub(/(\w+)\W*/){$1[-1]}
```

Must be run with the `-p` switch:

```
 $ ruby -p ed.rb <<< "asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop"
flvmrp
```

Comment: Please specify the `ruby` version. 1.9.2 outputs “#<Enumerator:0x9f65e10>#<Enumerator:0x9f65d98>#<Enumerator:0x9f65d34>#<Enumerator:0x9f65cd0>”.

Comment: You're right. I had completely forgotten that I installed it, but my current Ruby version is 2.0 (`ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474`). When running the program with version 1.8.7 it outputs an ASCII value! Didn't know there were so many differences between the versions.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely have to update my Ruby. (Both the interpreter and the knowledge.) The second capturing group is not necessary: `gsub(/(\w+)\W*/){$1[-1]}`.

Comment: Oh, of course it's not. Thanks, updated :)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 37 bytes

```
t=>t.match(/[a-z](?![a-z])/ig).join``
```

Comment: I don't think so. The question explicitly stated the letters should be output in as few bytes as possible (without separators)

Comment: adding `.join\`\`` (7 bytes) will fix the output

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 117 bytes

```
	L =&UCASE &LCASE
	N =INPUT
B	N SPAN(L) . X BREAK(L) REM . N	:F(O)
	X RPOS(1) LEN(1) . X
	O =O X	:(B)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxdC4IwGIWv3/2K90o2CCHoyvJCa0G0NlEH3on2AZVpJVmE9NfXdvWc83A4fdvVXTMzBgSGnl5GGUdPOBCQGG5konMS25glkaSCoY8FximPtq6kfGeFhGBNFSNQYJqojE4ZCi4d7JiAwlBhAQGNGVGgdG4vrSJcroyp@sMJL9dmXpbfz374LXCo29vEf7yPzxHH17m7/wE)

```
	L =&UCASE &LCASE			;*upper and lowercase letters
	N =INPUT				;*read input
B	N SPAN(L) . X BREAK(L) REM . N	:F(O)	;*while match success, set X to first run of L characters, split on non-L characters, and set N to remainder
	X RPOS(1) LEN(1) . X			;*set X to the last character of X
	O =O X	:(B)				;*append X to O, goto B
O	OUTPUT =O				;*output O
END
```

I feel like there's a way to directly set `X` to the end of the `SPAN(L)` but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
Sžosåγ€g£ʒDáQ}€θJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/@Oi@/OLDS89tftS0Jv3Q4lOTXA4vDKwFcs7t8Pr/PzzDX8ExyFWhMr9UIcDVP8DHVUHZQVHV00/B2MjA0shBWUNV00HZN1JBQ1nTQVNDRVPDId7QSNfA1MjQ0tDIRNfSwsAQqM7bM8TZw9XPXtFe0am0pAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 20 bytes

```
i`.(?=[a-z])|[^a-z]
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##HYnRCoIwFEDf9xX3JTAwoUezCPqEXqWuW151tXZtWxoi/bqlcOAcOI6CtnI7raJCTLpIouMhl5vhsh7z62wxTdKXFdwfJkMcPrfuu4dO2WecvHpyI4xvza1ode1jIBmg5NpnS51Y7ZaYpzDMN/D6TxMgrq0O2vVA3lFHZ5GmqDgEQx65QkXkkC2GhrCXxvwA)

This program is compatible with version 0.8.2

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
u=isAlpha
f(a:i@(b:_))|u b=f i|u a=a:f i|1>0=f i
f(a:b)=[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrRCsIgFEDf9xUyepgQo14to6i/iJBrTbxNnTldEdKvW@vpHA5Hw9h3xpSC1g8hkhNEaI8aQpU4jgfjNVSqAYb7RjJBaU5EckXwR@DAZlvvVnP5b5LyM1yKBXTcB3RxoWoYb4rce7MR4v26Tp8tmaSzy/bx7EImOeHg6/IF)

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 26 bytes:

```
:s/\v\S*(\a)\A*( |$)/\1/g<CR>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pYP6YsJlhLIyZRM8ZRS0OhRkVTP8ZQP53r//@CzPRiHYXUxBKFlPz0Ymswyyk/yQrMAEkCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 16 bytes

```
Li, -1|""`[a-z]+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnBCoJAEIDhu08xCEGQBh7NTl26dOoaMe7qqFvbju1uGiK9@lbCf/jgt@SVEVlYrY9lOKkE0myO4/Ii0um6CUG4uoHbXReI07saPnsYpHkk2@dIdob5pbiPetW6BEh4qLl1xaIDy92C/4w0cwVO/eo8JK1RXtkRyFka6BzlOUr2XpNDblASWWSDviMchdZf)

#### Explanation

```
Li, -1|""`[a-z]+
L         [a-z]+        List all the sequences of letters in the input
 i                      case insensitive
  ,                     Keep all the results
    -1                  but only the last character for each of them
      |""               Use the empty string as separator
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 43 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(?i).(?=[a-z])|[^a-z]","")
```

Port of [*@mbomb007*'s Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158150/52210).

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY8xb4MwEIX3/IoTE0jAntI0SvdmaEeUWgYuxMTY1D6gTaF/nRrKWkW6k599ep/fVbzjkW5QVcV1yiW3Fl64UN8bAKEIzZnnCMf5CvBGRqgScn8VNkjc@@jalSVOIocjKNjBZKMnGxtspLMfpPQ9fy@C2N/vUh7dTsGQvs@nF3peMCV/gKbNpAOsnE6LAmqXZP0sPfFgTfFlCetYtxQ3bkJS@SrOfY/b4gzVVSaM3T7z7ucRukzVYfzRoxlgaIVuvGBJ/D@jEaUNATlBoUubLOpZZw@LmId3CVJrt4NwdSEISyVImB7QGuzw9a57u2WZJpJomT6zDNEwrRhdkPVcytU@bsbpFw)

```java
s->  // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s.replaceAll("(?i).(?=[a-z])|[^a-z]","")
     //  Remove every match of this regex, and return as result
```

Additional explanation for the regex:

```java
"(?i).(?=[a-z])|[^a-z]"  // Main regex to match
 (?i)                    //  Case insensitive
     .                   //   Any character
      (?=[a-z])          //   Followed by a letter (as positive look-ahead)
               |[^a-z]   //   or a non-letter

""                       // Replace it with: nothing
```

Comment: That's actually `(?i)` for the flag.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 52 bytes

The narrow word characeter definition quite of narrows the number of approaches.
I wonder if anything else can compete with regex here.

[Try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd59a80961e20a4ac6324542f3ddd5232bfd81e8).

---

```php
<?=preg_filter("/.*?([a-z])[^a-z]+/i","$1",$argn._);
```

This requires PHP 7.1 for the negative string index. Run as pipe with `-nF`.

---

Another solution, **53 bytes** (requires PHP 7.1)

```php
foreach(preg_split("/[^a-z]/i",$argn)as$s)echo$s[-1];
```

Run as pipe with `-nR`.

---

The shortest non-regex solution I could find so far takes **60 bytes**:

```php
while(~$c=$argn[$i++])$b=ctype_alpha($c)?$c:!print$b;echo$b;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 12 characters

```
<L1>\X=$0
?=
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '<L1>\X=$0;?=' <<< 'asdf jkl;__zxcv~< vbnm,.qwer| |uiop'
flvmrp
```

Comment: Is there a reason you said 12 characters instead of 12 bytes? Just curious

Comment: Nothing special. I started golfing before the deluge of languages using multibyte characters, so all solutions mentioned characters. As I enjoyed those times more, I kept the habit of mentioning characters. In case of my solutions makes no difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 81 bytes

```
D,u,@@,o
D,l,@,V91 65r123 97r+bU€CJGe
D,T,@~,
L~,€lB]ABcB*"."dV€uJG$tbU€TBZVcGbUJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/PSsNAEMbP5imG0JOOhSgqKSJxLQSCJ2lyEMKSzW7bxJiNm20its2hr@LVp/BRfJG4WxHmMPPNb/58GedNM45z3GAQoHTmWGGAie/B9ZXyLi7Bv1FnLP45fD1EoTDtBQYDOo8DGqki6T3Jyak7dXli6k0UTvQRXpDnJA9ZHJnNeVbZnV7qmPFSFrW5NEPnxIXzO3BLq2rRaqHQilnLl1C@VJR@vOfdcAsdq19x@tYLtYPdppCNa6imWLUIItPA5X9GJJsdE9u0UCVlDm1hYq0BV3WhC9WDaJXoxJMFfJ8yqXUlWiqXlAmhqKypXgvam58NQVKesBiMoa11sQeShgHJ4ftza43sHWfy9/r4Cw)

Answer (score 1):

## [GAWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```
BEGIN{RS="[^A-z]"}{printf substr($0,length$0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWKTrOUbcqVqm2uqAoM68kTaG4NKm4pEhDxUAnJzUvvSRDxUCz9v//xOKUNIWs7Bzr@PiqiuSyOhuFsqS8XB29wvLUohqFmtLM/AIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 46 bytes

```julia
f(s)=string(matchall(r"[a-z](?![a-z])"i,s)...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc/BasMwDAbg@55Cyy42pDkOum4M9gi9lmHsVE7cKnZmqckoZa@eZekOAYF@kD6EThcK9nmavGL9xpJDbFRnpW4tkcrFwW6un@r9cem6CCXrqqr01M@LQlF5VVg@ejidaWfM9bsefl5hcLErq68R8w1ul5D6Qmt4Ak9Dl/uHFe1DwyWgFTimhndL@kjuZQl/wztkYXHCa0kp1cBhrlagbGKQkEdAzjjg/q7qION@bbZb45IIIZvkjUPMJkUjLZpxfvb/lM8RafoF)

Simple Julia with Standard regex. The `r""` constructor creates a `Regex` class. Notice how the `i` letter after the last `"` makes the expression case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
e€ØẠ¬œpµLƇṪ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYo9DoJAFISv8kK9sUesrK28wIafByyuLLIrqCEWNvTaUFobWgssIXgPvMgKJJPJl5kvQs7PWuPvVnfV8Hm2df9I2vfmWw7Naxx1V47d34em0tqwpedDtOMWpZeTm11XkDnxniwOOaYFFEcmEoOAkbBAEkBbgScCac20Fs5yhumcJC6EC5KNCRWQIGaKpTmgTDHD7SSYJnWEUhwlFT51EFMqYqpCpLnNufEH)

```
e€ØẠ¬œpµLƇṪ€ - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
  ØẠ         - Yield "ABC...XYZabc...xyz"
 €           - For each character in S:
e            -   Is it in the alphabet?
    ¬        - Logical NOT
               This yields a list, L, with 1s at non-alphabet characters
     œp      - Partition S at truthy indices of L, without keeping the borders
       µ     - Begin a new chain with the partitioned list, P, as the argument
         Ƈ   - Keep those with a truthy:
        L    -   Length
           € - Over each:
          Ṫ  -   Yield the last character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
m→fo√←ġo¬√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/dR26S0/Ecdsx61TTiyMP/QGiDz////icUpaQpZ2TnW8fFVFclldTYKZUl5uTp6heWpRTUKNaWZ@QUA)

since there's no conditional spliting function, `group-by` is used. Golflangs with regex are really strong here.

### Explanation

```
m→fo√←ġo¬√
      ġo¬√ group on nonalphabets
  fo√←     filter out nonalphabets
m→         map to last character
```

Comment: Well done!!!  Nonalphabets is the secret!  I was trying to do this last night, and ended up with [this](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/dR26S0/EdNjY/aJhxZmH9oDZDJ9ahpzaEl2o8alik5RikpJVb9//@/JCNVITUvJT4/TQEIgLz48vyinBQA), which is completely embarassing and so I was ashamed to post it!

Comment: [One of my first husk answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212008/80214) had this same problem and `√` was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) (-E), 29 bytes

```
s/[a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z])|./\1/gp
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/OlG3ylE3KlZLA8bSrNHTjzHUTy/4/z@xOCVNISs7xzo@vqoiuazORqEsKS9XR6@wPLWoRqGmNDM/4F9@QUlmfl7xf13X/7p5AA)

Beats other `sed` answers by 8 bytes. Port of the excellent [`ed`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11857/15940) solution.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>36</s> 37 bytes

```
s=>s.match(/[A-z](?![a-z])/ig).join``
```

Comment: `[A-z]` matches characters outside the alphabet, so this is invalid.

Comment: wut? what characters? @Razetime

Comment: oh, []^_` didnt know nor expact that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 6 bytes

*Thanks to lyxal for [reminding me not to be a sussy baka](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58669836#58669836)*

```
øWǍƛ[t
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C3%B8W%C7%8D%C6%9B%5Bt&inputs=%22asdf%20jkl%3B__zxcv%7E%3C%20vbnm%2C.qwer%7C%20%7Cuiop%22&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
øW      # Group words together
  Ǎ     # Remove non-alphabet characters
   ƛ    # For each remaining string:
    [   #   If it is not empty:
     t  #     Tail
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDuFfHjXZ04oiRIiwiIiwiYXNkZiBqa2w7X196eGN2fjwgdmJubSwucXdlcnwgfHVpb3AiXQ==) for a flagless 6

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>51</s>  50 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub("([a-zA-Z])*|.","\\1",s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BboMwEEX3nGLECipAiroKKZXaI2TZUlkYBnBqbNczQBqhXp0G1Ep/8aR587/75t6ax7UtylVXg2wqoNxjRqOMwui9Sm8v6dtH/LBkYRKW5SFMKA7U4Kxn8LjOvdIIhzwARuIE8OqwZmygAGXcyFGckdOKoxDSZwjjAJxXhqM22vw4gT8oiv/PeK2oaeHyqU9C3K719PMEkzRDkn3N6BdYRmXdVtbqafAucKqj@27F0NiOTju9WpnvsB03l5hYMgXa2hpI3dMzJJ1RrPwMSB4nPG9irXg@B8ejkJZZIwnbConohTWCexRzpfVe2HqD@hc)

### How it works:

- `([a-zA-Z])*` will match a whole word capturing every single char in group 1 (one at a time).
- if no words are found, `.` match the char to discard it
- `re.sub(<pattern>,"\\1",s)` substitute every occurence of our pattern by the content of capturing group 1 (the last char of the word since it only captures one char at a time)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
áмS¡€θJ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MILe4IPLXzUtObcDq///xOLU9IUsrJzrOPjqyqSy@psFMqS8nJ19ArLU4tqFGpKM/MLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l4Qn/Dy@8sCf40MJHTWvO7fD6r/M/sTglTSErO8c6Pr6qIrmszkahLCkvV0evsDy1qEahpjQzv4CrIDO9WEchNbFEISU/vdgazHLKT7ICM0CSXDn5@ckKxZlAlFGioJOel1mSWVSukFpclFqWGsRlaRmflF9SkpNaHJ@fFp@UmloUn58XX5KRGl@emJMDAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
á       # Only keep all letters of the (implicit) input-string
 м      # Remove all those letters from the (implicit) input-string
  S     # Convert it to a list of characters
   ¡    # Split the (implicit) input-string by those characters,
        # so only empty strings and strings consisting of letters are left in the list
    €θ  # Only keep the last character of each string
      J # Join it together to a single string
        # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 134 bytes

```go
import."regexp"
func f(s string)(o string){for _,e:=range MustCompile(`[A-Za-z]+`).FindAllString(s,-1){o+=string(e[len(e)-1])}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVBLTsMwEN37FKOsYjWp1B1NyaIgsUNCsKOqXCedpKaOHWynrZqGJZdgUyFxCM7BituQD5VGmqf5vHnzPj5zff4uebrlOULBhSKiKLVxYy8rnPdVuSy8-n2_1AzmeCg9klUqhcy3YJ0RKqe-vqA60wZYgFFsuGop7yvrbnVRCon-ajEPn3l4XI5WdHwn1Hou5VO_5tsgnNBaj-KBxseFROUjDSdL2hCDrjKq-Vfz01_vtPoUamJtFC-Ww17tcbvO4GUrZ4wdD-nu7Rp2iSqC8esezQlOldClF4BXitwGgNzBWud21qMbnUQ96JrdkNQ6BSva2DgIciWcMHtAa3CHj93AdMoS7ZxEy3TGEkTDtGJug2zPpfQaMphhIYphsMPamjy0Sp1U7c-dhZSShvy_dj4P-Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 36 bytes

```powershell
-join($args-split'[^a-z]'|%{$_[-1]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9Nb4JAEIbP8CsmhFZNoEmP1pqYmvTaRnszdgPrAGtXFncWMAr963Txq8kcZnae95lsoWrUlKGUIVcaOz@Znrpwq0Q@9COdUkiFFGaw@o7C43rQPJx8tgqf1@2oa113NnSdYDb0ItoksP2RE8aOB179vkIV57vgaW/dDTSlUIUXgJfIaqcLb3QJFSKlADAysFEpTc7dm4pfzk2/7CNkyMSGbhmpFAcStjIDQZoLI3QNSBorXPQ8F6Ze3OjxmMXKGInEVMJiRM1UzkyGrI6kPOsTnaO0/AgaeLf/j3gWfsRb5AZOruMbJDOPCAPw8VDYV9zAFHxmVxqplMZOj34Cd9B1Vp/LeUlG7S6a9cx6nGXJORL12bsnxD1cLZb4ugp65F/mLG5X7mTrtm73Bw)

1. Case insensitive split on non alphabetical characters
2. Get the last character of each word
3. Join them in a string