# Mode length of a sentence

Tags: code-golf, string, statistics

The task is simple. You are given a string with **alphabetical words** (say `"Hello world, this are tests"`). You have to return the [**mode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) of the lengths of words in the string. In this case, output is `5`, as it's the *most often length* of words in the string.

Definition of an alphabetical word (for this challenge): a string that consists of `a-zA-Z` only.

#### Sample I/O:

**Constraints:** Input has *atleast* one word, and a *unique* mode. Max. length is provided in last test case. Also, the string would be a single line, no newline chars.

(`In = Out` format)

```
"Hello world, this are tests"                     =  5
"Hello    world, this... are tests"               =  5
"I"                                               =  1
"Let's box (ง︡'-'︠)ง"                               =  3
"Writing some ✍(◔◡◔) program"                   =  7
"the-the-the-then"                                =  3
"Gooooooooogle is an app"                         =  2
"()<>a+/sentence$#@(@with::many---_symbols{}|~~"  =  4
"anot_her test actually"                          =  4
```

<sub>The unicode tests are *optional*.</sub>

[1000 words string](https://www.protectedtext.com/lorem-ipsum) = 5 (Password: `PXuCdMj5u65vwst`)

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

Comment: I don't understand the "hidden test" - who are you hiding it from? Why isn't the answer for it included in the question?

Comment: Why does not the regex for alpha*numeric* words accept numbers?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate, the alphanumeric was a typo, edited it.

Comment: Do we really need to handle Unicode chars? It doesn't seem to add anything to the challenge, and it leaves some languages out

Comment: @LuisMendo, made them optional now.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

-1 byte inspired by [Jonathan Allans Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209328/64121).
-2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

Input is a list of characters.

```
aγO0K.M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/8dxmfwNvPd///6OVNJR0lDSB2AaI7YA4EYi1gVgfiIuBOBWI84C4BImdDGWrALEyEDsAsQaULgfiTKj6DCC2guJcqNkg/ZVArIuE46F2VULVJQFxPhDnQMWrgbgWiGuAuA6MYwE)

#### Commented:

```
aγO0K.M     implicit input       ["a","b"," ","c","d"," ","e","."]

a           is_alpha (vectorizes)[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 γ          split into chunks of equal elements
              [[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0], [1], [0]]
  O         sum the lists        [2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0]
   0K       remove 0's
     .M     mode                 2

            implicit output      2
```

`a` is implemented as `Regex.match?(~r/^[a-zA-Z]+$/, to_string(x))`, which should be equivalent to the challenge specification.

<s>I feel like there has to be a shorter way to remove `0`s from a list than `ʒĀ}`.</s>

Comment: There indeed is a shorter way to remove 0s: `0K`. ;) Also, you can save 1 more byte by taking the input as a list of characters, so the `€` isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks a lot. I searched the wiki for *remove*, *delete* and *filter*, but *without* didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Yeah, the descriptions of the builtins are sometimes a bit counter-intuitive to search for unfortunately. :/ I had the same issue for the longest time at first. Luckily I now know almost all builtins out of the top of my head, give or take a few, since I golf so much in 05AB1E.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>70</strike> <s>68</s> 58 bytes

```ruby
->s{(s=s.scan(/[a-z]+/i).map &:size).max_by{|y|s.count y}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7BasJAEL37FYMtNUF3vYcq3tpC7z0EkU26msBmN@yM6JrEa0@9Fbz0UP/Czyn@gJ8Q3YJgH8xjZt578Owyce181LIxVgGOkGMqdDCMBdtM@8M85IUo4SHCfCP9vp4lrqpdjTw1S03gmqaNO91nqZSBlbHqfQCU5QjCSiCJhN3BVb7gxsE5/2968fQqqYeQmDUEv4eP02HfY73T4Se8HF5@sznlegFoCgnH78/guPs67vYXDqG0ZmFF4W2USXYz2v@ezBULJcE31CDK0ktB@DgW/SFKTVKn8v5uEkxWOWVRVAjtGGMzdEViFFZNvd36hNCGZpm0f@1BpLQUSrluZ8qlSLMKaqqhhHlMU2jaMw)

-20 bytes from Dingus.

-2 bytes from Rahul Verma.

-10 bytes from Dingus(again) by removing a variable.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 90 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.split(/\W+/).map(&:size).inject(Hash.new(0)){|h,v|h[v]+=1;h}.sort_by{|k,v|v}[-1][0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVnLrhy3EV1HX0EoQXQvxDuyt3JsOMjLAhLHgSB7cSMYnG7ODJV@qUmOrqIrb7PKLoA3WcR/oc8J9AP@BKWeJFtJgCCABWjkme4mq06dOnXYXvP@5bvDx@@uPnGv3C4uQ0gXD/741f0Hl7vRLRc/fRjDn/3lLkzPfJcuPnPxtJv8i4sPLi9f3Z7s@fZ0fX56/@MPPzq93sV5TV/vX766/RP8fn59ffXh0@sPnr5@d333Mz8Ms3kxr0NvTTqFaNzqTfIxxbv2jlyGP80du91ue9Mj/PitT/ei2c835uKfb/7y/Zvv7l3d@/7NPy7hC17@ag0pTEcT59Gbt3//68Xbb//29tvv4PPSLOt8XN2It6WTv2r@Tvjbb2b9cxy8wQgn45YFL11c/uwTd/9B9FPyU@d/8uNPLz59EdLp4cPRTS@vrq6@ji/H/TzEV69vv/mGwpxXP5qwxDyafh7m1cSQjBt9sqabpwhQ@pRX4/qwhNhhyB6A35nfzes@wC3jOPezcblL8Kyfwrgzn@dhcObgujCEGPQ7RN@vHtLGdc9ugGvm4PHT53arnfm5nzzk5A@H0AXcfHBdBizDHpaAOId5D/WDB@Pcu8FH2MGN5nmGX0aXV0QkGb/ChxvC8wzXoh8Xv5rJd/L3efY78wUUE5GK8M2c3D4kNyUzUmIJlkkBLwCYEBns7xM8KP8x4r7Z9Zjm6GHDzkCgCyZzBBq4qACFCe5NGOwA4a/zznwJ18M@D5AIMKALfYZNOUNKwa1dhmduwohbDT4cIGsARVJxzVPRLcFPtqR5hlAnlwiH4@QE@dEcwgQ7RjPlqTNLXnO0GFgeIMsuQPgDsWCZY/ZA5DDtzK9z7LwCTKANjMIZUIILcBkIkfRGirzWlba3AF0PJc7HAKXAAJUK0R0DYmKVcnCfhxWASiVjq4AybiZgBfsA2M99mC2WuOXnGVlZapAUgC9W57EblGnrDJu6rstjBIblZM5uDZgV/WOh@AOWxwPMg5@b59fTPGGJyrNTiIOZZi3vzvxidXDZjIHR3Jnfr13Q9aEqM5Jpofrsc4kRgurh7@JWiD144h9S0sIjACymtoY@dMAXgDVHBVzh0kJIgk7xVv4BLmY5gTyl1UH9AX1MaobqB9hmxXYCbpwgbCulPazQ5AHLRBg2VIe1YFnuMNnfinQA/895WHJyycN9JwwYCODyEZIGZUBxgHLhN@S3ZcIkaEu4QLQcwhEewbJK6R4TKRhnKMuAdIEl@jACSkWtHOjUAtmFLCqGEfoOYI7l9y6vEdFzMUJMXDNpr5taUGT9I8DkCEKxQD@SgMC3wp1U9eZxjlBJKFz0jUwxXvxIAVGaSuuh9bIsQhSNxEd0hjaBaxAX0LA0JFaIOlb7UXkO99TtKUzGDfuVBRDYBQJQOz0iknh/j/lyTNhKHAJpwza9pskstV7p0I0IstYjbbGYnJviz6Wllu1BsYj9GJyUnKjgb4CXJxdBkhmKWmd5ZKZ2AjoD/QeYI5E0/HPcDvqYruroQr1XckHv4CoiW4BNoi2a1q7gLHk4h8mBmoSzX1dXp1yDASsNFnZNDsHgOC1V41mOaZZLyFyoWq8jQRibVyBJYV30LWMbhPocRFNKVrXUFINlStZ68hRpcXRlaMBkQ1GTkpQZW9bmTiXNQwIxXHXSTDTIm9FF63HvL2sYoYKw/wFsQK3VkHVsMsIIsBC6y3vgi0PaOf@RSBoxFXaw6iZKuEQRW3UMy4gBtKnmVBtIwn00NRNRxhc/9ssZO0S0mWuGP5BCqILinGj6WMZQkddfJWqsRMVOAePF7qBdhXPFsHC7woKG5nE3r@hGCEIdj7A9hCVTtHB/U12eoBy6Lm0lekREvZiibZlqOPMaHKjQlFu1OEzMouQjuhzmAfjQc@gdNRTkSlfqKLaNdFBHrzmtyK6Ns9LRyQ@XwUXehRmKK5FsaqewH2HXVkZOtRfCrBnSQ2V9klpN@DdBLhw/@JVx3SqcdJwlY4v9WmRAjablKQTrI9GaEqLftf@pQWmmkloCnq31gYmmhqYvMi6QaOF0xrsyFeFeqqVYSdYXnOE96W11h@d5yGlB4U/ST6n2/Jfh7HDqcR70aat0Y2iVJlgOW5eDvUiQilLpBNV/afcCcJPKhgoQr@ob9yNNteJE@PhQ9ijTrhD1vyxbxvWy2UxpqtjL4YBckG38Spj0gJAh55pErSu0EPdDlSCmbwDFHcjDtemz8y0az@ZeqiwjC1e9qdNDY6sS1prbEkj14SIWZRaL/yWn1Zh7r9XeDw7ojpOx5@OSdjbxikYwiqYeFRpS1ynPDVy@q5FUu8fAYrawRkG7wGwp@hIWjYhaT5lHaIeKpcXQtq1aG5LEs1U9rqDl4xN/8BSR8w6uXCqCo5paFDiPgZBqn6Df@BSIWwGnknci5TG9xzhZuxwCCP2CDBWglIZu2hxwWcPZ1IpX2sifxlkPkdIgLPYgxNgpon8b0rcTUU99qN044RGTMqzem24cRCNtjRdGsbHY/kyrqn56aCKEVcxaJUZR4LJXXvOs4UlbPCA3V7Ub1MxyoEcJr@OOcFJbQKNt62jlxFtPi2zeea3iSZRH71WVUdBTdZtqlYIbzMc2Sok@M0d130W81ANI3wF8TU/pAZhHRPEJuUjVRsjKPJKT0ZNUGVGusa1l5RFisO7UsYnYKfnQlsYkivtD@Tr2SAJQff@DZ02qo4LDbGjc5jwxI0K/sUNkT/@QmVxFeolQXpkl1l3sfx169T1EYRVkxrEpKEXd8ZjBQQU9nhUbwtaYDzB80OeHpeBtvDJiWzWm57QzXXl/wsZJOgmy1tcSKp5bGZS7K2DlCKPBNK8pUOWOXkGWQbdtGsWoMdDEQjxSsAGRx8TKNX6jtAGd@/hUz8f9@iKHftWx0JyQSrfS@x9UUMRdmrCREUkXTVDzYgdHz6ZNWPSbJNQWkLrXwYMtJ5X7Yd8ACv2bdfribPt622bACUr81rJiYBtvSXqebWE6sQzOitBze7qhquWknrMP@KophiYcK/OctpLDspwrAelqC/k61xTwl91kXkPW2sT@phG4tpPwLaHypby6bbSetnRKeSGciAw1GxsWXKvIFElIruqH/ku5z7lYDpy7tYTTdKfVrcSoCMXVQvGD29d9tCLqIWs9S3XNBEekHK@aIYW/qulFgX9M1lBVEQPnVOT2MbQznF/i0BszNv1ObYOjF/Ry4lPn97/4mEbsqTFVR0n02ScVPy0vyp9UyapWW08VjEIxgUxwfQGsfJAWFqir7aVjb2Uu@1AmLcbatoZQVMOFcpGyKrSsK80MwZXbwdaJE@bxXl9klr7CechjGo1@eQOIulRfEdUR7XTMCnCh9Zd0YGA6Uk6FqPz@ob7wQc3it9KaiCspQilsozNZx7XYbiLoxkbrS44yr4uzEDZLn0jzVu/A3U2nCypfPQNJd@/M//0/itoaVltGsNKcv/t05113gkXN7bPbOz9azOH62dM78Mi7fwE)

Comment: Ah, you made a separate range. Nice.

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU7LasJAFN37FRdb6gSdsWtbxV1b6L4LEblJRzMwmQkzE0xM4rar7gpuuqh/4eeIP@AnpJmCYA/cA/c84JgsLJrluKETW@LYMhuhIsMZ0s28PxQBSzAldyMrNjx4IPeMYavkXs4XYVFWokIW6Uw5EHXdzDrdZy6lhrU28n0ALhYW0HBw3DrbHVzsFlcJxtj/0IunV@56FkKdAzkePs6HfY/2zoefoH28/WaEE2oFViccTt@f5LT7Ou32LQeQGr0ymPiYizm9OuW1J33BSnLwCxVgmnqLBI8T7A8tV46riN/eTMl0LVw8GiWoCkrpwhZJqKUt62q79Q1U2i1ibv7WA0YuQymLbmfOOEZxCZWrIIXlzM2hbn4B), used scan.

Comment: [Squeezed off another 6 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU7BasJAFLz7FQ9bMEF3vUsVb22h9x5EZJM@TWCzG/atmDUbrz31VvDSQ/0LP6f4A35C6hYEO/AG5s0MjFknrl2OWzahOqIxcUqFioYzwbbz/jCPeSHK2le@4pRvsQm6WiSu9s4TT/VaWXBN08463SeUUsNGG/k2AJvlBMIgWCRL3cHVvuAmwTn/H3oO9IK2R5DoCqKf4/v5eOix3vn4HV9EsF9NbnO1AtIFwunrIzrtP0/7w4VjKI1eGVGEmM2Q3ZwKv0d9xUoihIUKRFkGK4ofJqI/JFQWVYr3d9NousltNhoVQjnG2IJckWhJdeN3u9AQSttFhuZvPYjUroWUrtuZcxRpVoO3HkpYzuwcmvYX)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU7BasJAEL37FYMtNUF3vYcq3tpC7z0EkU26msBmN@yM6JrEa0@9Fbz0UP/Czyn@gJ8Q3YJgH8xjZt578Owyce181LIxVgGOkGMqdDCMBdtM@8M85IUo4SHCfCP9vp4lrqpdjTw1S03gmqaNO91nqZSBlbHqfQCU5QjCSiCJhN3BVb7gxsE5/2968fQqqYeQmDUEv4eP02HfY73T4Se8HF5@sznlegFoCgnH78/guPs67vYXDqG0ZmFF4W2USXYz2v@ezBULJcE31CDK0ktB@DgW/SFKTVKn8v5uEkxWOWVRVAjtGGMzdEViFFZNvd36hNCGZpm0f@1BpLQUSrluZ8qlSLMKaqqhhHlMU2jaMw) by squeezing another 4 bytes off Rahul Verma's latest version.

Comment: nice golf. I'll put it in.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 30 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/)

```apl
{⍵[⊃⍒+/∘.=⍨⍵]}≢¨⊆⍨⎕A∊⍨1(819⌶)⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BSsNAEIbvfYoFhU2oSclNi0o9qeDdg0jZttsksNkN2ZUaansR2liMFFHqwYP11AdQydknkXmBPkLcCMIi/jDDzD/fDAyJmdNLCRN@Cdm0Xw4hfz@D2TXk9/UGZE/uHuQr7Z2P4Ob1cwWzSdXfPR5ANtOVZ217O3D7YWurOlD2a7qCyRwfUcYEGoiE9baQCkKJSEKRolJJXPtDaRmg67r/sR7kb/jY2D2hCmOJOuISWV/FdF0sMXYwXhcvtm4N8DQJVch9JEVEETznFiweYLHU2UZxIvyERAatAuoYwY3RofiVzyiqXuKIxLFBWPbuPqk3JOWK8i7d3GhZrUGogmYzIjx1HKct06gjmByOrsZjY5FwodoBTX6@RqSrLghjKf4G)

```apl
{⍵[⊃⍒+/∘.=⍨⍵]}≢¨⊆⍨⎕A∊⍨1(819⌶)⎕ ⍝ Full program
1(819⌶)⎕ ⍝ Uppercase the input
⎕A∊⍨     ⍝ Test if each character is a capital letter
⊆⍨       ⍝ Group the letters together
≢¨       ⍝ Length of each word
{⍵[⊃⍒+/∘.=⍨⍵]} ⍝ Mode
```

The mode dfn is by [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/43008/68261). My approach was similar but one byte longer: `{⊃⍵[⍒+/¨⍵⍷¨⊂⍵]}`.

Comment: You can replace `(819⌶)` with [`⎕C`](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/c.htm) in 18.0, though TIO isn't updated yet.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>79</s> 67 bytes

*Edit: -9 and then -3 more bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
names(sort(-table(nchar(el(strsplit(scan(,''),"[^a-zA-Z]+"))))))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcHhCoJADADgd7HAHTqivxJhr5FYzGOgcDfjNgi1fPUL@r6Us1BkBZ2TARoNgUH8SAk4gFrSV5gM1JNAXZauLroH4XrDe18V7q879xnc5UrVSVmMxfPx0EL7nmxsmkiyIOJTlzjMQbfvZ9/zDw)

Commented:

```r
names(              # Get the names (=values) of...
  sort(-            # the descending (-) frequencies of...
    table(          # the table of values of...
     (w=nchar(      # the number of characters of...
       strsplit(scan(,''),
                    # the input, grouped by splitting on...
       "[^a-zA-Z0-9]")[[1]]))
                    # non-alphanumeric characters...
     [w>0]          # ignoring zero-length groups.
    )               
  )
)[1]                # Output the first name, which is
                    # the most-frequent number of characters
                    # per group.
```

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcFtCoJAEADQu1jgLDpUP5MIu0ZiMS4DCrtj7AyEfXj1DXov5SwUWUHnZIBGQ2AQP1ICDqCW9BEmA/UkUJelq4vuRvi64HWPx74q3F936DO405mqnbIYi@ftpoX2OdnYNJFkQcS7LnGYg76/n3XNPw); it's a shame that `"\\W+"` wouldn't work since it includes `_`

Comment: actually, is the `0-9` needed since a word consists only of `[a-zA-Z]+`?

Comment: 1) Thanks!  I obviously need a bit of practice at regexes!

Comment: 2) Not any more.  The question originally specified 'alphanumeric', but I notice that it's now been edited to 'alphabetic' so you're right.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(o=/[a-z]+/gi,w=>o[s]>(o[n=w.length]=-~o[n])?0:s=n)&&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdHNSsNAEAfwu0@xVGl3aTfxE6GY2JsK3j2UINt0mkQ2uyGzGOtHr568Cb14sG@Rx5G@QB8hJoJQQlr9ww7M5Tcz7J24F@inUWK40mMoJk6BjotWCokUPlDt2EPBH72uHUS9zHH1ED2X6qFyMkuCCkzoOXxW9h473@@jo1i7jYWvFWoJltQBndDWJUipSaZTOe4RE0ZIRArEABpsMUaaYtuEnOw0OmXWKMuytmmNztWmqZtTOQd15xpMB8lIPxD6lb@u8kWHd1b5JyubvydU4lFdvEkjE6mAoI6BLD/e6HL@vpwvyspIkuogFXGzXGmndc2EwNee@sfZjVtd6N8EEkj1fYqIJNnGVc5h3aHszBVdG0EZUD7s7Q7oIItM2O/HQk0557c4jUda4tPL82z2w1fOcfEN)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
e€ØẠŒg§ḟ0Æṃ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdOawzMe7lpwdFL6oeUPd8w3ONz2cGfz////lRLz8kviM1KLFEpSi0sUEpNLShOBWpQA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdOawzMe7lpwdFL6oeUPd8w3ONz2cGfz/8PtQIn//6O5lDyACvMVyvOLclJ0FEoyMosVEotSFUpSi0uKlXRg0kCApEJPTw9VkSeI8EktUS9WSMqvUNB4sKP9/Y6F6rrq73cs0ARyQNLhRZklmXnpCsX5uakKj@b0ajyaPuXR9IVAUlOhoCg/vSgxF6SsJCNVFwnngcTc82EgPSdVAeTCPIXEggKQlIamjV2itn5xal5Jal5yqoqyg4ZDeWZJhpVVbmJepa6ubnxxZW5Sfk5xdW1NXR1IR2Jefkl8RmoR2PUKicklpYnAkALKxAIA).

#### How?

```
e€ØẠŒg§ḟ0Æṃ - Link: S
  ØẠ        - alphabetic characters
 €          - for each (c in S)
e           -   (c) exists in (S)?
    Œg      - group runs of equal elements (1s or 0s)
      §     - sums
        0   - zero
       ḟ    - filter discard
         Æṃ - mode
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
M!i`[a-z]+
%M`.
O#`
O#^$`(.+)(¶\1)*
$#2
1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NSsNAHMTv@xR/SUo2xl2pxyLSWxUsHj340WzrnySw2Q27KzV@9OrJm9CLB/sSkrNPInmBPkJcFSEDMzDMHH4GXaFEN6CTtJvuFOmFYPdXCRlMU07OgtT7OkwpT2L6@XE5jHdJGByQoT93xyilhqU28mYPXF5YEAbBoXWW/G1evZlz3nuckFN0kYW5vgP61Txvm03Eom3zHvtCzk3hsTKwukRo315ou35t1xufMVRGZ0aUxOXIelZkov@VSYQfHgWiqgiND49Esm9ROVQLDIMxHS8Ll49GpVA1Y2xm63KupX14elytiFDazXI0v6AgFu5WSFl/Aw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
M!i`[a-z]+
```

List only the words.

```
%M`.
```

Take the length of each word.

```
O#`
```

Sort the lengths numerically.

```
O#^$`(.+)(¶\1)*
$#2
```

Sort in reverse order of frequency.

```
1G`
```

Take the mode.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF'[^A-Za-z]+'`, 51 bytes

```perl
map$k{y///c}++,@F;$_=(sort{$k{$b}-$k{$a}}keys%k)[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjdCoIwGADQh2nhZH3NLryxH@zGu14gMZkyUHQ/uEGsNR@9VVcHjubLnMcomEaTd5TSPhCyK6sjas/YqMX636MuwB8WwsSd2U5pnTUx4vR0YYQaLi2XPUebEpfP0Q5FIZh0ANAaJzo1Gx/e6/pR2o5Kmgi3fJ8dsgh6rpL6cYU7g1dDki8)

Comment: Nice, just made pretty much the same too! You can shave a few bytes using `%;` as the name of the hash, using `for` instead of `map...,...` and using `($_)=<list>` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnBDoIgGADgh4kmjv3j1EWr4cWHyJVDR8ulwPjZGhI@elSn7/BZ5eZDzqSOgXM@Jsbuxom2pqQvT2icj78iQ4I/MqWnCrjPmZbHs2QclfZKj4rsBBWvyT@qapE6AECPYRnMjDG9t@1jrJ@Mxgy2LbpbAxcJ65UVXw "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, not that it matters, but I think `\Pl` should be equivalent to `[^A-Za-z]`>

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
3Y4XXzXM
```

Supports ASCII characters only. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zjSJCKiKsL3/3/1xLz8kviM1CKFktTiEoXE5JLSxJycSnUA) Or [verify all ASCII test cases](https://tio.run/##VU27CsIwFN39ioBCK5o66FREOgjq4OZQp3rViyncJqW5Uuqjvx6jKNQDZznPApjcwU33szS9pVu33LlgjURG1Kai81iwyq2ACgWjZRv0vq5HJxBF0V9m48kKZYfaSyvzw4VQvHe1gLL0TjicL2A0sagZ9QkH/SRM6pxVHBegGyllZpviaMjen4@29QXQhjOF1edSwImvQNQELw).

#### How it works

```
3Y4   % Push predefined literal '[A-Za-z]+'
XX    % Implicit input. Regexp. Gives cell array of matched substrings
z     % Number of nonzero chars of each substring
XM    % Mode. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>148</s> <s>143</s> <s>140</s> <s>132</s> <s>100</s> 99 bytes

```python
n,*c=0,
for x in input()+'1':
 if'`'<x.lower()<'{':n+=1
 elif n:c+=n,;n=0
print(max(c,key=c.count))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvRCoMgFADQd79C2ECd1oq9uRz9ydbESGbXKKOkrV93wXk9Qwydh1tKIC5aFQK1fsQrtnAY5kAZJyWRCNuWvEi15s4vZqSsIhuRwFWJsHG2xSA1VyDuoAo0jBYC7ZuVavExUelc@xkCYykd8dHw62QgGNDmfKppvdjQSdk3ELMse06xf3s3bb/vvv8B)

Uses regex to check if character is a letter of the English alphabet and adds the count of all consecutive alphabets to a list and finds the mode of that list.

*-3 bytes thanks to Rahul Verma*

*-32 bytes thanks to ovs*

*-1 byte thanks to DLosc*

Comment: Also, you could just write `import re` and `re.match`. Result: -3 bytes.

Comment: @DLosc isalpha() returns True for some non-English characters as well. Check out the 4th example.

Comment: you can create lists with `[*...]`, the `re.match` can be replaced by `'`'<s.pop(0).lower()<'{'` and appending to a list is shorter with `+=`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvRDoIgFADQd7/CrTYg0XS9kTT/w7kyhpOFFyY4Y5a/Tp33Y4MfDVxidFRQ4O1JgV08JhmqUEfbjpbJOiotU8eSVA3ogWpXWGNxSQptVjljUqMNMch4laRSqyEFJjIO9Aq8TOyswOOpf2NBXzJwUQizgCckxn@89dnZSfAShDweGtysyo@MTT2EPM/vLkxPo932/ez7Dw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: And a `for`-loop is more fitting here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvRCoMgFADQd79C2EBFa8XeXI7@Y4ytiZFU1yijpK1fd8F5PUPwjYNrjFqAejxFhmo34hVbOAyzp4yTnEiEbU3epFjTzi1mpKwgG5HAVY6w6WyNQWquQNxAZWgYLXjaVyvVojVB6VS7GTxjMR7xXvHLZMAb0OZ8Kmm5WN9I2VcQkiR5TaH/uG7aft99/wM "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Hm. I was going by "The unicode tests are optional," but fair enough. In any case, you can save 1 more byte using [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42123/16766): change the first line to `n,*c=0,`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

```
aMR:+XA#_(_NaSKav)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0TfISjvCUTleI94vMdg7sUzz////Gpo2dona@sWpeSWpecmpKsoOGg7lmSUZVla5iXmVurq68cWVuUn5OcXVtTV1dQA)

#### Explanation

```
aMR:+XA#_(_NaSKav)
                    a is 1st cmdline arg; v is -1 (implicit)
aMR:                Map a function to each regex match in a and assign the result back to a
    +XA              Regex: a letter (XA) repeated one or more times (+)
       #_            The function: length of the match
                    Now we just need to get the mode:
             SKa    Sort a using this key function:
          _Na        Count of each element in the full list a
         (      v)  Since it's now sorted from least common to most, get the last element
```

If Pip had a two-byte builtin for getting the mode of a list, I could do this in 10 bytes: `MO#*Ya@+XA` (with `MO` being the mode builtin). Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>12</s></sup> 8 bytes

```
►=mLmf√w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Xba5Prlpjzpmlf///98jNScnX6E8vygnRUehJCOzWCGxKFWhJLW4pBgA)

Previous answer was badly optimized.(-4 bytes)

From Zgarb:

> ► has a second mode. If you give it a binary function f, it returns an element x that maximizes the number of elements y for which fxy holds.

> So ►= is a 2-byte max by frequency.

### Explanation

```
►=fImLmf√ġK√
         ġK√ group string on non alphabet-characters.
       f√    filter out non-alphabet characters
      m      map that to each word ↑
    mL       Length of each word
  fI         filter out zeroes (empty string length)
►=           max by frequency
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 66 bytes

```
"[a-zA-Z]+".r.findAllIn(_).toSeq.groupBy(_.size)maxBy(_._2.size)_1
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JBEhqkOXTjSKfbRejhGaOg)

Unfortunately, finding the mode in Scala is a bit clumsy

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 141 bytes

A really awful solution... just 2 bytes shorter than the Python one. 3

```
method(x,x asUppercase asList map(i,if(if(i at(0),i at(0),0)isLetter,1,0))join split("0")map(size)remove(0)uniqueCount map(reverse)max at(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBLTgJBEIb3nqIymtAdZxC3RA2JCzVha9yYkAYKpk0/xu4aGHywdeXOhI0LuQXHMVyAI4w9GpRZWKl@/Knvr1S3tOUI2qdwW2qk1A5ZERcg/HWWoRsIj@HelZ5Ai4zJWI5YlSCItXi8PVtc@i4SoYuPg@B3VhrwmZLEolbEK6uXD8gdajvB4MiNvM/x3Obmp7HDCTqPgSyqlseclyMWXaJSFqbWqWEMlEoPwiEQevIRh8xJQ8rs/YIhdthms/kfflWXYfKGh74tgH2uXjarZSNpbFYfPIg6eOMkSTMGbzXC@v2VrRdv68Uy7BVmx07ouoFSTHaWqVcv7DbGCqF6nQGRZXWI8ZMzcXjk0RCaAR7sd1hnKiltt7UwsyRJen6m@1b5x@en@bzuFcZSL0X3/QcgBpQLpWZ/TPkF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 129 bytes

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!*

```java
s->{int m=0,z=s.length()+1,a[]=new int[z];for(var x:s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+"))a[x.length()]++;for(;z-->0;m=a[z]>a[m]?z:m);return m;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHNbtNAEMfvPMUqIMWWs0u5xrUpF6ASB6QekGqZauJs7A37Ye2Ok9ghvXLihtQLB/oWeRyUF@gjhI0LiIsZab/0//9mRrNLWAFdzj8dCwnOkffbuplJURCHgP5YGTEnCoQOrtAKXWZ5GW5XYIlJrlqHXDHTYLz0SViDQrJFowsURrPXvy/nj9zkUiMvuU0XydHRdCs0EpWcTbrEMcl1iVUQRi8mkOWJ5mvi5azL44WxwanYZuqYq6XAYJR9BNq9otd5NApDyDZ/6TyKen/cUZqexSoBnyGFTOUvu6kKY8uxsZqoeBcfDat9Uyh1sGBQ17INRm@5lIasjZVzgpVwBCwnzihOkDt0vlj8ZBDz0ZOTHmWM9fR/wcsh4R3HsSMzsyHBz/2Xh/39mI4f9j9C/xhCPliBfsaP7R6@fw0Od98Od/d@D0ltTWlBDaFYcfrP0kO@N@ZPlJKT03g08dKQPQjPU4ieO@5/XRf82dOL4GItsJpOFeiWUnrjWjUz0m13n29vh7KANnhTcdtPkkCBDUjZnty73fEX)

---

Explanation:

```java
s -> {
  int m=0,             //m is the index of the max element in a
      z=s.length()+1,  //z is to avoid using a.length twice
      a[]=new int[z];  //Each index corresponds to a length, and the element at that index its frequency
  for(var x : s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")) //Fill up the pigeonholes
    a[x.length()]++;
  for(;                 //Find the index of the max element/highest frequency/mode
      z-->0;            //For every index from a.length to 0,
      m=a[z]>a[m]?z:m); //If the current element is greater than the current max frequency, change the mode length
  return m;             //Return the length with the highest frequency
};
```

Comment: [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZG9btswEMf3PAWhFjAJm4xnK1LTpW0ADQEyBIgTBLRMS3T5IZAnp6oir5m6FcjSoXkLP07gF8gjOIyTAl2UA/h19/8dDn8u@YrT5fz7Llfce3TaVvVMyRx54BCOlZVzpLk0@AycNMX0qiDtijtkk7PGg9DM1hAvQxNWg1RsUZscpDXsy9vl6JUbnRgQhXDpItl5mrbSANLJeKQSz5QwBZSYjCAksmQcL6zDsUrHcZZAqj9hnQCheqgmGYGg95WSgKPLy9mU05@f6cVVGw0VpcOoC7mIvDWMnYDaGbrO4m4XH1hWhUFAGbxgvKpUg6NvQimLbqxTcwSl9Ig7gbzVAoHw4CNC3sFC7MnRHmWM7el3wZO@QiZg4NHM/kD4cXP3tHkY0MHT5i8Jjz7k3EkIvr6Ou/3zC2/vf2/vH8JOUOVs4bjuQ6EU9L9l@nRf7b8olEAv9hgUSn1yTI5SPjz0Ivy0ycXHD8f4@EZCOZlobhpK6bVv9Mwq33a363VfF24sXJfC7Z1EPIeaK9W8qLtu9ww)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire That's a really cool approach! Do you want to make your own answer?

Comment: Indeed, the approach is different, so I understand you don't want to use it as your own. [I've posted it as my own answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209388/16236)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
q\L f üÊñÊÌÌÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=cVxMIGYg/MrxyszMyg&input=IigpPD5hKy9zZW50ZW5jZSQjQChAd2l0aDo6bWFueS0tLV9zeW1ib2xze318fn4i)

```
q\L f üÊñÊÌÌÊ     :Implicit input of string U    e.g., "()<>a+/sentence$#@(@with::many---_symbols{}|~~"
q                 :Split on
 \L               :  Regex /[^a-z]/i             ["","","","","a","","sentence","","","","","with","","many","","","","symbols","","","","",""]
    f             :Filter (remove empty strings) ["a","sentence","with","many","symbols"]
      ü           :Group & sort by
       Ê          :  Length                      [["a"],["with","many"],["symbols"],["sentence"]]
        ñ         :Sort by
         Ê        :  Length                      [["a"],["symbols"],["sentence"],["with","many"]]
          Ì       :Last element                  ["with","many"]
           Ì      :Last element                  "many"
            Ê     :Length                        4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>115</s> <s>113</s> 112 bytes

-1 byte ceilingcat

```c
m;n;w;c;l;i;f(char*s){for(m=n=l=0;s[l++];m=c>n?n=c,l:m)for(i=w=c=0;w=isalpha(s[i])?1+w:w-l?0:!++c,s[i++];);n=m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVlrjxu3Ff3uX8GqDaDtctWkjy@rKk7Rp4E2TWE4X@IgoGYoie085CGpXcN1/rp7nyTl2m1RIAt4H5oheXnuuece0t3dsevevRu30/Zh222Hbdge1t3JLT@NN28O87Ied9Nu2H26jd8Mt7ffbsdd9/n0dNp1drgfb/CFsHvYdfDCwy5EN5xPbh2/Cd/ePP3s9uH@4W54@un9j25vOwsf4vib7bQbt2/fJR@TrJMWa8KUTHfy3T9uzJsnhv5cfDQ7c1jD85utfHZ2ET@kRzsegI/OCzw8rFefxHvzSW/WL@G3lysLv9@8nOAnDnu6wu@r@9XBhQE@gzmsobV53e2Tt0@ejC5MawyBwlv9yQ/DbB7mZeitSacQjVu8wWdxZT7wZc2vYJ52LHw1wzebzUdnaMc@@@DsH/@y5rMyNp38XfNvWv3Xsb8oY/8469dx8Aa3Oxl3Pq8@PvbnZez65tefu9ufRT8lP3X@Jz/@Yv3FQ0in@/vRTa/v7u6@i6/H/TzEN2//@f33Kxj7yzLWTXP67uQXAsa4LmU3DK9X/yHmOvbP8@JHE84xj6afh3kxMcAco0@Q2XmKvks@5cW4PpxD7MJ0NH4IaWP@Mi/7AK@M49zPxuUuwVg/hXFjvszD4MzBdWEIMejfAGa/@AVmh3kvECEAdPD43ed2qY35jZ88QOcPh9AFXHxwXY5mH/YwBcQ5zPt5STAwzr0bfIQV3GheZfhkdHlB4JPxC3xzQ3iV4Vn04xnwmXwn/15lvzFfAccQ7wh/mZPbh@SgSEbaWIJpUsAHkBKIDNb3CQbKLyOum12P2xyhnFxnINAzbuYIuLqoAIUJ3k0Y7ADhL/PGfA3Pwz4PsJEUpi70GRblHdIW3NJlGPMYRlxq8OEAuwZQZCuuGRXdOfjJlm1eINTJJcLhODlBfjSHMMGK0Ux56sw5LzmiZJg8wC67AOEPxILzHLOH@grTxvwhx84rwATawChcACV4AI@BEElfpMhrXml50AffQ4rzMUAqMEClQnTHgJhYpRy852EGoFLZsVVAGTcTMIN9AOznPswWU9zy84KsLDlICsBXi/NYU8q0ZYZFXdflMQLDcjIXtwTcFf2wkPwB0@MB5sHPzfjlNE@YojJ2CnEw06zp3ZjfLg4emzEwmhvz16ULOj9kZUYynSk/@1xihKB6@Hd2C8QePPEPKWlhCACLW1tCHzrgC8CaowKucGkiZINO8Vb@AS4Gmsri0@Ig/4A@bmqG7IPmA6DAQuDGCcK2ktoDdINjwDQRhg3VYS6YlitM1rciHcD/Sx7OObnk4b0TBgwEcPkImwZlQHGAdOFfyG/LhElQlvCAaDmEIwzBtErqnhMpGGdIy4B0gSn6MAJKRa0c6NQZdheyqBhG6DuAOZbPu7xERA8aGMTEOZPyeqwJRdY/A0yOIBRnqEcSEPircCdVvXmeI2QSEhd9I1OMFw8pIEpRaT40X5ZFiKKR@IjOUCbwDOJCKdeCxAxRxWo9Ks/hnbo8hcm4Yb2yAAK7QABqpUdEEt/vcb8cE5YSh0DacL29psgslV6p0CsRZK1H2mIyeW@KP6eWSrYHxSL2Y3CScqKCfwRenlwESWYoap5lyEzlBHQG@g/QRyJp@Je4HNQxPdXWhXqv5ILawVlEtgCbREs0pV3BOefhEiYHahIufllc7XINBqw0mNglOQSD47SUjb/nmGZ5hMyFrPXaEoSxeQGSFNZF3zK2QajPQTSl7KqmmmKwTMmaT@4iLY6uNA3obChqkpLSY8vcXKmkeUgghqt2mokaedO6aD6ufbCPI2QQ1j@ADai5GrK2TUYYARZCd3kPfHFIO@e3ImnEVFjBqpso4RJFbNUxTCMG0G41p1pAEu6zqemI0r542O9mrBDRZs4ZfkAKoQqKfaKpY2lDRV5/n6iwEiU7BYwXq4NWFc4Vw8LlChMa6sfdvKAbIQi1PcLyEJZ00cL9q@xyB@XQdWor0SMi6sUUbctUw57X4ECJpr1Vi8PELEo@osthHhwXdwm9o4KCvdKT2optIx1U0UtOC7Lryllp6@TBpXGRd2GG4kwkm1op7EfYtZWWU@2FMGuG7aGyvkitJvybIBeOH/zCuF4rnFScJWOL9VpkQI2m5S4E8yPRmhSi37UfKlDqqaSWgGdrfaCjqaHpi4wLJJo47fGudEV4l3IpVpL1BXt4T3pb3eFlHnI6o/AnqadUa/7rcHHY9Xgf9N1W6cbQKk0wHbZOB2uRIBWl0g6qP2n1AnCzlSsqQLyqb1yP1NWKE@HjQ1mjdLtC1I9MW9r1@WoxpaliL4cDckG28Sth0gNChj3XTdS8QglxPVQJYvoGUNyBPFy7fXa@RePZ3EuWpWXhrI@1e2hsVcJac1sCqT5cxKL0YvG/5LQac@812/vBAd2xM/Z8XNLKJl5RC0bR1KNCQ@ra5bmAy99qJNXuMbC4W5ijoF1gthR9CYtaRM2n9CO0Q8XSYmjXpVoLksSzVT3OoOXjE3/jLiLnHZy5ZARbNZUocB4DIdU@Qb3xKRCXAk4l70TKY3qPcTJ3OQQQ@gUZSkBJDb10dcBlDWdTK17pSv40znqIlAJhsQchxkoR/bsifdsR9dSH2o0dHjEpzeq97sZBNNLWeGEUG4vlz7Sq6qeHJkJYxaxVYhQFTnvlNfca7rTFA3JxVbtBxSwHepTw2u4IJ7UF1NquHa2ceOtpkc07z1U8ifLovawyCnqqbrdapeAR92MbpUSfmaO67yJe6gGk7gC@pqb0AMwtoviEXKTqSshKP5KT0YtUGVGesa1l5RFisO7UtonYKfnQlsYkivtD@Tr2SAJQvf/BsyblUcFhNjRuc56YEaG/skNkT/@WmVxFeolQXpkl1l3sf2169R6isAp2xrEpKEXd8ZjBQQU9nhUbwtaYDzB80OfBkvA2XmmxrRrTOK1MV@5P2DhJJcGu9VpCxfNaBuXtClg5wmgwzTUFqtzRK8jS6K6LRjFqDDSxEI8UbEBkmFi5xm@UMqBzH5/q@bhfL3LoU20LzQmpVCvd/6CCIu5ShI2MyHbRBDUXO9h6rsqERb/ZhNoCUvfaeLDkJHM/7A2g0L@Zpy/Otq@vXTU4QYlvLSsGtvGWpOfZFqYTy@CsCDW3pxeqWk7qOfuAV00xNOFY6ee0lByW5VwJSFdbyM85p4C/rCb9GnatRewfG4FrKwlvCZUv5eq20Xpa0inlhXAiMlRsbFhwriJTJCG5qh/6L@U@78Vy4FytJZymOq0uJUZFKK4WigdeX/fRjKiHrPUs1XUn2CLleNU0KfxUTS8K/HOyhqqKGDhvRV4fQ9vD@RKHbszY9Du1DY4u6OXEp87vf/ExjdhTYaqOkuizTyp@Wi7KX1TJqlZbTxWMQjGBTHC9AFY@SAkL1NX20rG3Mpd9KJMWY21LQyiq4UK6SFkVWtaVpofgzG1j68QJc3uvF5mlrrAfcptGo19uAFGX6hVRbdFO26wAF1p/SQcGpiPtqRCV7x/qhQ9qFt9K60Zc2SKkwjY6k7Vdi@0mgl7ZaL3kKP26OAths9SJFG/1DlzddLqg9NUzkFT3xvzf/1HU5rDaMoKV@vyK/@vu7bt/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 113 bytes

```java
s->{int m=0,l=s.length(),t,L=0;for(;l>0;L=t>m?(m=t)-m+l:L)t=s.split("\\b[a-zA-Z]{"+l--+"}\\b").length;return-~L;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDNbhMxEMfveYrRQhQvWS@5cMl2l/YCVAqnIiHRVpWTOLsO/ljZsylpSK6ceqvUCwf6FnkclBfoIxhnEyQYaWzNzM9/z8ycLRidT796oWpjEeYhThsUMp01eoLC6PRV1plI5hx8ZELDqgNQN2MpJuCQYbgWRkxBhRq5QCt0eXkNzJYublGAT@Zc47uj2MkBKWAGuXe0WAmNoPJBInOXSq5LrEicYDLKB9nMWJLJYpCNcizUW6JyjKnqy@EoxkC7Wgok0dXV@JLRuzP65XoV9SWl/WgdclF8lMssx8Zquhlla5@1HQVhIAtmAbnD4X/NAlwsHXKVmgbTOrSKMxJ16ZuBA1pAd9rVUdI@S2CWsrqWyzMXxiP7VBwf5Nedva@9/8ClNHBrrJwCVsKFnzg4o3ir4I71YC2StEyapi12IM79iGPPwdh8A/J7@@N5@9SjveftrzgE/rMVGJZ5kNz9vCe7x4fd41M4Y6itKS1THitO/3Ht35u/VkoO@6Y0hEE8iU8K1n/tuEauJ/zli1NyeiuwGg4V00tK6Y1bqrGRbrX@vtl4pg3eVPywQ2ATbJiUyz8)

### Explanation

This basically splits the String on ascii words of all possible lengths to count them, and returns the max value of the count.

```java
s->{
 int m=0,                                 // The maximum number of 
     l=s.length(),                        // The length of ASCII letters, going from high to low
     t,                                   // Declare a temp variable.
     L=0;                                 // Initialize the most present length to 0.
 for(                                     // Loop
      ;
      l>0;                                // On each length, going down
      L=t>m?(m=t)-m+l:L                   // If a count is higher than the max count, the new count becomes the max count and the most present length becomes the current length
     )
  t=                                     
      s.split("\\b[a-zA-Z]{"+l--+"}\\b")  // Count the number of parts between or around words of length l
                                          // Also, decrement l
       .length;                           // Store the count into t
 return-~L;                               // Return L + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>81</s> 75 bytes

*Thanks to [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267/) for 5 bytes and [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/) for another 1 byte*

```python
lambda S:max(L:=[*map(len,re.findall("[a-z]+",S,2))],key=L.count)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc3PDoIgHADge0/BrAMk2FaX5rJ5bfNmN3ONFKcLfjDEFf3x1anvBT7jXa9htzc2dChDlyC5urUclaniT1ykWbVW3GApgFqRdAO0XEocVZy96jiiJd0SUtO78FmRNHoCRxaDMto6ZEUwdgCHOzyAmRwmhARMDkceb0oBTkAjVssc54/TuU//HXjG2HX06qbl@P5@5vkH)

Anonymous function: Finds all runs of letters using regex, collects a list of the lengths of those runs, and prints the item with the maximum frequency in the list.

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dc3PDoIgHADge0/BrAOk2KFLc9ns7hNkrqHiZMEPBriiP7469b3AZ4KfNOwPxsYRlegaJVPdwJArFHviuiibrWIGSw6Z5fkoYGBS4qQ50wujrzZNMkdIm915KOu81zN4shLKaOuR5dFYAR6PWICZPSaEREyOJ5buHAfPoeebdYWrh/BT8f8gUEpvLqhOS/f@fpblBw) by using python 3.8's assignment expr

Comment: You can use `re.findall('[a-z]+",input(),2)` for -1. (`2` is the value of the `re.IGNORECASE` flag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 48 bytes

```
Commonest@*StringLength@*StringCases[__?LetterQ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/fS8NADMff/StCKzK1171PnYWBOtiDom@llFizXuF@lLuMUeb2r9dzetBACEk@yTfRyJI0ctfguIWHcWW1toY8Fzfv7DrTbsi0LGO2Qk@@rOvHDTGTe6vG11Dm8sP@9cs0g7Xpd/xkna4ySEAsIclgW6ZVBVcwL@BwAQDJCyllYW@d@sqAZecBHQEHYR/wCRJsQuV5PgXP3Po/hkfExE3c82yjtYrgV8kA9n1sz67vl3g792SYTEOXaTEr9h3LxUKjGYQQtR/0p1X@cPw@neIUGsu1JHe@BLDhHSo1JMe78Qc) Function. Takes a string as input and returns a list of most common lengths as output. The list should only have a single number if the mode length is unique. It gives incorrect output on one of the Unicode examples, presumably due to `ง` counting as a letter.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 101 bytes

```php
$a=array_count_values(array_map(strlen,preg_split('/[^A-Za-z]/',$argn,0,1)));arsort($a);echo key($a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NSsNAFIX3eYoBA5lgptVtW7Uu1AoFuxMUDbfxkgQnM8PMrTX@dOvKndCNC/sWfRzJC/QNjLFF6IF74DvnLo7JTN07Mo37cADWQhkneqIofgA5Qcc3UQGGO7ISVWQsprEzMicetK9vj8UViKebdhD5YFMV7UX7YRh2wTptifsQdjHJNLvHcg31mkaDUXxyMezWA5RSs6m28i5ilOWOgUVG6Mh5m67RVt1qtbY@zr0hUuDYWD8y/r18Wy0XgQhWy6@wAe/S5pSrlDldIKs@33k1/6jmi8ZDZqxOLRQeZSi2Tnln@l@pRPa3RzEwxuNh7xB22w4VoUrQ3@nz/jSnrNMpQJVCiNiVxVhL9/z6Mpt5oDTFGdr1UAYJTUDK8kcbyrVytTj9BQ)

Drat PHP and it's super long function names again...

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 57 bytes

```factor
[ [ Letter? ¬ ] split-when harvest [ length ] map mode ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVG9SgNBEO7vKYYo5ILe2UfRdDEgNiIWIYTNZbxb2J9zZ2I8YtJa2Qk2Fqb3AVL7JJIXyCOce8kJAT@Y3Z2db@D7Zu5FwtaVtze9624bBCVSghacxcSCJbFMaJdPjEzsGCF3yFzkThoGwocJmgQJKFeSWZoUToNgFoBH4xKVsjC1To2PgTNJIBwCIzE19hkee6Q4jv/xevV9hdwkGNknCH9WL5vVshk1N6vPlk9qxp2TWxVkNcL64zVcv7@t35f@bHnlNnVC10zOMNoLU3937R9ShVBpNiDyvK6GrbNzcXRCaLjyfXjQCTtTyVm7rYUpoigaUqFHVtFs/rxY1E3CWB5m6LaWwM97IpQqGsE8KPvQB2@K0V3A9xcMdnOMpl4PZMI9Vg19UGhSznxVixx0tYRBWT3j8hc)

Split on non-letters, harvest (remove) any vestigial empty strings, get the length of each word, and take the mode.