# Sum the First n Even Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, fibonacci

There seems not to be a contest for this one yet.

The task is simple. Add the first `n` numbers of the Fibonacci sequence that are even and output the result.

This is given by [OEIS A099919](https://oeis.org/A099919), except that sequence is shifted by one, starting with `fib(1) = 0` instead of `fib(1) = 1`.

This is code golf. Lowest byte count wins.

## Examples

```
n sum
1 0
2 2
3 10
4 44
5 188
6 798
7 3382
8 14328
9 60696
```

---

<sub>[Related](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/project-euler-question-2-sum-of-even-fibonacci-numbers-under-4-million)</sub>

Comment: [https://oeis.org/A099919](https://oeis.org/A099919)

Comment: @EasterlyIrk The test cases imply the latter, but it should be explicitly stated.

Comment: @Mego yeah, I figured as much.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk, Mego is right. It is the latter.

Comment: Please don't accept answers so fast. It's only been an hour, golfier answer _could_ come in. EDIT: I see now there's already a shorter answer that's not accepted yet.

Comment: It's customary to wait at least a week before accepting an answer, because many people interpret it as a sign that the challenge is no longer active.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n(1) = 0`? Your statement `n = 0` makes no sense.

Comment: @devRicher I have corrected that. Someone else added that statement to my original post and I did not spot the mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @ETHProductions and 2 more saved thanks to @Adnan!*

```
zc»+U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/oasis#@1@VfGi3duj///8tAQ)

#### Explanation:

This uses the same recurrence formula as my MATL answer.

Comment: Oasis's info.txt says `U` is replaced in the code with `00`, might that save you a byte?

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks! I forgot that

Comment: Nice! You can replace `4*` with `z` and `2+` with `»` :)

Comment: @Adnan Thank you! I really should read the doc :-)

Answer (score 17):

### Python, 33 bytes

```python
c=2+5**.5
lambda n:(7-c)*c**n//20
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59sa6RtqqWlZ8qVZpuTmJuUkqiQZ6VhrpusqZWspZWnr29k8D8tv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89VcNQR8HQQNOKi7OgKDOvRCFNI0/zPwA)

Magic formula!

Comment: Oh god. It took me much longer than it should have to realize why you were "commenting out" that 20 on the second line :P

Comment: @xnor, Any reference to this magic formula?

Comment: @TheChetan: possibly `a(n) = (-10 + (5-3*sqrt(5))*(2-sqrt(5))^n + (2+sqrt(5))^n*(5+3*sqrt(5)))/20` (Colin Barker, Nov 26 2016) from the OEIS page

Comment: @TheChetan bit late, but it's Binet's formula

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
f=x=>x>1&&4*f(x-1)+f(x-2)+2
```

Recursion to the rescue! This uses one of the formulas on the OEIS page:

> f(n < 1) = 0, f(n) = 4*a(n+1)+a(n)+2

(but shifted by one because the challenge shifts it by one)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n/2and 4*f(n-1)+f(n-2)+2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBnladvlJiXomCilaaRp2uoqQ2ijDS1jf6n5Rcp5Clk5ikUJealp2oY6igYGmhacXEWFGXmlSgAlWn@BwA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
r3*♂FΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@19krPVoZpPbucX//5sCAA)

Explanation:

Every third Fibonacci number (starting from `F_0 = 0`) is even. Thus, the first `n` even Fibonacci numbers are `F_{i*3}` for `i` in `[0, n)`.

```
r3*♂FΣ
r       [0, n)
 3*     multiply each element by 3
   ♂F   retrieve the corresponding element in the Fibonacci sequence
     Σ  sum
```

Answer (score 6):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
3m*.bs
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3m%2a.bs&input=4&warnings=0)

```
3m*    -   map(i*3, range(input))
   .b  -  map(nth_fib, ^)
     s - sum(^)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>38 35</s>  32 bytes

```perl6
{[+] grep(*%%2,(1,&[+]...*))[^($_-1)]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uLKrVRQS85PSVWw/V8drR2rkF6UWqChpapqpKNhqKMGFNHT09PS1IyO01CJ1zXUjK39X5xYqaCkEq@gEq8H1qmhqaSQll@kYKinZ/kfAA)

```perl6
{[+] grep(*%%2,(0,1,*+*...*))[^$_]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uLKrVRQS85PSVWw/V8drR2rkF6UWqChpapqpKNhoGOoo6Wtpaenp6WpGR2nEh9b@784sVJBSSVeQSVeD6xNQ1NJIS2/SMFQT8/yPwA)

```perl6
{[+] (0,1,*+*...*)[3,6...^$_*3]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uLKrVRQS85PSVWw/V8drR2roGGgY6ijpa2lp6enpRltrGMGZMSpxGsZx9b@L06sVFBSiVdQidcD69HQVFJIyy9SMNTTs/wPAA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [+]                       # reduce with ｢&infix:<+>｣

    ( 0, 1, * + * ... * )\  # fibonacci sequence with leading 0

    [ 3, 6 ...^ $_ * 3 ]    # every 3rd value up to
                            # and excluding the value indexed by
                            # the input times 3

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica,  <strike>27</strike> 21 bytes

*Thanks to xnor for pointing out an alternate formula, alephalpha for correcting for starting index*

```
Fibonacci[3#-1]/2-.5&
```

Comment: Might the `(Fibonacci(3*n+2)-1)/2` formula be shorter?

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```matlab
@(n)filter(2,'FAD'-69,(1:n)>1)(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeZlplTklqkYaSj7ubooq5rZqmjYWiVp2lnqAmU/J@YV6xhqfkfAA)

#### Explanation

This anonymous function implements the difference equation `a(n) = 4*a(n-1)+a(n-2)+2` as a [recursive filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response):

> `Y = filter(B,A,X)` filters the data in vector `X` with the
>       filter described by vectors `A` and `B` to create the filtered
>       data `Y`.  The filter is a "Direct Form II Transposed"
>       implementation of the standard difference equation:
>
> `a(1)*y(n) = b(1)*x(n) + b(2)*x(n-1) + ... + b(nb+1)*x(n-nb) - a(2)*y(n-1) - ... - a(na+1)*y(n-na)`

In our case `A = [1 -4 -1]`, `B = 2`, and the input `x` should be a vector of ones, with the result appearing as the last entry of the output `y`. However, we set to `0` the first value of the input so that an initial `0` appears in the output, as required.

`'FAD'-69` is just a shorter way to produce the coefficient vector `A = [1 -4 -1]`; and `(1:n)>1` produces the input vector `x = [0 1 1 ... 1]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
9k5v1+2/3?*1-^5v/0k2/p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@2@ZbVpmqG2kb2yvZagbZ1qmb5BtpF/w/78pAA)

Or save the program in a file and run it by typing

```
dc -f *filename*
```

The program accepts a non-negative integer *n* on stdin, and it outputs the sum of the first *n* even Fibonacci numbers on stdout.  (The Fibonacci sequence is taken to start with 0, as per the OP's examples.)

---

This program uses the formula (F(3n-1)-1)/2 for the sum of the first n even Fibonacci numbers, where F is the usual Fibonacci function, given by F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(n) = F(n-2) + F(n-1) for n >= 2.

---

dc is a stack-based calculator.  Here's a detailed explanation:

```
9k  # Sets the precision to 9 decimal places (which is more than sufficient).

5v  # Push the square root of 5

1+  # Add 1 to the number at the top of the stack.

2/  # Divide the number at the top of the stack by 2.
```

At this point, the number (1+sqrt(5))/2 is at the top of the stack.

```
3   # Push 3 on top of the stack.

?   # Read a number from stdin, and push it.

\*  # Pop two numbers from the stack, multiply them, and push the product

1-  # Subtract 1 from the number at the top of the stack.
```

At this point, 3n-1 is at the top of the stack (where n is the input), and (1+sqrt(5))/2 is second from the top.

```
^   # Pop two numbers from the stack (x, then y), compute the power y^x, and push that back on the stack.

5v/ # Divide the top of the stack by sqrt(5).
```

At this point, the number at the top of the stack is (((1+sqrt(5))/2)^(3n-1))/sqrt(5).  The closest integer to this number is F(3n-1).  Note that F(3n-1) is always an odd number.

```
0k # Change precision to 0 decimal places.

2/ # Divide the top of the stack by 2, truncating to an integer.

p # Print the top of the stack on stdout.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 38 bytes

```forth
: f 1 1 rot 1 ?do tuck 4 * + loop 2/ ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwFET3PcUjK2sxRbGbiniQkEUxpC0t/BDi@eMPAzOzmHlRcvkM79ii1ieRUZWlqG9BKMf@Y6bnxl8kMd1ZdJYIR8IaXp1hwubWr6wYJVj2zHIZH8pwQTzu6/XhGsDXEw)

Wins over [existing Forth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199388/78410) by porting [this formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199432/78410):

$$
G(0)=G(1)=1, G(n+2)=4G(n+1)+G(n) \\
a(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{G(n)}2 \right\rfloor
$$

```forth
: f ( n -- a_n )  \ Take single number n and return a_n
  1 1 rot 1       \ g0 g1 n 1
  ?do             \ loop n-1 times
    tuck 4 * +    \ gn-1 gn -> gn gn+1=4gn+gn-1
  loop            \ end loop; top is gn
  2/              \ an = gn/2 (floor division)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
OOi:"t4*b+2+]x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@/vn2mlVGKilaRtpB1b8f@/JQA)

#### Explanation

This uses one of the recurrence formulas from OEIS:

> a(n) = 4*a(n-1)+a(n-2)+2

For input *N* the code iterates *N* times, which is 2 more times than necessary. This is compensated for by setting `0`, `0` (instead of `0`, `2`) as initial values, and by deleting the last obtained value and displaying the previous one.

```
OO      % Push two zeros as initial values of a(n-2), a(n-1)
i       % Input N
:"      % Do this N times
  t     %   Duplicate a(n-1)
  4*    %   Multiply by 4
  b+    %   Bubble up a(n-2) and add to 4*a(n-1)
  2+    %   Add 2. Now we have 4*a(n-1)+a(n-2)+2 as a(n), on top of a(n-1)
]       % End
x       % Delete last value, a(n). Implicitly display the remaining value, a(n-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 80 bytes

```
@set/at=x=0,y=1
@for /l %%i in (2,1,%1)do @set/az=x+y,y=z+x,t+=x=y+z
@echo %t%
```

Uses the fact that every third Fibonacci number is even, and just calculates them three at a time (calculating more than one at a time is actually easier as you don't have to swap values around). I tried the `(Fibonacci(3*n+2)-1)/2` formulation but it's actually a few bytes longer (`t+=` turns out to be quite efficient in terms of code size).

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>82</strike> <strike>38</strike> 36 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @BrainSteel*

The formulas at the OEIS page made it much shorter:

```
a(n){return--n<1?0:4*a(n)+a(n-1)+2;}
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/bbQN0T)

82 bytes:

```
x,s,p,n,c;f(N){s=0;p=n=1;c=2;while(n<N){if(~c&1)s+=c,n++;x=p+c;p=c;c=x;}return s;}
```

The first version is 75 bytes but the function is not reusable, unless you always call `f` with greater `N` than the previous call :-)

```
x,s,p=1,n=1,c=2;f(N){while(n<N){if(~c&1)s+=c,n++;x=p+c;p=c;c=x;}return s;}
```

My first answer here. Didn't check any other answers nor the OEIS. I guess there are a few tricks that I can apply to make it shorter :-)

Comment: You can make this a tad shorter by shuffling things around a bit: `a(n){return--n<1?0:4*a(n)+a(n-1)+2;}` (36 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <strike>22</strike> 21 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)

```apl
(2+5*.5)∘(⌊20÷⍨*×7-⊣)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X8NI21RLz1TzUccMjUc9XUYGh7c/6l2hdXi6ue6jrsWa/9MetU141Nv3qG@qp/@jruZD640ftU0E8oKDnIFkiIdn8P@0Qyse9W62BAA)

Uses [xnor's magic formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105530/91097)

```apl
(2+5*.5)∘(⌊20÷⍨*×7-⊣)

(2+5*.5)               ⍝ constant c
        ∘(           ) ⍝ joined to
                 7-⊣  ⍝ 7-c
                ×      ⍝ multiplied by
               *       ⍝ input^c
           20÷⍨        ⍝ all over 20
          ⌊            ⍝ floor
```

## Or with [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 19 bytes

(Thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m))

```apl
(2+√5)∘(⌊20÷⍨*×7-⊣)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X8NI@1HHLFPNRx0zNB71dBkZHN7@qHeF1uHp5rqPuhZr/k971DbhUW/fo76pnv6PupoPrTd@1DYRyAsOcgaSIR6ewf/TDq141LvZEgA)

Comment: Save a byte by answering with the tacit function `(2+5*.5)∘(⌊20÷⍨*×7-⊣)` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X8NI21RLz1TzUccMjUc9XUYGh7c/6l2hdXi6ue6jrsWa/9MetU141Nv3qG@qp/@jruZD640ftU0E8oKDnIFkiIdn8P@0Qyse9W62BAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") and optionally another two from Dyalog Extended's `√` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X8NI@1HHLFPNRx0zNB71dBkZHN7@qHeF1uHp5rqPuhZr/k971DbhUW/fo76pnv6PupoPrTd@1DYRyAsOcgaSIR6ewf/TDq141LvZEgA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: Why is [your bounty request](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/17363/71) for 50 instead of 100 (doubled by being well-explained)?

Comment: I didn't know what would count for well explained and is it is just a re-implementation of someone else's formula, I didn't think think it would count. @Adám

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
⌊⊃⌽(4∘⊥,⊃)⍣⎕÷2 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco9DoJAGIThfk4xpSaasD8sC70mHoOEQEPAWGltISFgZ2JjZTyBhZWVN/kugksxxbx58n29Lk553VaTdJdykqGX/izDd2Glu0v/WoW7lPEp19vvo6lnhrAK2bY98Mhs11DGt4pAlsg2TRH6LKYKChoGFjEcEnikCEzGByNqqojWUnnPJPU0xodkjfZ0kUsddZwoZf8)

A full program.

#### How it works: the math

Uses `a(n) = (Fibonacci(3*n + 2) - 1)/2` from the OEIS page, but we have offset 1 in `a(n)`, so the actual formula is:

$$
a(n) = \frac{F(3 n - 1) - 1}{2}
= \Bigl\lfloor \frac{F(3 n - 1)}{2} \Bigr\rfloor
$$

And using \$ F(2) = F(-1) = 1 \$ and \$ F(n+3) = 4F(n) + F(n-3) \$, we define a derived sequence \$ G(n) \$ such that

$$
G(0)=G(1)=\frac12, G(n+2)=4G(n+1)+G(n)
$$

Then the desired value is \$ a(n) = \lfloor G(n) \rfloor \$.

#### How it works: the code

```apl
⌊⊃⌽(4∘⊥,⊃)⍣⎕÷2 2  ⍝ Input: n
            ÷2 2  ⍝ 2-element vector [.5 .5] i.e. [G(1) G(0)]
   (4∘⊥,⊃)⍣⎕      ⍝ Derive [G(x+2) G(x+1)] from [G(x+1) G(x)] n times:
    4∘⊥           ⍝   G(x+2) = 4×G(x+1) + G(x)
        ⊃         ⍝   G(x+1) as first element of the vector
       ,          ⍝   Concatenate
 ⊃⌽               ⍝ Get the last element of the result vector, i.e. G(n)
⌊                 ⍝ Floor
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>32</s> 27 bytes

```
Fibonacci[3Input[]-1]/2-1/2
```

*Credit to **xnor**. Saved 5 bytes thanks to JungHwan Min.*

Comment: Surely Mathematica has Fibonacci and it's shorter to do either `(Fibonacci(3*n+2) - 1)/2` or write the sumi?

Comment: @JungHwanMin This isn't plagiarism; it mentions the OEIS page. Also, this isn't a candidate for community wiki. See [How should Community Wikis be used?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9692/12012).

Comment: @devRichter Sorry for undeleting your post, but it was necessary to have a conversation. If you want to keep it deleted, let me know and I'll move this conversation to a chat room.

Comment: @Dennis still, I believe credit should be given to [Vincenzo Librandi](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Vincenzo_Librandi) explicitly -- (accidentally deleted my last comment... could that be undeleted?) For the community post suggestion, I stand corrected.

Comment: What I meant was to mention his name in the post... (or perhaps include the Mathematica comment `(* Vincenzo Librandi, Mar 15 2014 *)` in the post, as it is on OEIS.)

Comment: @JungHwanMin Why are you singling out this answer? Most answers to this question use one formula or another from the OEIS page, and I don't see anyone mentioning Gary Detlefs by name...

Comment: @devRichter I don't know or have Mathematica. How does this accept user input?

Comment: @Dennis I found a shorter one. [This](https://i.gyazo.com/d25ee5b855c1723a99c5307f4bae1227.png) is how the input screen looks like.

Comment: @Dennis While other answers are implementations of a formula, this is a copy/pasted answer, with spaces removed...

Comment: @devRicher Welp, it *was*. Now, my point does not matter. +1

Comment: -6 bytes: `Fibonacci[3Input[]-1]/2-.5`

Comment: Seems to output `a(n).` instead of `a(n)`. @JungHwanMin

Comment: @devRicher If you want an exact integer... -5 bytes: `Fibonacci[3Input[]-1]/2-1/2`

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell (<s>32</s> 31 bytes)

Saved one byte thanks to @ChristianSievers.

Using the formula given in OEIS: `a(n) = 4*a(n-1)+a(n-2)+2, n>1` by Gary Detlefs

`a n|n>1=4*a(n-1)+a(n-2)+2|n<2=0`

Comment: A golfier way to say `n<=1` for integers is `n<2`. Also, the second condition doesn't need to be the negation of the first (the idiomatic `otherwise` is simply `True`), so usally in golfing something like `1<2` is used.

Comment: @ChristianSievers indeed the n<2 is an obvious improvement, thank you. The second one works as well, though it does not save me anything in this case. I'm still learning Haskell and did not realise I could have a guard like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/), 10 bytes

```
Uo@MgX*3Ãx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x@a7@CbHqFlXKtZ8f@/JQA)

Thanks ETHproductions :)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
sum(DescTools::Fibonacci(3*(scan():2-1)))
```

> `scan()` : take `n` from stdin.
>
> `scan():2-1` : generate integers from `n` to `2`, decrement by `1`, yielding `n-1` through `1`.
>
> `3*(scan():2-1)` : multiply by 3, as every third fibonacci number is even.
>
> `DescTools::Fibonacci(3*(scan():2-1))` : Return these fibonacci numbers (i.e. `3` through `(n-1)*3`).
>
> `sum(DescTools::Fibonacci(3*(scan():2-1)))` : Sum the result.

Previously, I had this uninteresting solution using one of the formulae from OEIS:

```
a=function(n)`if`(n<2,0,4*a(n-1)+a(n-2)+2)
```

Comment: I managed to match your bytecount without recursion :)

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Nice! I've ditched the recursion also and made a one-byte improvement :)

Comment: Nice, what exactly does `desctools::fibonacci` do that `numbers::fibonacci` cant? Because that mist be a bit shorter.

Comment: Oh nevermind, found it. Sweet, the other implementations I found don't support asking for multiple numbers at once.

Comment: And for some reason `sapply(1:10,gmp::fibnum)` does really weird stuff.

Comment: `numbers::fibonacci` has a second argument that allows display of numbers `1` to `n`, which is a nice feature, but then you still need to do careful indexing to extract every third element. So you end up with something like this: `sum(numbers::fibonacci((n=scan())*3-3,T)[1:(n-1)*3])`, 52 bytes.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Yeah, ``gmp::fibnum'' returns objects of type `bigz`, which the `*apply` class of functions converts to type `raw` because reasons...

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```
for(${0}=1;$i++<$argv[1];$$x=${0}+${1})${$x^=1}&1?$i--:$s+=$$x;echo$s;
```

showcasing [variable variables](http://php.net/variables.variable). O(n).
Run with `-nr`.

**breakdown**

```
for(${0}=1;         # init first two fibonaccis (${1}=NULL evaluates to 0 in addition)
                    # the loop will switch between $0 and $1 as target.
    $i++<$argv[1];  # loop until $i reaches input
    $$x=${0}+${1}       # 3. generate next Fibonacci
)
    ${$x^=1}            # 1. toggle index (NULL => 1 => 0 => 1 ...)
    &1?$i--             # 2. if current Fibonacci is odd, undo increment
    :$s+=$$x;           #    else add Fibonacci to sum
echo$s;             # print result
```

Numbers are perfectly valid variable names in PHP.
But, for the literals, they require braces; i.e. `${0}`, not `$0`.

**36 bytes, O(1)**

```
<?=(7-$c=2+5**.5)*$c**$argv[1]/20|0;
```

port of [xnor´s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105530#105530)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 42 bytes

Non-recursive solution, as contrast to the earlier solution by @rtrunbull [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105705/59530).

```
for(i in 1:scan())F=F+gmp::fibnum(3*i-3);F
```

Uses the property that each third value of the Fibonacci sequence is even. Also abuses the fact that `F` is by default defined as `FALSE=0`, allowing it as a basis to add the values to.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 47 bytes

```forth
: f 3 * 1- 0 1 rot 0 do tuck + loop d>s 1- 2/ ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvBDoIwEIThu0/xhyNapHpSEp7ECykWiJU1tSa8fd2G0@xkvvUS02wmXyLnO54rNdbQYomSNEch/dyLI0Hkw9h/y34506nfsEWqWWhoKjA9lRav1cX9peOxHz7KW3USbifcEMKyTipl5Tm4@bDlPw)

Uses the first formula for OEIS `a(n) = (Fibonacci(3*n + 2) - 1)/2`, since the code for Fibonacci is relatively small in forth.

```forth
: f              \ start a new word definition
  3 * 1-         \ multiply by 3 and subtract 1 (simplified form of 3*(n-1) + 2 )
  0 1 rot 0      \ create starting Fibonacci values and set up loop parameters
  do tuck + loop \ Fibonacci code - iteratively copy top value add top 2 stack values
  d>s            \ drop the top stack value
  1- 2/          \ subtract 1 and divide result by 2
;                \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
Σ↑Θnİ0İf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9odXNr///Oo@KGkc6YbsSwMMSwZv///zI)

painfully slow due to intersecting two infinite lists.

Comment: Nice.  [This](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9odXNr/23igoHhuKMxMP/Oo@KGkWbCpjLOmMSwZv//) is another, rather faster, 8-byter, but obviously golf doesn't care about speed!

Answer (score 0):

## PARI/GP, 21 bytes

```
n->fibonacci(3*n-1)\2
```

`\` is the integer quotient.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel (Version 1911), 119 Bytes

Using iterative calculations (Maximum iteration 1024)

```
A1 'Input
B1 =IF(B1=4^5,1,B1+1)
C1 =SEQUENCE(A1*3-1)-1
D1 =IF(B1=1,N(C1#>0),IF(C1#=B1,SUM(INDEX(D1#,B1-{0,1})),D1#))
E1 =SUM(D1#*(MOD(D1#,2)=0)) 'Output
```

Tests
[image: Test tables]

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 46 bytes

```
(:m;5 2 -1??:i 3*5\- 2i-m?*3i*5+2i+m?*+-10+20/
```

Ignore the floating point, TIO isn't perfect.

Yeah, yeah. I cheated. This is just a fancy arithmetic equation to calculate the result. Works in O(1) time, though, assuming a^n can be calculated in O(1) time, which might not be true.

```
(:m;5 2 -1??:i 3*5\- 2i-m?*3i*5+2i+m?*+-10+20/ #Sum the first n even F
(:m;                                           #Set m to our input minus one, pop the value from the list. 
    5 2 -1??:i                                 #Set i to sqrt(5), but don't pop it since we're gonna use it (saves 1 byte)
               3*5\-                           #5-3sqrt(5)
                     2i-m?                     #[2-sqrt(5)]^m
                          *                    #Multiply those two together
                           3i*5+2i+m?*         #Same as the above lines, but + instead of -.
                                      +        #Add the left part with the right part
                                       -10+    #Add -10 (-10+20/ and 10- 20/ are the same size)
                                           20/ #Divide by twenty.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv@V/DKtfaVMFIQdfQ3t4qU8FYyzRGV8EoUzfXXss4U8tU2yhTG8jU1jU00DYy0P//HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
0.@{.4*@2++}\*;
```

This one actually does the "operation" using a neat little trick I found. The sum is actually just a 0, 0 leading sequence, with a(n) = 4a(n-1) + a(n-2) + 2. So I do that.

```
0.@{.4*@2++}\*; #Print the sum of the first n even F
0.              #Add two 0s to the stack. [n 0 0]
  @             #Bring the n up front. [0 0 n]
   {       }    #A block of "do something" [0 0 n {}]
   {       }\   #Bring n to the front again [0 0 {} n]
   {       } *  #Perform the block n times on the stack below it [0 0]
   {.      }    #Duplicate our top element (a[n-1] a[n-1])
   { 4*    }    #Multiply the dupe by 4 (a[n-1] 4a[n-1])
   {   @   }    #Bring up our bottom element (a[n-1] 4a[n-1] a[n-2])
   {    2++}    #4a[n-1]+a[n-2]+2 = a[n]
   {       }    #Stack is now a[n-1] a[n], so we dop the loop until our n is right!
              ; #The stack has a[n-1] a[n], but our "n" in question is 1 too high
                #So we pop the top element, leaving a[n-1], W5.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv@d9Az6Faz0TLwUhbuzZGy/r/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
L<3*ÅfO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx8ZY63Brmv///5YA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Ḷ×3ÆḞS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4bi2w5czw4bhuJ5T/zk7w4ck4oKsR/8)

Uses the formula

$$a(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(3i)$$

where \$f(n)\$ is the \$n\$-th Fibonacci number

### How it works

```
Ḷ×3ÆḞS - Main link. Take n on the left
Ḷ      - [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]
 ×3    - [0, 3, 6, ..., 3n-3]
   ÆḞ  - n'th Fibonacci number for each
     S - Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
1_{_4*@+}qi*;2/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3zC@Ot5Ey0G7tjBTy9pI//9/SwA)

Uses Bubbler's wonderful formula.