# Write a haiku-w detector

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

A [haiku](https://www.youngwriters.co.uk/types-haiku-poem) is a poem with three lines, with a 5/7/5 *syllable* count, respectively.

A **haiku-w** is poem with three lines, with a 5/7/5 **word** count, respectively.

### Challenge

Write a program that will return **true** if the input is a haiku-w, and **false** if not.

A valid haiku-w input must consist of 3 lines, separated by a newline.

- Line 1 must consist of 5 words, each word separated by a space.
- Line 2 must consist of 7 words, each word separated by a space.
- Line 3 must consist of 5 words, each word separated by a space.

### Examples

```
The man in the suit
is the same man from the store.
He is a cool guy.
```

**Result:** True

```
Whitecaps on the bay:
A broken signboard banging
In the April wind.
```

**Result:** False

---

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Standard code-golf loopholes apply. Cheating is prohibited.
- Other boolean return values, such as `1` and `0`, are acceptable.
- A length-3 list of strings as an input is also acceptable.
- Valid haiku-w inputs should not have leading or trailing spaces, or multiple spaces separating words.

Comment: Must the input be a single string (containing newlines), or can it be a length-3 list of strings?

Comment: A length-3 list of strings is acceptable. Editing the OP to reflect this.

Comment: Will the haiku-w always contain 3 lines?

Comment: Yes. If the input contains more than or fewer than 3 lines, the program should return **false**.

Comment: Will there ever be leading or trailing spaces on any line? Or multiple spaces separating words?

Comment: Good question. Valid haiku-w inputs should not have leading or trailing spaces, or multiple spaces separating words.

Comment: By the way, clarifications like this are a primary reason to post proposed questions in the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first. :)

Comment: Bonus points for submissions where the code itself is a haiku-w.

Comment: @Glorfindel - done. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108849/9524

Answer (score 25):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> <s>72</s> <s>64</s> <s>63</s> <s>54</s> <s>42</s> 39 bytes

*Thanks to Neil for saving 13 bytes*

```
a=>a.map(b=>b.split` `.length)=='5,7,5'
```

### Explanation

This is a fat-arrow function that takes an array of strings as argument. It replaces each line by its word count. If it is a haiku-w, `a` now contains an array of a five, a seven and a five again. Since JavaScript doesn't allow us to compare 2 arrays at the same time, the array is converted to a string first, and then compared. This results in a boolean that is returned.

Comment: `%` and `*` have the same precedence, so you don't need the `()`s, although I think `(d*2|5)` might also work. Also you can get away with a single `&`, although I think you can improve on even that by using `(b...).length==3>b.some(...length-...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the parentheses. Also, I changed my approach, so I don't explicitly check for length anymore.

Comment: Ah, in that case, don't bother with the calculation, just use `a=>a.map(c=>c.split` `.length)=='5,7,5'`.

Comment: Hehe, you're right. I should've thought of that...

Comment: You still don't need the `+''` - `==` stringifies if the other argument is a string.

Comment: Really? Nice. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

## AWK (GNU Awk), <del>24</del>, <del>30</del>, <del>28</del>, 20 bytes

**Golfed**

```
517253==$0=q=q NF NR
```

Will output "517253" for *True*, and empty string for *False*.

> In awk, any nonzero numeric value or any nonempty string value is true. Any other value (zero or the null string, "") is false

[The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Truth-Values.html)

**How It Works**

Each awk statement (rule) consists of a pattern (or expression) with an associated action:

```
pattern {action}
```

Awk will read the input line by line (record by record) and evaluate pattern expression to see if a corresponding action is to be invoked.

The code above is a standalone Awk expression (pattern) w/o the action block, which is implied to be `{print $0}` in that case.

It should be read right-to-left:

`q=q NF NR`

Append a **N**umber of **F**ields (words) and **N**umber of **R**ecords (i.e. the current line number), to the variable *q*.

This way, when processing a proper Haiku-w, *q* will be set to:

- *51* - on line #1 (5 words)
- *5172* - on line #2 (5 words + 7 words)
- *517253* - on line #3 (5 words + 7 words + 5 words)

`$0=q`

Assign the newly computed value of *q* to *$0* (which holds the whole current line/record by default).

`517253==$0`

Compare it with a "signature" for a proper Haiku-w (517253),
if there is a match, the whole expression evaluates to "true" and
a corresponding action (implicit `print $0`) is run, sending
"517253" to stdout (True), otherwise output will be empty (False).

Note that this will properly recognize a Haiku-w, even if it is followed by an arbitrary number of garbage lines, but I believe that is ok, as:

> A length-3 list of strings as an input is also acceptable.

(i.e. we can assume the input to be 3 lines long)

**Test**

```bash
>awk '517253==$0=q=q NF NR'<<EOF
The man in the suit
is the same man from the store.
He is a cool guy.
EOF

517253
```

[Try It Online !](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYU90TzNtb1FyRnM)

Comment: This fails if the input consists of one line containing 575 words, or two lines containing 57 and 5 words, etc.

Comment: @Lynn, true, putting on hold, until this is fixed.

Comment: @Lynn, should be fixed now

Comment: Very clever fix! :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```py
lambda l:[s.count(' ')for s in l]==[4,6,4]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#dYq9CgIxEAZ7n@LrLoFgdVgIeZKY4tRdXIjZIz93vn20Fq4bZobhcRtped@fC9I11PNDe25mwmRZCyokI0Xvw@wubo5jLfLLbILktTdjHf4hWjs0E9quaK9CBNZewLLR6cCjygeVNspHxxc)

Takes input as a list of lines, with the words separated by single spaces.

As we're guaranteed there'll be no leading or trailing spaces, and only single spaces will seperate each word, we can verify a w-haiku by simply counting the spaces in each line.

We do this in a list comprehension, to create a list of the space-counts. If it is a correct haiku, it should look like `[4, 6, 4]`, so we compare it with this and return the result.

Comment: If you're okay with supporting only Python 2, you can save two bytes: `map(str.count,l,'   ')`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ċ€⁶⁼“¥©¥‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@k@1HTmkeN2x417nnUMOfQ0kMrDy191DDj////0eohGakKuYl5Cpl5CiVAZnFpZom6jnpmMYSXmAuRTSvKz4WIlOQXpeoBVXikKgAVJSok5@fnKKSXVuqpxwIA)

### Explanation

```
ċ€⁶⁼“¥©¥‘  Input: length-3 list of strings
 €         For each string
ċ ⁶          Count the number of spaces
    “¥©¥‘  Convert string to code page indices, makes [4, 6, 4]
   ⁼       Match
```

Comment: Also `ċ€⁶⁼4,6,4` and `ċ€⁶⁼464D¤`… I can’t find anything shorter, though. (Oh, you can flip it, too: `464D⁼ċ€⁶$`)

Comment: `ċ€⁶Ḍ=464` works fine for 8.

Comment: Actually, [no it does not](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@k@1HTmkeN2x7u6LE1MTP5//9/tHp@XqpCSXm@QklGUWqqQlp@aZG6jrqhgpGCsYKJgqmCmYK5goWCpYKhgYKhoYKhkYKhsYKhiYKhqYKhmYKhOVAtpgEKaZllqeqxAA), sorry.

Answer (score 7):

### Batch, 102 bytes

```
@echo off
call:c&&call:c 2||exit/b
:c
set/an=%1+5
set/ps=
for %%W in (%s%)do set/an-=1
exit/b%n%
```

Exits with non-zero errorlevel as soon as it reads a line with the wrong number of words.

Comment: ......well crap

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
{4,6,4}==Count@" "/@#&
```

Unnamed function taking a list of lists of characters as input and returning `True` or `False`. Simply counts how many spaces are in each list of characters, which under the rules of the challenge correlate perfectly with the number of words in each line.

Previous submission:

## Mathematica, 31 bytes

```
Length/@StringSplit/@#=={5,7,5}&
```

Unnamed function taking a list of strings as input and returning `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
f l=[sum[1|' '<-c]|c<-l]==[4,6,4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#JYq9CsMgGEVf5SKFLCZQCJni3gfoJg4i2gh@WvwZCnl3K7jdc8/pDkHI0kg@7wXLuRp1m3MNSgi584PvqpP2EQLf7GPFAw6SvS8L0hFD1DFL85Vx5sskTdO6nGg@NWW7jeJlMSINk1LAp/02pvof).

Edit: thanks to @xnor for a byte!

Comment: Pointful is shorter: `f l=[sum[1|' '<-c]|c<-l]==[4,6,4]`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 12 bytes

```
M%` 
^4¶6¶4$
```

(there's a trailing space after the first line)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@@@rmqDAFWdyaJvZoW0mKv//h2SkKuQm5ilk5imUAJnFpZklXJnFEHZiLkQurSg/FyJSkl@UqsflkaoAVJKokJyfn6OQXlqpBwA)

- `` M%` ``  - Count the number of spaces in each line.

  - `M` - Match mode - print the number of matches.
  - `%` - for each line
  - `` ` `` - separate configuration and regex pattern
  - - just a space.
- `^4¶6¶4$` - There should be 4, 6, and 4 spaces, and exactly three lines.

  - `¶` matches newlines. The rest is a simple regular expression.

Prints `1` for valid input, `0` for invalid.

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 43 bytes

```powershell
"$args"-replace'\S'-match'^(    )
\1  
\1$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#JYrBCoAgGIPvPcWIwDoU9Bbd6xjRj/ypkBpqh57eBHcY@7bltqOgYjsGfm6SLPZVjJaS1OLoUTQ0@wwU60TOedMMSw7GIZUYX5NOZ2IFsnW8gre1ST7wdLqFUT4E6f0N9X7TDw)

#### Explanation

Takes input as a newline separated string.

Removes all non-whitespace, then checks to see that it matches "4 spaces, newline, 6 spaces, newline, 4 spaces newline" exactly, using a regex.

The capture group matches 4 spaces, the backreference `\1` refers to that. Newlines are embedded in the string. Note the second line of the regex contains two spaces after the backreference.

Comment: That is an interesting aproach!

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>58</s> 44 bytes

```
lambda h:[len(l.split())for l in h]==[5,7,5]
```

-14 by tbodt

Comment: You're allowed to take the input as a length 3 list of strings. You can save the bytes spent using `split("\n")`.

Comment: 44 bytes: `lambda h:[len(l.split())for l in h]==[5,7,5]`

Comment: Someone make this shorter to reach crossed out 44

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
dL/uq
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=dL%2Fu%03%04%06%04q&input=%5B%22The+man+in+the+suit%22%2C+%22is+the+same+man+from+the+store.%22%2C+%22He+is+a+cool+guy.%22%5D)

```
dL/       -  map(i.count(" "), input)
        q - ^ == V
   u  -  [4, 6, 4]
```

After the `u` byte there are the following bytes: `0x03 0x04 0x06 0x04`

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 26 bytes

24 bytes of code + 2 bytes for `-ap` flags.

```perl
$m.=@F}{$_=$m==575&$.==3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#U1YsSC3KUdAtSPyvkqtn6@BWW60Sb6uSa2tram6qpqJna2v8/39IRqpCbmKeQmaeQgmQWVyaWcKVWQxhJ@ZC5NKK8nMhIiX5Ral6XB6pCkAliQrJ@fk5CumllXoA)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
qj464T/R;
```

A program that takes input of a list of `"quoted strings"` and prints `True` or `False` as appropriate.

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qj464T%2FR%3B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22The+man+in+the+suit%22%2C+%22is+the+same+man+from+the+store.%22%2C+%22He+is+a+cool+guy.%22%5D%0A%5B%22Whitecaps+on+the+bay%3A%22%2C+%22A+broken+signboard+banging%22%2C+%22In+the+April+wind.%22%5D&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
qj464T/R;   Program. Input: Q
qj464T/R;Q  Implicit variable fill
     T      Are the base-10
 j          digits
  464       of 464
q           equal
      /     to the number
        ;   of spaces
       R    in each string
         Q  in the input?
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

*Saved lots of bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

This takes an array of three strings as input.

```
®¸lÃ¥"5,7,5
```

[Run it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=rrhsw6UiNSw3LDU=&input=WyJUaGUgbWFuIGluIHRoZSBzdWl0IgoiaXMgdGhlIHNhbWUgbWFuIGZyb20gdGhlIHN0b3JlIgoiSGUgaXMgYSBjb29sIGd1eS4iXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

### C 142 bytes

```c
void f(){char *c;l=3;s[3]={0};while(l>0){if(*c==' ')s[l-1]++;if((*c=getchar())=='\n'){l--;}}printf("%d",(s[0]==4 && s[1]==6 && s[2]==4)?1:0);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```c
void f()
{
  char *c;
  c = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); 
  int l=3;
  int s[3]= {0};


  while(l>0)
  {  
    if(*c==' ')
    s[l-1]++;

    if( (*c=getchar())=='\n')
    {    
      l--;
    }   
  }
  printf("%d",(s[0]==4 && s[1]==6 && s[2]==4)?1:0);
}
```

Returns 1 for 5/7/5 sequence else 0.

A positive testcase:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## J, 12 bytes

```
4 6 4=#@;:@>
```

The input is a boxed list of strings.

### Explanation

This is a fork with a constant left tine. This checks the result of the right tine, `#@;:@>`, for equality with `4 6 4`. The right time unboxes each (`>`), then (`@`) converts each string to words (`;:`), then (`@`) takes the length of each (`#`).

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 357 bytes

Sort of new to code golf, but this is the best I could do quickly

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n(std::string s)
{
    int b = 0;
    for(char c: s)
        if(c == ' ') b++;
    cout << "C = " << b;
    return b;
}
int main()
{
    string a, b, c;
    getline(cin, a);
    getline(cin, b);
    getline(cin, c);
    if(n(a)==4 && n(b)==6 && n(c)==4)
        cout<<'1';
    else cout << '0';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The goal of code golf is to make your code as short as possible; a good first step would be to remove all unnecessary whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 48 bytes

```
all(stringr::str_count(scan(,"")," ")==c(4,6,4))
```

Reads a 3-length character vector from stdin and works by counting the number of spaces. To count the number of spaces we use the `str_count` from the  `stringr` package which can count occurrences based on a regex pattern.

An alternative approach without using packages could be:

```
all(sapply(scan(,""),function(x)length(el(strsplit(x," "))))==c(5,7,5))
```

Comment: First time I've ever seen `el` before, thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby 1.9.3

Not golfed, but is itself a haiku-w

```
def haiku_w(input)
  lines = input.split("\n")
  lengths = lines.map(&:split).map(&:length)
  lengths.eql?([5,7,5])
end
```

or...

```
lines equals input split (newlines)
lengths equals lines map split map length
lengths equals five seven five?
```

Unfortunately doesn't work with leading whitespace on any lines, but does cope with trailing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>57</s> 64 bytes

**Edit** Corrected with the addition of 7 bytes after feedback from @Dada. Thanks!

```python
i,j=input,''
for x in i():j+=`len(x.split())`+' '
i(j=='5 7 5 ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JYtLCgMhEET3c4rGTSsj7oZAwH0OkAOMBCdp8TP4gcnpjcFdVb1XnaTTFM9WJeJypAwXUATi4u5WvXsb@aXK6alyIfYVARfiTmvc4AYboOidPT8Wgon/Xx2xNKpMMiqzmTDpkVOYS03ZqmE8LAzJwCslD@/2VewH)

Not the shortest Python answer by a long way but just wanted to use the new trick I learned recently of using `input()` to display the output and save a `print` statement. Takes a list of lines as input. Requires Ctrl C (or any other key-press for that matter) to terminate the program (with an exception) in a terminal but works fine without on TIO.

Comment: This will fail in cases like [this one](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#tc09CoAgGAbgvVO8uKgk0Z9ZgXdxKfhELMrA29vYCVqf5SmkvKV4PklxXu3HhQyKICFXX1sXtihyc5@BkpDSVSS8tVwbzWUprEWHHgNGaEwwmLHgV2MKX8pe).

Comment: I'll give you that @Dada. That is one serious test case :)

Comment: Corrected and tested with your test case.

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 16 bytes

```
"@Y:Ybn&h][ACA]=
```

The input is a cell array of strings and returns a [truthy or falsey array](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5@QqQABqgpu@UUKiTk5Cpl5BaUlxVz2CnAZzzSFkqLSVC51EKnOVYuQSc0pTlVISwSSXOpgSp0r1iXk/39DLgOuaEMFIIzlijZQAMJYEN8AyAcA).

[**Try it Online**](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/kEGkVmZSnlhEb7ejsGGv7/3@1ekhGqkJuYp5CZp5CCZBZXJpZoq6jnlkM4SXmQmTTivJzISIl@UWpekAVHqkKQEWJCsn5@TkK6aWVeuq1AA)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input
"       % For each element in the cell array
@Y:Yb   % Split it on spaces
n       % Count the number of elements
&h      % Horizontally concatenate everything on the stack
[ACA]   % Create the array [5 7 5]
=       % Perform an element-wise equality
        % Implicitly display the truthy/falsey array
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB / Octave, 38 bytes

```
@(x)cellfun(@(y)sum(y==32),x)==[4 6 4]
```

This solution accepts a cell array of strings as input, counts the number of spaces in each line and then compares the result to the array `[4 6 4]` and yields a truthy (all values are 1) or falsey (any value is zero) array.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/KK8UDN)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 25 bytes

```perl6
{.lines».words~~(5,7,5)}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 82 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @corvus_192!

```java
s->s[0].split(" ").length==5&s[2].split(" ").length==5&s[1].split(" ").length==7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#dU5BasMwEDzLr1h0CPahIi2UHoL7gvaUo8lhbcuOiCwZ7TqhBL9dlZKSXlrmMOzMMLPz0lrTQWeRCD7ROLgWwjjWYcBOwwdObY9XmO@x1nur0UFYXLnnYNzYHOCI5rRcqh2shfjJESMnOnvTw5RKf8MYRqryhrhXw1BHenqnZntQNFvDpQRZKavdyMe6ft1sqHn533r@03qLQuzSxP6LWE/KL6zmtM/WlYPKv9@@qFJkLdYYJcLkMVx86AEzZJS3o30gSwhZJHiw/AY)

It looks *so golfable* but without a builtin map function, I can't find a good way. Iterating through the array is a few bytes longer, as is writing a map function using streams.

Lambda expression takes an array of Strings and returns a Boolean.

Comment: What if you have only two lines as input, or four?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen according the op, "A length-3 list of strings as an input is also acceptable". My program takes a length-3 list of lines.

Comment: You could get a map function if you called `Arrays.stream`, but that's long enough that it may not be worth using (especially if you need to import `Arrays`)

Comment: @Pokechu22 yeah I tried that, still ended up being longer.

Comment: You can use `&` instead of `&&` to save two bytes

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 44 bytes

```
#(=(for[l %](count(filter #{\ }l)))'(4 6 4))
```

Input is list of strings.
Function finds only spaces and counts them.
This explanation is a Haiku. :)

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, <s>96</s> 94 bytes

```
INPUT A$,B$,C$?C(A$,4)*C(B$,6)*C(C$,4)DEF C(S,E)WHILE""<S
INC N,POP(S)<"!
WEND
RETURN N==E
END
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 154 bytes

```
class M{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a.length==3&&a[0].split(" ").length==5&a[1].split(" ").length==7&a[2].split(" ").length==5);}}
```

The program requirement and potential of having less or more than three lines, not too mention Java's verbosity itself, causes this 'golfed' code to be pretty big..

**Ungolfed:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/mW9xaG)

```
class M{
  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.print(a.length == 3
        && a[0].split(" ").length == 5
         & a[1].split(" ").length == 7
         & a[2].split(" ").length == 5);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## SimpleTemplate, 77 bytes

Sadly, the regular expression aproach is the shortest.

```
{@if"@^([^\s]+ ?){5}\s([^\s]+ ?){7}\s([^\s]+ ?){5}+$@"is matchesargv}{@echo1}
```

Requires that the text is given as the first argument, with *NIX-style newlines.
This won't work with Windows-style newlines.

**Ungolfed:**

```
{@if "@^([^\s]+ ?){5}\s([^\s]+ ?){7}\s([^\s]+ ?){5}+$@"is matches argv}
    {@echo 1}
{@/}
```

---

**Non-regex based, 114 byes**

```
{@setR 1}{@eachargv asL keyK}{@php$DATA[L]=count(explode(' ',$DATA[L]))!=5+2*($DATA[K]&1)}{@set*R R,L}{@/}{@echoR}
```

This requires that each line is given as an argument to the function.

**Ungolfed:**

```
{@set result 1}
{@each argv as line key k}
    {@php $DATA['line'] = count(explode(' ', $DATA['line'])) != 5+2*( $DATA['k'] & 1 )}
    {@set* result result, line}
{@/}
{@echo result}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Stacked, 22 bytes

```
[' 'eq sum]map(4 6 4)=
```

Takes input from the top of the stack as a list of character strings, as such:

```
($'The man in the suit' $'is the same man from the store.' $'He is a cool guy.')
```

### Explanation

```
[' 'eq sum]map(4 6 4)=
[         ]map          map the following function over each item
 ' 'eq                  vectorized equality with ' '
       sum              summed
              (4 6 4)=  is equal to (4 6 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
€#€g575SQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oaY0yEKebmpsGB/7/H60ekpGqkJuYp5CZp1ACZBaXZpao66hnFkN4ibkQ2bSi/FyISEl@UaoeUIVHqgJQUaJCcn5@jkJ6aaWeeuzXvHzd5MTkjFQA)

**Explanation**

```
€#         # split each line on spaces
  €g       # get length of each line
    575    # push the number 575
       S   # split into list of digits
        Q  # compare for equality
```

Comment: I couldn't get away from `vy` and 10 bytes, nice solution. Using `ð¢` and `464` instead was my approach, unfortunately 464 is still 2 bytes compressed, obviously.

Comment: @carusocomputing: That's an interesting idea. I think you could post that as `ð¢464SïQ` in 2sable for 8 bytes.

Comment: You go ahead, that's more your answer than mine in all honesty (I think it's a winning answer too!)

Comment: @carusocomputing: `ð¢` is the main part of that answer and it was your idea :)

Comment: ahhh, just give me a shoutout. If it ends up having a flaw I won't know how to fix it haha.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 100 bytes

```
f<-function(a){all(sapply(a,function(x){length(grep(" ",as.list(strsplit(x,"")[[1]])))})==c(4,6,4))}
```

Takes as an argument a length-3 list of strings. Probably won't be golfed further since further golfing turns it into @Billywob's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 135 bytes

```
1 INPUT a$: DIM b$(SPLIT a$,NOT ","): l$=""
2 FOR EACH c$ IN b$()
3 DIM d$(SPLIT c$,NOT " ")
4 l$=l$+STR$ ARSIZE d$()
5 NEXT c$
6  ?l$="575"
```

Input is a comma separated string, each part being put in an array.
Then each of those elements are split up on spaces and the length of that array is appended to a string.

Prints 1 (true) or 0 (false) if it matches the 5-7-5 format.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>136</s> 124 bytes

*Saved 12 bytes thanks to **VisualMelon***

```
class P{static void Main(string[]s){var v="";foreach(var c in s)v+=c.Split(' ').Length;System.Console.WriteLine(v=="575");}}
```

Arguments require each sentence to be wrapped in double quotes and then separated by a space, like this:

```
"One two three four five" "One two three four five six seven" "One two three four five"
```

### Ungolfed

```
    class P
{
    static void Main(string[]s)
    {
        var v=""; //Short way to make a string
        foreach(var c in s) //loop through all sentences
            v += c.Split(' ').Length; //split on space and append the array size as string
        );
        System.Console.WriteLine(v == "575"); //print the result!         
    }
}
```

Please note this is my first attempt on golfing ever, let me know if anything is against the rules. Also feel free to point out things that makes this golf even shorter!

Comment: Doesn't look like there is anything illegal here, and it's refreshing to see a complete program submitted ;) Few standard tricks: you don't need the space ` ` in `string[] s`, you can often save bytes by adding a `using System;` clause, but in this case you don't need to as it's much cheaper to use a `foreach` loop instead of `Array.ForEach`: `foreach(var c in s)v+=c.Split(' ').Length;`

Comment: @VisualMelon Wow, that's some useful tricks right there. Thanks alot! I'll update my answer :)

Comment: I don't think there's any need to print the linebreak, so you can just use `Write`.

Comment: Actually, instructions say "Other boolean return values, such as 1 and 0, are acceptable." -- so you can just `return` an exit code, dropping the print entirely. Added bonus, `int Main` is shorter than `void Main`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
puts ARGV.map{|l|l.split.size}==[5,7,5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@19QWlKs4BjkHqaXm1hQXZNTk6NXXJCTWaJXnFmVWmtrG22qY65jGvv///9EBSj8n6yABBHiAA)

Accepts lines of input as command-line arguments, finds the word counts, and check they are 5/7/5

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### C# 6 - 80 bytes (98 with using)

```cs
bool a(string[]s)=>s.Select(x=>x.Split(' ').Length).SequenceEqual(new[]{5,7,5});
```

This, as usual, assumes a method is enough, and doesn't include a complete program.

It also doesn't include `using System.Linq;`, as it is present as default in the standard C# class template from VS 2008 onwards. Add 18 bytes if you want to include it in the count.

The method accepts the input as an aray of strings (one per line), then splits every string using spaces as separators, keeping the length of every array generated this way. Finally, it checks if those lengths are equal to {5,7,5}.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - <s>78</s> 75 bytes

*Saved one byte thanks to **Kevin Cruijssen***

Here's my first ever submission on PPCG :

```
<?=preg_match('#^(\S+ ){4}\S+\r\n(\S+ ){6}\S+\r\n(\S+ ){4}\S+$#',$argv[1]);
```

**Regex breakdown :**

```
#                   Regex delimiter
^                   Starts with
(\S+ ){4}           [Any non-space character present n times, followed by a space] x 4
\S+                 Any non-space character present n times
\r\n                Carriage return
(\S+ ){6}           [Any non-space character present n times, followed by a space] x 6
\S+                 Any non-space character present n times
\r\n                Carriage return
(\S+ ){4}           [Any non-space character present n times, followed by a space] x 4
\S+                 Any non-space character present n times
$                   Ends with
#                   Regex delimiter
```

[Try it online !](https://eval.in/727680)

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This looks like a good first submission to me. Btw, you can save 1 more byte by removing the space after the comma. :) Enjoy your stay! (PS: If you haven't seen it yet, there is a [Tips for golfing in PHP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) post you might find interesting to read through.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip and the link. I managed to save another 2 bytes by switching `echo ` to `<?=`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 46 bytes

```
<?=array_map(str_word_count,$argv)==[0,5,7,5];
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?=array_map(str_word_count,$argv)==[0,5,7,5];' | php -- "The man in the suit" "is the same man from the store." "He is a cool guy." 2>/dev/null
> 1
```

## Explanation

```
<?=                        # Print result of the expression.
  array_map(               # Apply function to each input line.
    str_word_count,        # Count words
    $argv
  )==[0,5,7,5];            # Check if result is 5,7,5 (need 0 because
                           # first arg is always `-`).
```

Comment: Are you sure that `word_count()==0` will work for any `$argv[1]`?

Comment: @Titus, do you mean `$argv[0]`? The first argument when running with `-r` or passing code via stdin

Comment: ... is always `-`

Comment: ... in online interpreters. Save to file and try offline. ;) Yea ok ... it works for stdin.

Comment: My code is not intended to be run from file. So it's valid then. In any case, if you want to run it from a file, just add `[0]+...` at the beginning, and it will force the first array item to be 0, regardless of the script name. (4 bytes)

Comment: No, it´s ok; but `[0]+` is a nice hint.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 29 bytes

```
([5,7,5]==).(length.words<$>)
```

Ungolfed

```
wordCount line = length (words line)
isHaikuW lines = map wordCount lines == [5, 7, 5]
```

Comment: I think this fails to validate the "Valid haiku-w inputs should not have leading or trailing spaces, or multiple spaces separating words."-rule specified in the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex, 44 Bytes

I'm new to codegolfing, but have attempted one with a regex.

```
/^(\S+ ){4}\S+\n(\S+ ){6}\S+\n(\S+ ){4}\S+$/
```

will match exactly 5, 7, 5 words and not match anything else.
ie.

```
Golfing with regex is fun
obscurity prevails; intention is hidden from view
and sanity is forever lost
```

First block `(\S+ ){4})` matches four words (at least one nonspace character) with a trailing space. `\S+\n` matches a word and a newline.

Second block `(\S+ ){6}\S+\n` is similar but for 6 words, trailing space, word and newline.
Third block is identical to first `(\S+ ){4}\S+\n)`

`^(...)$` ensures that the match is found at the beginning and end, so it won't match a haiku inside a string.

Suggested improvements welcome as it's my first time golfing (and I'm rusty at regex).

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
5 7 5]qN/Sf/:,=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@2@qYK5gGlvopx@cpm@lY/v/f0hGqkJuYp5CZp5CCZBZXJpZwpVZDGEn5kLk0orycyEiJflFqXpcHqkKQCWJCsn5@TkK6aWVegA)

**Explanation**

```
5 7 5]           The array [5, 7, 5]
      q          Read all input
       N/        Split on newlines
         Sf/     Split each line on spaces
            :,   Get the length of each line (in words)
              =  Check if the two arrays are equal
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 34 bytes

```
_.map(_ split " "size)==Seq(5,7,5)
```

Usage:

```
val f:(Seq[String]=>Boolean)=_.map(_ split " "size)==Seq(5,7,5)
println(f(Seq("The man in the suit", "is the same man from the store.", "He is a cool guy.")))
```

Ungolfed:

```
array=>array.map(line=>line.split(" ").size)==Seq(5,7,5)
```

Explanation:

```
 _.map(               //map each line in the argument
     _ split " "size  //  to the number of parts when the line is splitted at spaces
 ) == Seq(5,7,5)      //compare that to a sequence of 5, 7, and 5
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>114</s> <s>113</s> 108 bytes

```
n,i,r,c;f(){n=i=r=1;while(n<4){c=getchar();c-32?c-10?1:++n%2?i-7?(r=0):(i=1):i-5?(r=0):(i=1):++i;}return r;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
εð¢}ƵĆ7вQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NbDGw4tqj229Uib@YVNgf//RyuFZKQq5CbmKWTmKZQAmcWlmSVKOgpKmcUQbmIuRDqtKD8XIlKSX5SqB1LikaoAVJWokJyfn6OQXlqppxQLAA)

```
εð¢}ƵĆ7вQ  # full program
        Q  # is...
  ¢        # the list of the number of..
 ð         # spaces...
  ¢        # in...
           # (implicit) current element in...
ε          # for each element in...
           # implicit input...
        Q  # equal to...
       в   # the list of the base...
      7    # literal...
       в   # digits of...
    ƵĆ     # 242...
        Q  # ?
   }       # end map
           # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Oḷ575d⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPU8lRTElQjglQjc1NzVkJUUyJTgxJUJDJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTIyVGhlJTIwbWFuJTIwaW4lMjB0aGUlMjBzdWl0JTIyJTJDJTIwJTIyaXMlMjB0aGUlMjBzYW1lJTIwbWFuJTIwZnJvbSUyMHRoZSUyMHN0b3JlLiUyMiUyQyUyMCUyMkhlJTIwaXMlMjBhJTIwY29vbCUyMGd1eS4lMjImZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
Oḷ575d⁼  # Implicit input
O        # Split each line on spaces
 ḷ       # Get the length of each inner list
      ⁼  # And check if it's exactly equal to
  575d   # The list [5,7,5]
         # Implicit output
```