# Factory workers

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

## Challenge

Factory workers are usually very hard-working. However, their work is now being commonly replaced with machines.

You have to write a program that takes a number as input. It will print out a factory of 10 workers 10 times. Every time, each worker has a `1/input` chance of being 'fired' and replaced by a machine.

### Input

An integer, coming from STDIN or a function call.

### Output

10 cases of the factory, each one with usually more workers fired.

## Output format - how to print a factory

A factory looks like this:

`|0000000000|` or `|0000011001|`

A pipe represents the walls, a 0 represents a worker, and a 1 represents a machine, so the first print of the factory will always be `|0000000000|`.

## Example

#### Input: 10

#### Output:

```
|0000000000| //always start off with this
|0000000010| //a 1/10 chance means that this worker lost his job
|0000010010|
|0010010010|
|1010010010|
|1010110010|
|1010110011|
|1010111011|
|1010111111|
|1110111111|
```

---

#### Input: 5

#### Output:

```
|0000000000| //always start here
|0000001001| //a 1/5 chance means that 2 workers got fired
|1000101001|
|1000101111|
|1101101111|
|1111111111| //after achieving all machinery, the machines continue to be printed
|1111111111|
|1111111111|
|1111111111|
|1111111111|
```

## NOTE

The number of workers fired is RANDOM - in my examples for `1/5 chance` there would always be 2 workers fired but your program has to do this randomly - sometimes 1 and sometimes 3 - they just have 1/5 chance of being fired.

Comment: The input is always `>1`? what happens if you still have a worker after 10 iterations ?

Comment: It doesn't matter - the worker can be considered very lucky ;)

Comment: Does an input of 10 mean that each worker has a 1/10 chance of losing their job each time, or that 1/10th of the workers will be fired each time?

Comment: The former as specified in the NOTE (sometimes 1 sometimes 3)

Comment: can we have spaces between the workers, like `| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |`?

Comment: @12Me21 it means each worker has a 1/10 chance of losing their job, NOT the latter.

Comment: @Uriel No, I'm mean =)

Comment: @Arnauld it seems like it was simply a mistake, and I was the only one who took it as correct :)

Comment: Shouldthe 1/x chance per worker or per employed worker?

Comment: @Pureferret It doesn´t matter. Any worker already sacked could have a (x-1)/x chance of not being fired again; but he stays fired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
AÆP=®|!UöÃªAçTÃû|C
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QcZQPa58IVX2w6pB51TD+3xD&input=OAotUg==)

---

### Explanation

```
AÆP=®|!UöÃªAçTÃû|C     :Implicit input of integer U
A                      :10
 Æ                     :Map the range [0,A)
  P=                   :  Assign to P (initially the empty string)
    ®                  :    Map P
     |                 :      Bitwise OR with
      !                :      The negation of
       Uö              :      A random integer in the range [0,U)
         Ã             :    End Map
          ª            :    OR, for the first element when the above will still be an empty string (falsey)
           Aç          :    Ten times repeat
             T         :      Zero
              Ã        :End Map
               û|      :Centre pad each element with "|"
                 C     :  To length 12
                       :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>92</s> 89 bytes

```r
cat(t(cbind("|",apply("[<-"(matrix(runif(100)<1/scan(),10),1,,0),2,cummax),"|
")),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTBCoAgDADQe5@x0waLNOhWX9JpWYGQImZQ4L8vD@9lVScFC7rNxx2hAktK14ewzj1gkJL9i/mJ/kRrDM12uJ1EJLamYW6P7J4Q5CWG2gER30daAEgn/QE)

Ungolfed:

```r
m <- matrix(runif(100)<1/n,10,10)   #10x10 matrix of TRUE with probability 1/n
                                    #and FALSE with probability 1-1/n
m[1,] <- 0                          #set first row to 0
m <- apply(m,2,cummax)              #take the column cumulative maxima
m <- cbind("|",m,"|\n")             #put "|" as the first and last columns
m <- t(m)                           #transpose m for the write function
cat(m,sep="")                       #print m to stdout, separated by ""
```

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time trying to beat 92 this afternoon using various implementations of `replicate` and `for` loops without success, however but with your tips for `Do-while loops`, I have finally just realized how abusable `{` potentially this. I have extended this abuse to an example with `for()` for a 92 bytes solution. Maybe you already realized the implications of `{` abuse when you wrote that tip post, but I have realized just now. https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEtvyhBI1OnusK2ODkxT0PTusy2KLVAw0DH0EDT2tDKslanOjmxREOpRkmnTEephktJpzi1wFZJCaQwN7GgIKcSKldUmpeZpgHUZWOoX6GpbVCr@d/0PwA

Comment: @Vlo Is that the right TIO link? Still, looks like you've beaten me with a function! I golfed you down to [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcuxCoAgEADQva@Qm@7gopzLjxFJcMjE8hCyb7doe8vL3a9j9yW6KxwRK4vJW8KZ9Uzkj4xBhaiEbmcvhAYsDG0APrdkAGgRk3ZbUTiXGDx@a9VTpaf/7i8)

Comment: I should start an R chatroom... I think `"for"` is almost always no better than `for`, and it's [occasionally worse](https://tio.run/##K/r/Xyktv0hJI1PH0MpUx83WTdtQU0FZoSQjs1ihPD9PvQRIFmVzuf13U7DRVXBz9Al25ULWUQ3WUgvSk5eamgLUmKqQVJSYnFrM5caFQ4@bjS7YGqCe/CKQksTi4sz0vNzUvBJUTUA9GpkKmXkKQF2aYIsUYG4DIpBVxRn5RSWpxUB9/wE)!

Comment: Haha, of course `pmax` can be used. Here is my earlier point about the `{` operator. https://tio.run/##PZDBasNADETv@xVDfKhNjcGHXAKl5OJTT2l/YGPL2aXLKmjlBBP67e7WSXoRCL2RZiTLshlZNqWv29227t6617ZCAXU@4crxRXOVb9MtBb4c4QY@k1hlQW8jjgS@kAS2Aw24enVQhpWjV7EyQ6YIG2f0PNA69vf@gHGKvXqODfYJFkJpClo/hit@4jAiOZ7CgCxTRyzzO6aUb8Yw50JIpOARZdWs7nISBOYzsvmsFCV5JLFzY0yBD44nEpO50uelt7/M2137U9W91dJXVWY@70Lz/Ms/9GSWXw

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 84 bytes

```js
n=>[...s=2e9+''].map(j=>`|${s=s.replace(/./g,i=>i&1|Math.random()*n<!+j)}|`).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCsIgFADQ9/4iiNSsuxb0EKR/0Be0QHFuKe4qOnrJvt3O8fqji8kurSeMo22TaCjkEwCKuNgbJ@QFi07UC6nq7ltEgWxT0MbSDrr56IR0@74@9PqGrHGMC2UHvG@5Z7@qGPjoUG1UMxFLDBZCnOlE@zPjZMABCZ/olbH2Bw)

---

## Recursive version, 88 bytes

```js
n=>(g=k=>k?`|${s=s.replace(/./g,i=>i%5|Math.random()*n<(s!=k))}|
`+g(k>>3):'')(s=5e9+'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchBDsIgEADAe39houmuVaoxHDQuvsA/lFBKEYQGGi/Wt6NXb5N5yJfMKtlp3ofY6zJQCSTAkCPhbt2yfmfKLOnJS6WhZa3ZWRJ2w5e7nEeWZOjjE3AbrpBX5BA/S9U1BpwQJ7zUNUImrs/NT0XFkKPXzEcDAxwPiNV/ccTyBQ)

#### How?

We start with **k = s = '5000000000'**.

At each iteration:

- We coerce each character **i** of **s** to a number, compute **i modulo 5** -- so that the leading **5** is treated like a **0** -- and randomly perform a bitwise OR with **1** with the expected probability **1/n**, except on the first iteration.
- The counter **k** is right-shifted by 3 bits. We stop the recursion as soon as **k = 0**, which gives 10 iterations.

  It is important to note that **5000000000** is slightly larger than a 32-bit integer, so it is implicitly converted to **5000000000 & 0xFFFFFFFF = 705032704** just before the first bitwise shift occurs. Hence the following steps:

  ```
   step | k
  ------+-----------
     0  | 705032704
     1  | 88129088
     2  | 11016136
     3  | 1377017
     4  | 172127
     5  | 21515
     6  | 2689
     7  | 336
     8  | 42
     9  | 5
    10  | 0
  ```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 37 bytes

```apl
⎕{⎕←' '~⍨⍕'|'⍵'|'⋄×⍵+⍺=?10⍴⍺}⍣10⊢10⍴0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1GogftQ2QV1Bve5R74pHvVPVa9Qf9W4Fkd0th6cDmdqPenfZ2hsaPOrdAmTVPupdDGR3LQILGPz/b2gAAA)

**How?**

`10⍴0` - start with 10 zeros.

`⎕←' '~⍨⍕'|'⍵'|'` - every time print the formatted array,

`?10⍴⍺` - generate a random array with values ranging `1` to input,

`⍺=` - element-wise comparison with the input. should mark `1` / input of the elements, giving each a `1` / input every time,

`⍵+` - add to the array,

`×` - signum. zero stays zero, anything greater than one comes back to one.

`⍣10` - repeat 10 times.

Comment: Confused I am, +1 =)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>82</s> <s>80</s> 69 bytes

```powershell
param($x)($a=,0*10)|%{"|$(-join$a)|";$a=$a|%{$_-bor!(Random -ma $x)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCU0Ml0VbHQMvQQLNGtVqpRkVDNys/M08lUbNGyRoopZIIFFaJ103KL1LUCErMS8nPVdDNTVQA6qyt/f//vykA)

Takes input `$x`. Creates an array of all zeros, saves that into `$a` and then loops that many times. Conveniently, the factory is just as wide as it is iterations worth. Each iteration, we output our current factory with `"|$(-join$a)|"`, then loop through each element of `$a`.

Inside we're selecting the current element `$_` that has been `-b`inary-`or`ed with either `1` based on the `Random` chance based on input `$x`. For example, for input `10`, `Get-Random -max 10` will range between `0` and `9` and be `0` approximately 1/10th of the time. Thus with a `!(...)` wrapping the `Random`, we'll get a `1` approximately `1/input` amount of the time, and the other `1-1/input` amount of the time we'll get `$_`. Yes, this sometimes means that we're overwriting a `1` with another `1`, but that's fine.

That resulting array is then stored back into `$a` for the next go-round. All of the resulting strings are left on the pipeline, and the implicit `Write-Output` at program completion gives us newlines for free.

*-2 bytes thanks to Veskah.*
*-11 bytes thanks to ASCII-only.*

Comment: [80 Bytes?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCU0Ml0VbHQMvQQLNGtVqpRkVDNys/M08lUbNGyRoopZIIFAaqiVbJ1NZWNTSI1THUjFbUCErMS8nPVdDNTVQAmhFbW/v//39TAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Veskah Yes, that will work nicely. Thanks!

Comment: [78?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCU0Ml0VbHQMvQQLNGtVqpRkVDNys/M08lUbNGyRoopZIIFFZJjFbJ1NZWNTSI1U3KL1LUCErMS8nPVdDNTVQAGlFb@///f1MA)

Comment: [69????](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCU0Ml0VbHQMvQQLNGtVqpRkVDNys/M08lUbNGyRoopZIIFFaJ103KL1LUCErMS8nPVdDNTVQA6qyt/f//vykA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Oh sure, why are we re-indexing into `$a` when we're already looping through it? lol And that's a clever trick with the `-bor`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 30 bytes

```
.+
|¶10*$(*0¶
.-10+0\%0<@`\d
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bq@bQNkMDLRUNLYND27j0dA0NtA1iVA1sHBJiUriAKgwNAA)

I'm having lots of fun with randomness in Retina^^

#### Explanation

The first stage sets up the string we will be working with:

```
.+
|¶10*$(*0¶
```

It replaces the whole input with `|`, a newline, and then 10 lines containing as many `0`s as the input says. The first character on each line will represent a   worker of the factory.

The following stage means:

```
.                     Disable automatic printing at the end of the program
 -10+                 Do the following exactly 10 times:
       %                For each line:
        0<                Print the first character, then
          @`\d            Pick a random digit and
1 (on the next line)      replace it with a 1
     0\                 Then print the first character of the whole string
                        followed by a newline
```

The first line of the working string contains only a `|`, which will be the first character printed by every iteration of the loop (being the first character of the first line), and will be also printed at the end of every iteration (being the first character of the whole string). The replacement will never have any effect on this line because it doesn't contain any digit.

Each other line contains `n` digits, so there is a 1 in `n` chance to turn the first character of the line (which is the only meaningful one) into a `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>104</s> 103 bytes

```python
from random import*
x='0'*10;i=input()
exec"print'|%s|'%''.join(x);x=[choice('1'+n*~-i)for n in x];"*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCsMgEADAe14hgbBqadFexZeUHIo1ZAvZla0FCyFftznNbcqvrkz33hfhTcmTXie4FZZqhxbBgfUuYEQq36rNkFtOYxGkCvv02WECuL0ZSTcTWnyklTFlDR4uZI8rmoVFkUJSbQ7jWfXu3R8)

Comment: Sorry, you need to format the output

Comment: @lolad fixed c:

Comment: well done, +1 =)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>105</strike> <strike>93</strike> 90 bytes

```javascript
x=>w.map(a=>(`|${w=w.map(j=>j|Math.random()<1/x),w.join``}|
`)).join``,w=Array(10).fill(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdBDsIgEADAu@/wsJtUbD27JD6gf2DTFoVQtqGN1Ihvx4PObTw/eR2SW7ZTlHGqlupOOquZF2DSYMrxnel3T9qXnreHShxHmQGv3XnHJisvLhrzKQeD@E@T6ZYSv6BrUVkXArRYB4mrhEkFuYOFC2L9Ag)

+2 bytes for putting the array inside the function, thanks to @Shaggy for pointing that out

```javascript
(x,w=Array(10).fill(0))=>w.map(a=>(`|${w=w.map(j=>j|Math.random()<1/x),w.join``}|
`)).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5BCsIwEEDRfc/hYgZqbAV3TsADeIcMbaMJaVLSYirGs0dBN@Lyv9W3fOO5i2Zatj70Q9FUYK0TnWLkO7QNCm2cgwaRZBIjT8AkQeXNI9GnLUmbz7xcRWTfhxHw2O5WrJOwwXilnrlSiN8oXfBzcINw4QIa9ojVrxz@5P2A5QU)

Comment: Note that functions need to be reusable here, so `w` will need to be declared *within* your function.

Comment: @Shaggy, thanks I edited it. unfortunately it added 2 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẋ⁵ẋ€⁵¬1¦X€€=1o\j@€⁾||Y
```

A full program accepting the integer as a  command line input and printing the output to STDOUT.
(As a monadic link it returns a list of characters and integers.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hru5HjVtBZNMaIOPQGsNDyyJA7KY1tob5MVkOYPF9NTWR////NwUA)**

#### How?

Effectively decides at each stage if each worker (including any machines) lose their job (with a one in N chance), however machines are replaced by machines (using logical-OR).

```
ẋ⁵ẋ€⁵¬1¦X€€=1o\j@€⁾||Y - Main link: integer, N
 ⁵                     - literal ten
ẋ                      - repeat -> [N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N]
    ⁵                  - literal ten
  ẋ€                   - repeat €ach -> [[N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N],...,[N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N]]
       ¦               - sparse application...
      1                - ...to indices: [1]
     ¬                 - ...do: logical-NOT -> [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[N,N,...],...]
        X€€            - random integer for €ach for €ach
                       -   (0s stay as 0s; Ns become random integers in [1,N])
           =1          - equals one? (vectorises)
             o\        - cumulative reduce with logical-OR
                  ⁾||  - literal list of characters = ['|','|']
               j@€     - join with sw@pped arguments for €ach
                     Y - join with line feeds
                       - implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 58 bytes

```
{say "|$_|" for 0 x 10,|[\~|] ([~] +(1>$_*rand)xx 10)xx 9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ujixUkGpRiW@RkkhLb9IwUChQsHQQKcmOqauJlZBI7ouVkFbw9BOJV6rKDEvRbMCJAsiLWv/g3X6KdgqGFkpWSukaRhpWivAxUwhYqaa1v8B)

`+(1 > $_ * rand)` generates a single bit with the required frequency of `1`s.  `xx 10` replicates that expression ten times to produce a single factory instance as a list of bits, and `[~]` joins that list into a single string.  `xx 9` replicates that factory-string-generating expression nine times, and then `[\~|]` does a triangular reduction (which some other languages call a "scan") with the stringwise or operator `~|`, so that a worker fired in an earlier iteration remains fired in later ones.

Comment: Nice. You can remove the space before `for`. Beats the number-based solution `{say "|{.join}|"for [\<<+|>>] (?$++X*!<<^$_).roll(10)xx 10}` I was working on by two bytes. With `[\Z+|]` it would be 56 bytes but this doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: You can also replace `$_*rand` with `.rand`. The way I interpret the rules, returning a list of "factory" strings should also be OK.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>110</strike> 106 bytes

-4 bytes from @ceilingcat

```c
char l[]="|0000000000|",i,j;f(n){for(srand(time(i=0));i++<10;)for(j=!puts(l);j++<10;)rand()%n||(l[j]=49);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrLCoMwEADv@QorFHbRQoReyjZfIh5CNO2GGEu0J@O3pw/EOc6MuTyMydk8dSx826kyyYNU1lw7shBwtVOEOerQw8LjAKwkInFV3RtJ@ItOnV7vZQaP5Hb93/EcUgLfuk5db0hbHjUHQLGK4ouFRiKJLX8A)

Iterates through a list of characters for each round of replacements.

Ungolfed:

```c
f(n)
{
    //start with a fresh factory
    char l[]="|0000000000|";

    //init rng
    srand(time(0));

    //print 11 lines
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        //print current factory
        puts(l);

        //iterate through the workers. start at index 1 to skip the '|'
        for(int j = 1; j < 11; j++)
        {
            //the expression (rand()%n) has n possible values in the range [0,n-1],
            //so the value 0 has 1/n chance of being the result and thus the worker
            //has 1/n chance of being replaced
            if(rand()%n == 0)
            {
                l[j] = '1';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you print 1 too many factories. The example shows 10, but your TIO link shows 11.

Comment: Hm you're right. I changed it to 11 after reading a comment on someone else's solution telling them it's supposed to be 11, but I never actually verified the example from the challenge. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 26 bytes

```
'|'it10th&Yr=0lY(Y>48+y&Yc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X71GPbPE0KAkQy2yyNYgJ1Ij0s7EQrtSLTL5/39TAA)

#### (Long) explanation

Example stack contents are shown along the way. At each step, stack contents are shown bottom to top.

```
'|'    % Push this character
       % STACK: '|'
it     % Take input. Duplicate
       % STACK: '|'
                5
                5
10th   % Push [10 10]
       % STACK: '|'
                5
                5
                [10 10]
&Yr    % Random 10×10 matrix of integers from 1 to input number
       % STACK: '|'
                 5
                 [4 5 4 4 5 5 2 1 2 3
                  3 4 3 3 1 4 4 3 1 5
                  5 1 4 5 4 4 5 2 3 2
                  3 4 5 2 1 3 2 5 3 4
                  4 1 2 2 4 1 1 5 1 1
                  4 5 3 1 5 3 5 2 4 1
                  2 1 4 3 3 1 3 5 3 5
                  1 2 2 1 2 2 4 3 5 3
                  4 5 4 1 2 2 5 3 2 4
                  4 1 2 5 5 5 4 3 5 1]
=      % Is equal? Element-wise
       % STACK: '|'
                [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
                 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
                 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
                 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
                 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
0lY(   % Write 0 in the first row
       % STACK: '|'
                [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
                 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
                 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
                 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
                 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
Y>     % Cumulative maximum down each column
       % STACK: '|'
                [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
                 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
                 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
                 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
                 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
                 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
                 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
                 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
                 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
48+    % Add 48, element-wise. This transforms each number into the
       % ASCII code of its character representation
       % STACK: '|'
                [48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
                 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 49
                 49 48 48 49 48 48 49 48 48 49
                 49 48 49 49 48 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 48 49 49 48 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 49 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 49 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49]
y      % Duplicate from below
       % STACK: '|'
                [48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
                 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 49
                 49 48 48 49 48 48 49 48 48 49
                 49 48 49 49 48 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 48 49 49 48 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 48 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 49 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 48 49 49 49 49
                 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49]
                 '|'
&Yc    % Horizontally concatenate all stack contents as char arrays.
       % 1-row arrays are implicitly replicated along first dimension
       % STACK: ['|0000000000|'
                 '|0000000001|'
                 '|1001001001|'
                 '|1011001101|'
                 '|1011001101|'
                 '|1111101101|'
                 '|1111101101|'
                 '|1111101111|'
                 '|1111101111|'
                 '|1111111111|']
       % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 75 bytes

```
INPUT N
FOR J=0TO 9?"|";BIN$(F,10);"|
FOR I=0TO 9F=F OR!RND(N)<<I
NEXT
NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -a
say"|$_|",s/0/rand"@F"<1|0/eg<0for(0 x10)x10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKpRiW@RkmnWN9AvygxL0XJwU3JxrDGQD813cYgLb9Iw0ChwtBAE4j//zf9l19QkpmfV/xfN/G/rq@pnqGBngEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
TÅ0TFDJ'|.ø=sITи€L€ΩΘ~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5HCrQYibi5d6jd7hHbbFniEXdjxqWuMDxOdWnptR9/@/OQA)

There should be some more room for golfing.

- `TÅ0` — Push a list of 10 zeroes.
- `TF...` — Do this 10 times:

  - `DJ` — Duplicate the current item and join it.
  - `'|.ø=` — Surround it with two `|`s and print to STDOUT.
  - `ITи` — Repeat the input 10 times.
  - `€L€Ω` — And for each occurrence, get a random element of **[1 ... N]**. (There might be a built-in for this which I haven’t seen yet)
  - `Θ` — Push 05AB1E truthified™. For each, check if it equals **1**.
  - `s...~` — Logical OR the result by the current item.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
⊞υ×χ0Ｆχ⊞υ⭆§υ±¹‽⁺1×κ⊖θＥυ⪫||ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy9CsIwFIX3PkXIdC9EaAanToKLQiWoLxDaaxtsEk1Scei7x1To2c7f1406dF5POas5jjALdjeWIshaMF5zxKZ6@MCKR7YtbikYN7T6BYd0cj191/BCg04EElGwq3a9t6CmOQKXfGM@BTtSF8iSS9TDG/9qKlVwCVZe4Zy9ccCXpbzM2ua8z7vP9AM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ×χ0
```

Push an string of 10 `0`s to the empty list `u`.

```
Ｆχ
```

Repeat the next command 10 times.

```
⊞υ⭆§υ±¹‽⁺1×κ⊖θ
```

For each character of the last string, repeat it `n-1` times, add a `1`, and pick a random character from the string. This gives a `1/n` chance of changing the character to a `1`. The result is pushed to `u`.

```
Ｅυ⪫||ι
```

Map over the list of strings, surrounding each with `|`, then implicitly print each on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 83 bytes

```
f=(n,t=9,s=`|0000000000|
`)=>t?s+f(n,t-1,s.replace(/0/g,v=>+(Math.random()<1/n))):s
```

```js
f=(n,t=9,s=`|0000000000|
`)=>t?s+f(n,t-1,s.replace(/0/g,v=>+(Math.random()<1/n))):s
```

```html
<p><input id=i value=10 /><button id=t onclick="o.textContent=f(+i.value)">Run</button><p><pre id=o></pre>
```

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##VchLDsIgEADQfU8yE8vHhYkaB0/gHUooRQ1Cw5CuuDvumvQt39dull35rFWkPPu@UE9kIBCTqUI8@RSAZfFrtM6D0iqMG5mXrW9ZbJrzD/BxVqlpxDsjTE3v2jCNlW7YXU6co5cxB1jggjgc54rY/w)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>153</s> <s>152</s> 131 bytes

```java
n->{for(int j=10,a[]=new int[j],i;j-->0;){var s="|";for(i=0;i<10;a[i++]|=Math.random()*n<1?1:0)s+=a[i];System.out.println(s+"|");}}
```

-18 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*, and -3 more bytes by converting Java 8 to Java 10.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rZIxb4MwEIX3/opTpEq4BGJX6lLH6dQxWTIihisYMCUmsh2iKOG3UwPJ1q2V7OFO7z69d3aNHUZ1/j1kDVoLW1T6@gSgtJOmwEzCbiwBulblkAW@D5pw3@r99cc6dCqDHWgQMOhocy1aM8lqwegSk1RoeR55SZ0uFa@jaEM5uXZowIrFbcEnvaBcrRnlmKgwTG9ii66KDeq8PQTkRa/ZB3unxIbCC1K@v1gnD3F7cvHReHSjAxt6FuF9P/DZ2PH01Xhjd3@T/YMPF@ydnyiTFMkcTMdZwCjhsFoBo8@QVah97LaAUjrnpVAoI3OQmFVg2pPOp7FfLExrmYFvM@/1ziv/ymP04fC/gDPus5Pm0moJZ9U0I@/OwsI/P7hKjrV1MxZGG48FkekL9MMP)

```java
n->{                             // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  for(int j=10,a[]=new int[j],i; //  Create the array with 10 workers (0s)
      j-->0;){                   //  Loop 10 times
   
    var s="|";                   //  Start a String with a wall
    for(i=0;i<10;                //  Loop `i` from 0 to 10 (exclusive)
        a[i++]                   //    After every iteration, change the current item to:
         |=                      //     If it's a 0:
           Math.random()*n<1?    //      If the random value [0:1) is below 1/n
            1                    //       Change the worker to a machine
           :                     //      Else:
            0;                   //       It remains a worker
                                 //     Else (it already is a machine)
                                 //      It remains a machine
      s+=a[i];                   //   Append the current item to the String
    System.out.println(s+"|");}} //   Print the String, with a trailing wall and new-line
```

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##rZIxb4MwEIX3/opTpEq4BGJX6lKHdOqYLBkRw9UYMCUmsh2iKOG3UwPJ1q2V7OFO7z69d3aNHUZ1/j2IBq2FLSp9fQJQ2klToJCwG0uArlU5iMD3QRPuW72//liHTgnYgYYEBh1trkVrJplKGF1imiVankdeqrJlzVUUbSgn1w4N2GRxW/BRXyeU12tGOaZ1GGa3ZIuuig3qvD0E5EWv2Qd7p8SGiRdkfH@xTh7i9uTio/HoRgc29CzC@37gs7Hj6avxxu7@JvsHHy7YOz9RphmSOZiORcAo4bBaAaPPICrUPnZbQCmd81IolJE5SBQVmPak82nsFwvTWmbg28x7vfPKv/IYfTj8L@CM@@ykubRawlk1zci7s7Dwzw@ukmNt3YyF0cZjQWT6Av3wAw). Replace `var` by `String` for Java 9 and below and for an extra 3 bytes. I basically merged the two loops you have.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, <s>30 40</s>  35 bytes

Missed the bit about no spaces ;( - fixed  & thanks to Uriel for -3 bytes

Prompts for screen input of number

```
'|',(⍕0⍪×+⍀n=?9 10⍴n←⎕)[;2×⍳10],'|'
```

Explanation similar to that of Uriel:

```
?9 10⍴n create a 9x10 matrix of numbers selected at random between 1 and number

×+⍀n= compare elements of matrix to number, cumulatively sum columns and signum

[;2×⍳10] take non-space columns

'|',(⍕0⍪.......,'|' concatenate a row of zeros and front and back columns of |
```

Comment: `9 10⍴?90⍴5` → `?9 10⍴5`. You also need to eliminate spaces

Comment: @Uriel thanks for the -3 bytes and I had missed the no space rule.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 132 bytes

```python
from random import*
w,p,c=[0]*10,'|',1/int(input())
for _ in w:print(p+''.join(map(str,w))+p);w=list(map(lambda x:x|(random()<c),w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsIwEEX3PUV2mWmDtoibak8iIrGlGGkmQzqSCr17tLr68N6Dz295BDrkPMbgVbQ0fMd5DlHKIhk2fXepr2VTG71q0@wdCTjilwBiMYaobsqRSi3HzXCl9e4ZHIG3DLNEkxArxlPqJjfLj07W3werlnZZ4f8HeO5xK3M@fgA)

Answer (score 0):

### VBA, 144 bytes

```vb
Sub f(i)
Dim w(9) As Long
For x = 0 To 9
s = "|"
For y = 0 To 9
s = s & w(y)
If i * Rnd() < 1 Then w(y) = 1
Next
Debug.Print s; "|"
Next
End Sub
```

Indented for easier reading:

```vb
Sub f(i)
    Dim w(9) As Long
    For x = 0 To 9
        s = "|"
        For y = 0 To 9
            s = s & w(y)
            If i * Rnd() < 1 Then w(y) = 1
        Next
        Debug.Print s; "|"
    Next
End Sub
```

Takes advantage of 2 points: VBA Arrays will default to Base 0 (so `w(9)` is the same as `w(0 to 9)`) and creating the Array as a Long will automatically initialise it to 0.

(Annoyingly, **20** bytes are auto-formatting that VBA adds in but not actually required - 19 spaces and one semi-colon)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see answer for Ruby yet, so:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 92 bytes

```ruby
n=gets.to_i
z='0'*x=10
x.times do
puts'|'+z+'|'
x.times do|s|
z[s]='1' if rand(n)==0
end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P882PbWkWK8kPz6Tq8pW3UBdq8LW0ICrQq8kMze1WCEln6ugtKRYvUZdu0obSCJJ1BTXcFVFF8faqhuqK2SmKRQl5qVo5Gna2hpwpealgPD//4YGAA)

Comment: Save a byte by using `rand(n)<1` instead of `rand(n)==0`, and save a few by using `{..}` instead of `do..end`, e.g. `x.times{puts'|'+z...}`

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 67 bytes

```
->n{f=[0]*10;10.times{p"|#{f.join}|";f.map!{|l|rand>(1.0/n)?l:?1}}}
```

I think I've cheated a few things here. First of all, this function prints the output with quotes around each line, e.g.:

```
pry(main)> ->n{f=[0]*10;10.times{p"|#{f.join}|";f.map!{|l|rand>(1.0/n)?l:?1}}}[5]
"|0000000000|"
"|0100100000|"
"|0100100000|"
"|0100100000|"
"|0100100100|"
"|0100110100|"
"|0101110100|"
"|0111110100|"
"|1111110110|"
"|1111110110|"
=> 10
```

If this is unacceptable (given that this is [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art), that is probably the case), here is a solution that prints without quotes for **70 bytes**:

```
->n{f=[0]*10;10.times{puts"|#{f.join}|";f.map!{|l|rand>(1.0/n)?l:?1}}}
```

#### Explanation:

```
->n{                                                              } # defines anonymous lambda
    f=[0]*10;                                                       # initializes f to [0,0,0,...] (10)
             10.times{                                           }  # main loop
                      p"|#{f.join}|";                               # joins f and prints | before and after
                                     f.map!{|l|                 }   # maps each element of f
                                               rand>(1.0/n)? :      # if rand is greater than 1.0/n
                                                            l ?1    # keep current element or replace with '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>71</s> 70 bytes

[merging](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158096/55735) [loops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174268/55735) saved 5 bytes (again):

```php
for(;$k<91;$v|=!rand(0,$argn-1)<<$k++%10)$k%10||printf("|%010b|
",$v);
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ebe434c2fa884c3697e151769d1178c1d547d0b5).

---

edit 1: fixed format and first output (no change in byte count thanks to additional golfing)
edit 2: Golfed one more byte: After the last printing, there´s no more need for firing anyone.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 131 bytes

```cs
n=>{var r=new Random();var a=new int[10];for(int i=0;i<100;a[i%10]|=r.Next(n)<1?1:0)if(i++%10<1)Write("|"+string.Concat(a)+"|\n");}
```

Hey, at least I tied with Java.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BS8QwEIXv@RWhsGyGriURvDTtioiHBVFZFzzseghpqkN1uqRZFdr@9pruSW8z73u892x3YTucbmzAlgqksK7Licp1/2U89yW5b741VLWfAvQsmbMUfXslX3XdehFvjqXUWCgptdnjIpKh9NmD@wmCoFDXKpeAtcA0jaxQ8OIxOJEMSdoFj/SW3bZkTRAG0mQ4UAJ6nDSL4c7YdzHXNrGSbyjbOlPt2juqBGTPxw8MYnmgJQDr2Tn0HikGb@h4CjznvRyTVQP6L3s8hQjz2MHqeXv2ZHznRAP/bPEZJyXZFbtk6hc)