# Display 0 - 1000 - 0 each on a separate line

Tags: code-golf, tips, php

I've tried this question on two forums and have been told this is the best place for this type of question. I'm trying to print from 0 to 1000 then back to 0 again (and all numbers in-between), printing 1000 only once. Also, each number must be on a separate line using vanilla PHP.

My current code is 60 characters long. Is there a way to do the same thing but in less characters?

#### [PHP](https://php.net/), 60 bytes

```php
echo implode("<p>",array_merge(range(0,999),range(1000,0)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU5Mz8hUycwty8lNSNZRsCuyUdBKLihIr43NTi9JTNYoS84CkgY6lpaWmDoRjaGBgoGOgqalp/d/e7j8A)

Comment: Welcome! This looks like a solid tips question, but I suggest taking a look at [this list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18613/20260) and see if there's any more helpful info you can give. Where did the challenge originally come from?

Comment: hi, thanks!. i'm studying on a course and its just like a bit of fun set by the trainer. i cant link the challenge because its on a private git hub.

Comment: I think it would be good to link a runnable version of your code. Is [this right](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU5Mz8hUycwty8lNSNZRsCuyUdBKLihIr43NTi9JTNYoS84CkgY6lpaWmDoRjaGBgoGOgqalp/d/e7j8A)? I don't know PHP so I'm not sure if I did it right with the `<?php` around the code and the `<p>` for newlines. You can edit the code and the press the link icon at the top, and the copy-paste option for "Code Golf submission" can be pasted into your question.

Comment: Also, we have [Tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2913/20260) which might give you some inspiration. I noticed [one mentioning `array_merge`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116360/20260) which your code uses.

Comment: May the list end with a trailing `<p>`?

Comment: is that better?

Comment: @Sisyphus is can end however. there arnt really anyrules on the code side. its more about the shortest number of characters and it prints 1000 only once

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 38 bytes

```php
for(;$i-=1|$x|=$i/1001;)echo~$i,"<p>";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMnVtDWtUKmpsVTL1DQ0MDK01U5Mz8utUMnWUbArslKz//wcA)

A one-byte improvement by [JoKing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king). The idea is that by decrementing `$i` instead of incrementing it, we can save on the minus in the `1|-$x` construction by having `$x` become `-1` instead of `1` as a signal. This is achieved by using `$i/1001`, which is `0` if `$i>-1001` and `-1` otherwise. This would break even if not for the fact we can now use `~$i` instead of `$i-1`.

#### [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

```php
for(;$i+=1|-$x|=$i>1e3;)echo$i-1,"<p>";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMrVtDWt0VSpqbFUy7QxTja01U5Mz8lUydQ11lGwK7JSs//8HAA)

In collaboration with [primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4098/primo) on the code.golf discord.

The idea is to have a signal variable `$x` that is zero until `$i` hits 1000 then is 1 afterwards. We use the bitwise construction `1|-$x` which is a shorter version of `$x ? -1 : 1` to select whether to go upwards or downwards.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/),  <s>56</s>  49 bytes

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to @Sisyphus and @xnor*

My PHP is rusty, but here is a first attempt.

```php
for(;$n<2e3;)echo 1e3-abs(1e3-$n++),'<p>';echo 0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxV8myMUo2tNVOTM/IVDFONdROTijVAtEqetramjrpNgZ26NVjSwPr/fwA)

## 47 bytes

A shorter version suggested by @Neil:

```php
echo 0;for(;$n<2e3;)echo'<p>',min(++$n,2e3-$n);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU5Mz8hUMrNPyizSsVfJsjFKNrTVBYuo2BXbqOrmZeRra2ip5OkBxXZU8Tev//wE)

## 43 bytes

If the output can end with an extra `<p>`:

```php
for(;$n<2001;)echo 1e3-abs(1e3-$n++),'<p>';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxV8myMDAwMrTVTkzPyFQxTjXUTk4o1QLRKnra2po66TYGduvX//wA)

Comment: i was trying turnery but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `echo` takes multiple arguments, so you can remove the brackets and replace `.` with `,`

Comment: It looks like `1e3-abs($n-1e3)` is a byte shorter than the ternary. And shifting indices probably shortens that too.

Comment: `for(;$i<2001;)echo 1e3-abs(1e3-$i++),'<p>';` (thx @xnor)

Comment: I think `echo 0;for(;$n<2e3;)echo'<p>',min(++$n,2e3-$n);` is shorter for the first option, but I couldn't seem to adapt it for the second option.

Comment: @Neil Nice improvement. I've turned this into community wiki, so feel free to edit further if you find something for the second option.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 51 bytes

```php
echo join("<p>",[...range(0,999),...range(1e3,0)]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU5Mz8hWy8jPzNJRsCuyUdKL19PSKEvPSUzUMdCwtLTV14HzDVGMdA81YTev/9nb/AQ)

There's already shorter versions, but I just wanted to show the OP how the original code can be shortened with the old alias `join` and the spread operator that is now available in PHP

**Depending on your rules, even shorter:**

**49** bytes with `<?=`

```php
<?=join("<p>",[...range(0,999),...range(1e3,0)]);
```

or even **47** with a literal new line, if your output can be wrapped in `<pre><code>`

```php
<?=join("
",[...range(0,999),...range(1e3,0)]);
```