# Custom Rows of Smileys Triangle

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

This problem is inspired from [shinh's problem](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Smileys+Triangle).

Given an input of positive integer \$n\$, output a smiley triangle (see below) with \$n\$ rows.

### Detailed rules

- Can be either a function or a full program.
- Standard I/O rules applied.

  - **RULE CLARIFICATION: Output as exactly a string, rather than an array of strings whose item represent a line.**
- Standard loopholes are forbitten.
- This is code-golf. Shortest code wins.

## Valid output syntax

Assuming ASCII encoding.
A smiley triangle with \$n\$ rows `triangle(n)`, where n>=1, should be output. `<0xXX>` is a character with such codepoint, in hexadecimal.

```
triangle(n) = triangle(n) <0x0a> | triangle_(n)
triangle_(1) = <0x3a> spaces
triangle_(n) = triangle_(n-1) <0x0a> row(n) spaces
row(2) = <0x3a> <0x2d>
row(n) = row(n-1) <0x29>
spaces = <0x09> spaces | <0x20> spaces | *empty*
```

### Example outputs

If n is 1, then

```
:
```

If n is 2, then

```
:
:-
```

If n=5, then

```
:
:-
:-)
:-))
:-)))
```

Comment: is returning an array of lines valid output?

Comment: @Razetime, I don't think so, as I clarified to use LFs as in "Valid output syntax".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte simultaneously spotted by Razetime*

```
↑ḣ¡→":-)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxIc7Fh9a@KhtkpKVrub///9NAQ)

```
    ":-)    # the string ":-)"
  ¡         # construct infinite list by repeatedly appending
   →        # last element of list so far;
 ḣ          # now make list of all prefixes,  
↑           # and take number of elements equal to input
```

Comment: remove `⁰` for -1

Comment: @Razetime - Thanks: I was just doing it while you commented!

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
s=':-'
exec"print s[:-1];s+=')';"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hW3UpXnSu1IjVZqaAoM69EoTjaStcw1rpY21ZdU91aSSszr6C0REPz/39DAwA)

**42 bytes**

```python
s,c=':-'
exec"print s;s+=c;c=')';"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1gn2VbdSledK7UiNVmpoCgzr0Sh2LpY2zbZGiihqW6tpJWZV1BaoqH5/7@hAQA)

**43 bytes**

```python
s=':'
exec"print s;s+='-)'[s>':'];"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hW3UqdK7UiNVmpoCgzr0Sh2LpY21ZdV1M9utgOKBVrraSVmVdQWqKh@f@/oQEA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
“:-)”ṁ«\)Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//4oCcOi0p4oCd4bmBwqtcKVn/w4cpauKBvgoK//81)

```
        )     Map over (the range from 1 to) the input:
“:-)”ṁ        Mold ":-)" to the shape of the argument, cycling its contents.
      «\      Scan by minimum: replace anything to the right of ) with ).
         Y    Join on newlines.
```

Thanks to Jonathan Allan for salvaging my first attempt, [`”)xⱮa⁾:-Y`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw1zNikcb1yU@atxnpfv/cHukZhaQycX1/78pAA), for another 10-byter:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
”)xa⁾:-ṁ)Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw1zNisRHjfusdB/ubNSM/H@4XTMLyOXi@v/fFAA)

```
        )     Map over (the range from 1 to) the input:
”)x           Repeat ")" by the argument.
   a⁾:-       Zipwith-vectorize logical AND with ":-":
              overwrite the first two characters with ":-".
       ṁ      Mold to the shape of the argument, trimming the extra "-" for 1.
         Y    Join on newlines.
```

Comment: Your pretty close code can also be made into this working 9 byter: `”)xa⁾:-ṁ)` [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw1zNisRHjfusdB/ubNT8f7g9UjMLyOXi@v/fFAA) (or `”)ṁa⁾:-ṁ)`). Good spot on the order of the characters by the way!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! Checking the order of the characters was actually the first thing I thought to do, even though my initial approach didn't use it.

Comment: newlines are required in the output.

Answer (score 7):

## Excel, <s>37</s> 49 bytes

*+12 bytes to accommodate clarification that the output should be one string*

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(":-"&REPT(")",A1),SEQUENCE(A1))&"
")
```

This returns one string as opposed to the earlier version which returned multiple cells each containing a string.  Due to the Excel string limit, this only works for n <= 254.

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnF_QDKPVdX0hy4-6?e=VpuWvQ)

```
=LEFT(":-"&REPT(")",A1),SEQUENCE(A1))
```

Previous version that works for n <= 32767.

Comment: Why would the code fail after n=32767?

Comment: @Mohammad, it fails because of the string limit in Excel.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
…:-).ÞI£Jη»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMyK11NvcPzPA8t9jq3/dDu//8NDQA)

Or, for the same length:

```
')×„:-ì¨¨η»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9vc2FiaWX//ycpw5figJ46LcOswqjCqM63wrv//zEw)

```
…:-)         # string literal ":-)"
    .Þ       # cycle last character to create infinite list
      I£     # take the first input characters
        J    # join into a string
         η   # take all prefixes
          »  # join by newlines

')×          # repeat ")" input times
   „:-ì      # prepend ":-"
       ¨¨    # remove the last two characters
         η»  # join the prefixes by newlines
```

Comment: You can combine both of your answers in the legacy version of 05AB1E for -1 byte: [`')×„:-ì£η»`](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v8wNWFiMWX//ycpw5figJ46LcOswqPOt8K7//8xMA) (the `£` will implicitly use the input, even though it's the first argument instead of second).

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╞■¼╤╝<Ñ┬
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=c6feacd1bc3ca5c2&i=5)

outputs with newlines.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 32 bytes

```hs
(`take`(":":iterate(++")")":-"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcIxCoAwDADAr4Tg0FIcXQr9gU6uggZptVhL0Ph9o9ztdB@xFE1hUrMIHXEx6NFniRdJNM6h/fkWrdWTcoUAJ/EwAz8yytVXaCBBp@@aCm23tivzBw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs an array of lines.

```
õî":-"ú')U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9e4iOi0i%2bicpVQ&input=NQotUg)

```
õî":-"ú')U     :Implicit input of integer U
õ              :Range [1,U]
 î             :For each slice the following to that length
  ":-"         :  Literal string
      ú')U     :  Right padded with ")" to length U
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>17</sup> 15 bytes

*-1 thanks to Jonah!*

```
[:]\$!.'('&':-'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61iY1QU9dQ11NXUrXTV/2tycaUmZ@QrpCkYQhjqukCgDhM0xiZoiiz4HwA)

Reshape `:-` with fill `(` to length `n`. `[:[\` return each prefix.

Comment: `[:]\{.!.'('&':-'` for 16.

Comment: @Jonah ah, with that `$` works, too! Thanks!

Comment: Cool, didn't realize you could use fit with `$`.  One thing I don't understand is why you can't `]\@$!.'('&':-'`?  I mean, I get that `]\@$` is a new verb, which has no definition for `!.`, but why wouldn't J just check the rightmost verb in the list of conjunctions, and if it's defined there, use that one?

Comment: @Jonah even better `!.` would just set the fill for the context, e.g. `(… $ … {. … $)!._` would all use `_`. But I guess the cost of implementing it outweighs the seldom usage.

Comment: Why a sad triangle instead of a smiley triangle? Isn't `)` the correct fill char?

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 37 bytes

```
{({(":-",(x-2)#")")[!x]}'!x+1)[1+!x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqNaQ8lKV0lHo0LXSFNZSVNJM1qxIrZWXbFC21Az2lAbxPlfXeuQYGCVpmBk8B8A)

My first non trivial K answer, a lot of room for inprovement.

Comment: [Do this to surpress printing](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqNaQ8lKV0lHo0LXSFNZSVNJM1qxIrZWXbFC21Az2lAbxPlfXeuQYGCVpmBk8B8A)

Comment: And the `f:` doesn't count as part of your bytecount - it's like `lambda a,b: a+b` but the only difference is newlines are unescapable delimiters, so the `f:` has to be on the same line.

Comment: you can use `#` to save a lot of bytes instead of indexing with `[]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 9 bytes

```
⇩\)*‛:-p¦
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%87%A9%5C%29*%E2%80%9B%3A-p%C2%A6&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Wasif said I should post my 9-byter as my own answer, but I thought it was too similar to his, so I got rid of the map lambda and the slice, just because why not. :P

Explanation:

```
⇩          # x = input - 2
 \)*       # Push a 'x' long string of ')'
    ‛:-p   # Prepend the string ':-'
        ¦  # Prefixes
           # 'j' flag - Join top of stack on newlines and print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda n:[print((':-'+')'*i)[:-1])for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKrqgKDOvREND3UpXXVtdU10rUzPaStcwVjMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNPM/Y/mpChjpmmFZeCQppGpiaQghik@R8A)

-1 byte thanks to Mohammad

Comment: -1 instead of `i+1` will save 1 character

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 37 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>--n?f(n)+(s=n>1?s+')':`
:-`):':'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYxBCoAgEADvfWR3iZWsm2B@JSmNItbI6PvWMbp1nRlm9ZfP47HsJ0uaQinRiu2ZxUUUqjFb6bXLNRCYoTI8kAEDZUyS0xbUlmaMqImqNwEGdYQ9@BPb5uMitr/q7letn3m5AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `jr`, 10 bytes

```
ƛ?\)*‛:-+Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=%C6%9B%3F%5C%29*%E2%80%9B%3A-%2B%E1%BA%8E&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Thanks to @emanresuA for -2 bytes

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 12 bytes

```
‛:-?⇩\)*+¦?Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%80%9B%3A-%3F%E2%87%A9%5C%29*%2B%C2%A6%3F%E1%BA%8E&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Comment: [11](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C6%9B%E2%80%9B%3A-%3F%5C%29*%2Bn%E1%BA%8E&inputs=10&header=&footer=),  [10 with a flag](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=%C6%9B%3F%5C%29*%E2%80%9B%3A-%2B%E1%BA%8E&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Comment: Be honest, did you get my username right first time?

Comment: @emanresuA nope, I was tempted to write Ausername lol, BTW nice to meet you after long time!

Comment: [You can remove the `?` for 9 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=%C6%9B%5C%29*%E2%80%9B%3A-%2B%E1%BA%8E&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Comment: [Alternate 9 bytes with an emoticon in it and without the `r` flag](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C6%9B%5C%29*%E2%80%9B%3A-p%E1%BA%8E&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller nice! You can post as a separate answer!

Comment: I decided to post one that was pretty different, so you can still update yours with the 9 bytes if you want.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 20 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{,\⍵⍴':-',')'⍴⍨|⍵-2}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q9aJedS79VHvFnUrXXUddU11IPNR74oaoKCuUS0A&f=S1MwBAA&i=AwA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Monadic function

`{`...`}` monadic function, takes n on right

`⍵-2` n minus 2

`|` abs (No. of braces, call it x)

`⍨` swap x with

`')'` brace for

`⍴` dyadic reshape to get x braces

`,` concat with

`':-'` smiley head

`⍵⍴` take first n (monadic reshape)

`,\` prefixes (ravel scan)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>40</s> <s>35</s> 27 bytes

```
Input N
Disp ":
":-
For(I,2,N
Disp Ans
Ans+")
End
```

-5 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)

-8 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6vpKT03zOvoLREwY/LJbO4QEHJikvJSpfLLb9Iw1PHSAcq6phXzAXE2kqaXK55KWBdAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) -F, 59 bytes

```php
for(;$i<$argn;)echo$i++?":-".str_repeat(")",$i-2)."
":":
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcSxCoAgEADQ3c84HBTTIWhRwa3fCAlLF@8wv7@rNzyqxDHR/4VDBdmizOPuQZezomzGJPAW3DPHMQqVPBVoWGSzq3YgwIMXEJi3F2k27A/b/QM)

Straightforward stuff.. Probably golfable a bit more, I'll try other things later

Answer (score 1):

## [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), 88 bytes

Just a port of the syntax in OP.

```
define(g,`ifelse($1,2,,`)g(decr($1))')')define(f,`ifelse($1,1,:,`f(decr($1))
:-g($1)')')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yzX5/z8lNS0zL1UjXSchMy01pzhVQ8VQx0hHJ0EzXSMlNbkIyNXUVAdCqLo0ZHWGOlY6CWkIdVxWuukgBkj9/zQNQ00urjQNIzBpqvkfAA)

### Usage

`f(number here)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＮθＧ↓→θ⁺:-×)θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orID@nMj0/T8PKJb88T0fBKigzPaNER6FQRyEgp7RYQ8lKV0lHISQzNxXI1gQyCzU1Na3//zf9r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｇ↓→θ
```

Draw a triangle of size `n`.

```
⁺:-×)θ
```

Paint the triangle using a smiley with `n` chins.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
i=input()
o=':-'+')'*i
for x in range(1,i+1):print o[:x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERDkyvfVt1KV11bXVNdK5MrLb9IoUIhM0@hKDEvPVXDUCdT21DTqqAoM69EIT/aqiL2/38zAA)

Without the leading newline

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
i=input()
o=':-'+')'*i
for x in range(i+1):print o[:x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERDkyvfVt1KV11bXVNdK5MrLb9IoUIhM0@hKDEvPVUjU9tQ06qgKDOvRCE/2qoi9v9/MwA)

Never going to be a winner. Just an alternative approach.

**55 bytes**

```python
lambda x:'\n'.join((':-'+')'*x)[:x]for x in range(x+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr3RrK9FEBwcSX6IOGEUxWghhqK/Hu/SVK8pQ/bTUx73b7kAtLoLdHYMQoW3RIGOjPFtdfcygEASyk/MgNT1zTTlIAU8j1x8)

Another alternative using a lambda, surprisingly longer than using `input()`. It's that `join()` that's expensive.

Comment: These produce leading newlines

Comment: @jitse Having read the question again several times, I don't see where it says leading newlines are disallowed. Maybe I am missing something??

Comment: Allowed formatting is specified in the `Valid output syntax` block in the question. Leading spaces are specifically not included there, so I don't think they are valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 25 bytes

```
.+
$*)
^.
:
:.
:-
.
$`$&¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRUuTK06Py4rLCkjoculxqSSoqB3a9v@/KQA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*)
```

Start with `n` chins.

```
^.
:
```

Change the first chin into eyes.

```
:.
:-
```

Change the second chin, if any, into a nose.

```
.
$`$&¶
```

Output all of the nontrivial prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.times{|i|puts":-#{?)*n}"[0..i]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@vJDM3tbi6JrOmoLSkWMlKV7naXlMrr1Yp2kBPLzO2tva/hqGenqmmXm5iAUhVWnRmrDVIae1/AA)

Comment: 1.upto(n) saves 1 byte

Comment: @GB Thanks, but I found an even better way: `n.times`  saves 2 :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```hs
f x=($":-"++cycle")").take<$>[1..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwlZDRclKV0lbO7kyOSdVSVNJU68kMTvVRsUu2lBPryL2f25iZp6CrUJuYoFvvEJBaUlwSZFPnoKKQpqC6X8A)

- Thanks to @Unrelated String for saving 2!

Comment: [I'm kind of surprised this managed to shave two bytes off](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwlZDRclKV0lbO7kyOSdVSVNJU68kMTvVRsUu2lBPryL2f25iZp6CrUJuYoFvvEJBaUlwSZFPnoKKQpqC6X8A)

Comment: Thanks @Unrelated String ! I was just trying some sort of map but I'm still not much confident with haskell tricks

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

```c
f(x){x&&f(x-1)+g(x);}g(x){x&&g(x-1);putchar("\n:-)"[x<3?x:3]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KzukJNDUjrGmpqpwO51rXpUMF0sKB1QWlJckZikYZSTJ6VrqZSdIWNsX2FlXEsUOX/zLwShdzEzDwFDc1qLoU0DVNNa67a/wA)

- double recursion

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>43</s> <s>33</s> 28 bytes

```powershell
':-'+')'*"$args"|% *ve @args
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCoJAFEXXM18xDGOmNaJbQxCidZHLiEh7WmFpM1qB@u3TCEotert3OffcsniBkGfIc54UAhRLg0aZPjdnpmXalB1FJmlrEPsJJOwf1WHM4F1CUsHJc0lAqM@t4egCe47jua3RYMQEyDqvNDFhKWEHnYw9nf04nKiOZSUu92zqzjVoYbTbRMtaVsVtHV81tQ@1D0V1koCUfXlQc3h8RZrYjosDoKPVn0mMOtypDw)

Saved 10 bytes thanks to mazzy!
Saved 5 bytes by:

- removing gratuitous parenthesis
- using `Remove` instead of `Substring`
- using splatting

Comment: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##bY3BCoJAFEXXzlcMMqZjKbo1hCBaF7mMiNGeVmjajFKgfru9QKlFb/cu555blU@Q6gJ57iSlhIGlYTtUQorCYoJbZuCYc5ObNj6dQZWdUY8yMfSEMHhVkNRw9j0aUj1w@Hj6kviu63ud0RKNSVBNXiMxYyllJ0ymHmY/DjdqYlXL6z2zvAWCnGiHXbRuVF0W2/iG1HGFPi1qkgSU@pRHtQOPrwiJ/bQ4Ahht/kwSrSf98AY "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")?

Comment: awesome! ٩(^‿^)۶

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 57 bytes

This assumes the initial memory location contains *n* in binary (0x05 == 5). The TIO link allows a single ASCII character as input and converts it to binary.

```
->>++++++++[-<+++++++>]<++.<[->-------------.----<[->.<]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/q9jpw0F0bo2umBgF2vzX9cOWRzKAkpoa@vZROva6SIDPRABEtWziY39/9/0/38A)

Comment: Is it outputting a line rather than a triangle?

Comment: Ah… I misunderstood that bit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <sup><strike>82</strike></sup> 80 bytes

```java
String a(int n){return(n>1?a(n-1):"")+(":-"+")".repeat(n)).substring(0,n)+"\n";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/NbsIwDL7zFFZOsbJW9Eo3eILtsuPGwYQwBYpbJS7ShPrsJSSV8MGW7M/fz5luVJ2Pl9l2FCN8kuf7ClJ5FhdOZB18lcWzviV4/gOr0xUY23yYVnlEIfF2XiC0QO7ByRhY87bZkeaqwY1SaLTaVMooVHVwgyPRjFjH8RDzt16/MRr1y6qd5id3WySG8dB5uyjBrfdHuCbDumj@7AlfVk99gOzBwwc0Lfj3Zp26MQgvUM70H8Vd636Uekg00rFO5nEJVwKWPs0P)

Recursively append longer smileys. A different approach might be shorter...

-2 thanks to ceilingcat!

Comment: I always miss the simplest things, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, <s>53</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```bash
a=:-;for n ({1..$1})a+=\)&&<<<$a[1,n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P9HWStc6Lb9IIU9Bo9pQT0/FsFYzUds2RlNNzcbGRiUx2lAnL/Z/anJGfi1XmoIxEBsBsSEQm4BoEMPQ/D8A)
 <sub><s>[39 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P9HWSpcrLb9IIU9Bo9pQT0/FsFYzUds2RlNNzcbGRqU60crASiWv9n9qckZ@LVeagjEQGwGxIRCbgGgQw9D8PwA)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[53 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P9HWSpcrLb9IIU9Bo9pIT0/FsFYzUds2RhMuaAgRtLGxUalOtDKwUsmr/Z@anJFfy5WmYAzERkBsCMQmIBrEMDT/DwA)</s></sub>

Realised I was wasting bytes by doing 2 loops when one would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>109</s> 95 bytes

```
 n =input
b s =gt(n,1) char(10) ':-' dupl(')',n - 2) s :f(c)
 n =n - 1 :(b)
c output =':' s
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxLCoQwEAX3OcXbdTcoGNFNIIeZxC9IRybJ@aNui6rKmkK6ptag8KfetZiADL8X1s4K4vH7sx0E5HrCUu@LSahT9BjlFd3GUcwXf8jCcRATkWp5V/DkCNmsurQ2Pw)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 68 bytes

```c
i;f(n){char*s=calloc(n,4);for(s[i=0]=58;n--;s[i]=i++?41:45)puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCsIwEEX3PcVQEBLTgIVWxDF4EO0iRFIDcVqaiovSqxtTUBf6NsP8eR/GyNaYGB1aRnwyVz2sgzLa@84wKiqOthtYODm1aVS9Q5IS09YoJ8SxKvdVzfv7GFjgOEdHI9y0I8ZhyiCRusCWlEBBiWkcYIsgBH2MhX5IimU5qdXlTHlBHL@35Sv8M@UvqfbW5myOT2O9bkOUjxc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com), 67 bytes

```
Column@With[{n=#},":-"<>")"~StringRepeat~n~StringTake~#&/@Range@n]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zk/pzQ3zyE8syQjujrPVrlWJ7ikKDMvPSQxOzVayUpXycZOSVOpDiIYlFqQmlhSl6ejHKum7xCUmJee6pAXq/Y/AChZ4pDm4Jqcke@grFYXnJyYV1fNZajDZaTDZarDZclV@x8A)

For some reasons unbeknownst to me, TIO doesn't display the list in column form. But if you run it in Mathematica, it will generate the desired result.

Explanation:

```
s=":-"<>StringRepeat[")",n]   (* generates the main string *)
StringTake[s,#]& /@ Range[n]  (* a list of substrings up to length n *)
```

Comment: `Column` is formatted in the REPL, but doesn't actually evaluate. Use `Print/@` instead. [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P@/9pIUBRZl5JQ7BJUAqPSQxOzVayUpXycZOSVOpLiQxKSe1Lk9HOVatzrGoKLGyLu9/moNrcka@g7JaXXByYl5dNZehDpeRDpepDpclV@1/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP `-F`, 86 bytes

Without any predefined funcation!

```
for($n=0;$n<$argn;$n++){echo':';for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){echo$i>1?')':'-';}echo PHP_EOL;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFTybA2sVfJsVBKL0vOADG1tzerU5Ix8dSt1a7B8pq2htUqmja0KUDYTJquSaWdor64JVKSrbl0LElEI8AiId/X3sa79b2/33/RffkFJZn5e8X9dNwA)

Thanks.

Comment: Nice first answer! [Here is a 68 byte version](https://tio.run/##bVJNT@MwEL3zK0aRpTSCKhSJCynltCsOSHBHK@Q4U2KRzmRtpyEg/jrdsbMrFbQXy/Px3pt5dt/2h/VNL@eW3aJSdHq6Vto9U1W8o2k5v8qrWFH2elUpG6tSSpVlkT8qu7n4VaXwJK8@DmWpCBpGT3kAQmwgMNQIlmywurNv2JyU5cQDGE2SNQ53SAFUDCC0CB1zD4apEQATLLzeo4eI0MTS4KCeAgqn0YNHyJRdXyvKYoJ30hkTEhdHMrrzfKxl/2kdyQhss/rCsrn4QuKw77TBhAvoSLvpCJ/6b/JC7FrmQjOBBm/puUPwwcnlDEYb2m@qskAySBuD3qeipQZfgbcpmKGw2MoGCbdHF2bIOZQQ3IDxvjqD3nEzCInIjtpRRNVDgJHdi49bEM@vIU8JtdPmBYMs@f6RwdiiODTb3moPTN0kR5xE5AcTB/2PDdnD7cPTj/u7v7t2NogpuhOVUYIZbhuE3wMHGWuhqRHsjvezg76PJDWGEUU@ix8og9gTiwlTHC4/uY/q/rD8@Qc)

Comment: I added some comments in the footer, I recommand reading [tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2913/90841), it can be useful, even if most improvements I used are "classical" tricks not in the post.

Comment: @Kaddath thank you so much! Let me learn golfing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

```perl
sub f{map{substr':-'.')'x99,0,$_}1..pop}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrTo3saAayCouKVK30lXXU9dUr7C01DHQUYmvNdTTK8gvqP2vomSrom/NVVCUmVei5FAdrQAEaRoq8ZogRmxtTF5MnpJCWn6RAlCDqfV/AA)